# Perguntas gerais sobre computadores no tópico?

Tags: debate

Hoje votei para fechar essa pergunta sobre utilização do Windows:

[image: Pergunta sobre Windows no SOPT]

Ela seria fechada directamente no Stackoverflow original. Mas um comentário do `mgibsonbr` que havia na pergunta têm alguma razão:

> Como nós não temos ServerFault em português ou SuperUser em português, creio que o nosso escopo pode sim incluir certas questões de configuração do SO

Devemos ser mais tolerantes a perguntas não só sobre programação? ou manter o ambito a perguntas de programação (por enquanto)?

Comment: Observação: a pergunta já foi apagada pelo AP (autor da pergunta, hehehe).

Comment: @bfavaretto e não há ninguem excepto moderadores que consigam ver a pergunta :)

Comment: @bfavaretto: aprovo a designação __AP__

Comment: Acho que vai ter que fazer glossário do SO. Acho que todo mundo sabe o que é OP, ninguém sabe o que é AP. Nada impede de inciarmos moda também.

Comment: o que é "OP" ??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Uma pergunta não precisa envolver programação, pelo menos é isso que foi previamente estabelecido no site (pode mudar no futuro), mas precisa estar relacionada diretamente com o trabalho do desenvolvedor.

Tem que ser uma pergunta que só interesse ao desenvolvedor. Se a pergunta pode estar interessando **circunstancialmente** p/ uma pessoa que por acaso é desenvolvedor ela não ajuda um desenvolvedor, mas sim um usuário de computador que **também** exerce o trabalho de desenvolvimento.

Devemos sempre perguntar: "Isso é útil para DESENVOLVEDORES em geral". Não pessoas em geral, não usuário de computadores em geral, *desenvolvedores* exercendo sua profissão específica. Muitas vezes ele tem atividades próximas ao desenvolvimento mas que só podem ser interessantes para ele por causa da situação específica dele.

Se o desenvolvedor está escrevendo um texto e tem dificuldade com alguma coisa do editor de texto, vamos responder também? Acho que não.

Não basta ter a palavra programador/desenvolvedor na pergunta. Não adianta dizer: "sou desenvolvedor, o que devo comer no almoço?" Pode parecer exagero, mas coisas do tipo já deram muita polêmica nos sites em inglês.

O site tem um escopo definido e precisamos segui-lo. Não tem onde perguntar em português no SE? Paciência.

É o que queremos aqui? Eu não gostaria de ver um site tão aberto assim, mas estou ouvindo o que todos tem a dizer.

Na pergunta específica tem até como ela ser feita de um jeito que seja de interesse do desenvolvedor, mas muda o sentido dela e a forma como as pessoas vão responder.

Podemos deixar estas perguntas para o [Super User em Português](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84282/super-user-em-portugues).

Comment: O seu ponto sobre útil para desenvolvedores em geral é precisamente meu ponto. Acho que a linha que temos que setar é que stackoverflow br aceita mais ou menos os conteúdos de stackoverflow americano + programmers + uma pontinha de SU / SF para coisas que um DEV venha precisar fazer (Produzir uma entrada no menu para chamar uma função da sua aplicação se encaixa nesse critério, mas, ao meu ver, produzir uma entrada no menu em geral não).

Comment: Sim, o site foi proposto para ser exatamente isso e a equipe do SE vê assim também (provavelmente que o original fosse isso também mas a história não permitiu). Acrescentaria um pontinha de outros sites, **talvez**: os filhotes do SU, Pro Webmasters, Game Dev, Math, TCS, ITSec, DBA, WP, UX, CR, Code Golf (que não me grada muito), Project Management, QA&Test, Crypto, Freelancing???, entre outros. Só uma pontinha, só onde há sobreposição com o trabalho de desenvolvedor diretamente. Note que não conheço o escopo de todos profundamente, e posso ter exagerado.

Comment: Meu argumento é que o Stack tem sites demais: StackOverflow, Programmers, Server Fault, Database Administrators. Um desenvolvedor de software competente precisa ter conhecimento sobre todas essas áreas. **Se nesses casos, é para mandar a pessoa usar o site em inglês (e que se exploda se não souber inglês), então eu acredito que não precisamos de StackOverflow em português.**

Comment: É para mandar nos casos que a pergunta não pode ser feita aqui, para usar a questão que está sendo discutida aqui, sim deveria ir p/ o SU em inglês, até que tenha o SUpt, coisa que a equipe já deixou claro que não é intenção ter (acho que isso mudaria se o SOpt fosse um estrondoso sucesso)

Comment: Antes até de mandar para qualquer lugar, ela deveria ser melhorada para ficar aqui! Muitas, não todas, podem ser salvas, mas vejo que é comum o autor não querer melhorar. Boa vontade atrai boa vontade.

Comment: Peraí, perguntas sobre editor de texto acho que são muito bem-vindas sim. Aqueles usados por *programadores*, obviamente (vim, emacs, etc.), não perguntas sobre como formatar tabelas no Word, por exemplo (a não ser que via macros, VBA, etc.).

Comment: @obvio171 Aí são editores de código e não de texto ;)

Answer (score 7):

Pessoalmente acho que a ausência de outros sites em português não justifique a tolerância a conteúdo não relacionado à programação no site.

Enquanto a diferença pode ser tênue acredito que devemos definir uma linha de corte.

Por exemplo: Se fosse uma pergunta do tipo "Como fazer o instalador da minha aplicação configurar uma opção global no windows para chamar determinada função de um *assembly* .NET passando como parâmetro o diretório atual do usuário?" (não que o título fosse esse). Acredito que a pergunta seria bem vinda.

Porém uma pergunta genérica que não envolve programação (apenas manipulação do registro do Windows), ao meu ver, não possui espaço no stackoverflow.

Algo que deve ser debatido é se devemos ou não recomendar os sites em inglês para os usuários uma vez que a migração automática é impossível.

Comment: Não vejo problemas em indicar o site em inglês, deixando claro que está nessa língua. Não vamos solucionar todos os problemas da vida de um programador. Alguns ele vai ter que se contentar em tentar em inglês ou um fórum comum em português.

Comment: "apenas manipulação do registro do Windows" Isso já é algo que, embora não seja específico de desenvolvedores, seria uma coisa que raramente um usuário comum precisaria fazer... Não posso falar por outros profissionais de TI (ou além), pela falta de experiência, mas fico me perguntando: "por que alguém ia querer mexer **manualmente** no registro do windows se não fosse para dar suporte a alguma aplicação específica?" (desenvolvida *in-house*, pois se fosse externa ou seria problema do fornecedor ou ela já teria essa funcionalidade *built-in*) No mais, concordo com suas colocações.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Pode parecer pouco, mas automatizar faria diferença. Certos detalhes são sutis para definir se a pergunta é pertinente ou não. IMHO, claro.

Comment: @mgisonbr... Tudo bem que eu sou um DEV e um Power User (como disse, a linha é tênue), porém, pelo menos para mim, a pergunta do usuário soou mais como uma maneira de organizar o menu contextual dele e adicionar novas entradas. Eu já fiz isso algumas vezes via registro, mas existem aplicativos para fazer isso... Eis um exemplo: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/17882-edit-context-menu-change-default-program-windows.html. De qualquer maneira, independentemente da resposta, achei que a pergunta em si também foi genérica e faltou esforço de pesquisa.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Se lembro bem, tinha algo na pergunta que poderia dar a entender que a finalidade era ligada a programação. Mas não era claro.

Comment: @bfavaretto E a pessoa tem que ajudar também. Mas o ideal, principalmente nesse momento, é discutir antes de apagar, até porque pode ter sido um erro. O autor errou a segunda vez apagando a questão.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, a indicação de edição de registro para máquinas Windows é mais comum do que você imagina, já que grandes feitos de *crack* são efetuados ali. E dada a quantidade sabida de software pirata no Brasil, e de nego querendo windows original sem pagar por ele, acho que seria apenas uma questão de tempo até que o SOPT inundasse com perguntas nessa vertente.