# Stack Overflow em português é somente o StackOverflow em português ou é mais abrangente?

Tags: debate, big-7, proposta-para-faq

Além do site StackOverflow, temos outros sites da área de programação no StackExchange tais como SuperUser, Computer Science, ServerFault, Programmers e Code Review, entre outros.

O StackOverflow em português visa a ser apenas o StackOverflow em português, ou questões que seriam de um Programmers em português ou de um Code Review em português também podem ser postadas aqui?

Comment: Apesar de já ter respondido essa pergunta, entendo que ela seja duplicata [dessa](http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/98/perguntas-gerais-sobre-computadores-no-topico). Vou sinalizar a pergunta como duplicata.

Comment: @LaPingvino Ãnh?!?!?! De onde você tirou isso? Acho que você está andando pelos Coffee-Shops holandeses, hein? :)

Comment: me perdi nas opções, por isso tirei depois. agora apaguei o comentário tb, n vi antes. (e não, nunca usei drogas e não planejo usar além de cafezinhos...)

Comment: Discordo de quem estava votando como duplicata. Se for assim, não poderemos mais discutir o que é on e off-topic a não ser naquela questão. Essa é mais genérica. e trata **no máximo** de um tema semelhante, nem sequer é exatamente o mesmo assunto. leia mais em http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/ e http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled e ainda http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38375/what-is-an-exact-duplicate. E vou criar outra parecida com essa mas que cria outro tipo de discussão

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Eu já *comentei* algo sobre isso, mas acho que vale uma resposta mais detalhada, até porque fiz uma pesquisa para responder com mais propriedade.

Lembro sempre que essa é minha opinião, vou influenciar para que essa seja a postura da comunidade, mas posso mudar de posição se alguém me convencer do contrário ou a comunidade decidir por outro caminho. Claro que alguns pontos são inegociáveis, mas tem mais a ver com a qualidade da questão do que com o conteúdo. Em tese, mantendo a qualidade, qualquer conteúdo poderia ser aceito aqui, desde que a comunidade decida assim.

Versão curta: o SOpt é bem mais abrangente que o SO original e envolve o desenvolvimento de software em geral. O público alvo aqui é o desenvolvedor que fala português e todo seu trabalho, não é apenas o desenvolvedor quando está codificando algo como é o original. A proposta do site foi feita assim, as perguntas criadas na fase de definição indicavam isso, e é o que a equipe do SE deseja. Até porque outros sites em português não serão criados tão cedo (pode até ser nunca), isso já foi definido também (pode mudar se o SOpt for um estrondoso sucesso, algo no mesmo nível do original, guardada as proporções do público alvo que é claramente menor).

*Achou a curta muito longa? Aguarde...*

Vejamos o [post que mostra a posição da equipe do SE](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-no-o-stackoverflow-com) do que pode ser inclusive aqui:

> - Áreas relacionadas ao dia a dia de programadores, como administração de sistemas, carreira profissional, tópicos gerais para profissionais de TI.
> - Questões conceituais, menos concretas, como design de software e metodologia de testes. - - Coisas que vão além da programação.
> - Perguntas menos rígidas sobre boas práticas ou como aprender mais sobre um assunto. Desde que essas perguntas não envolvam somente discussões sobre opiniões pessoais. Questões amplas, não-específicas, não costumam dar certo no Stack Exchange.
> - Pedidos de recomendação, com requisitos bem definidos, de ferramentas, bibliotecas, etc.
> - Perguntas básicas de programação.
> - Perguntas específicas demais, que só ajudariam a quem perguntou; Você decide o que quer responder, mas não há necessidade de remover essas perguntas do site.

Isso não quer dizer que a equipe está impondo isso. É uma ótima sugestão que podemos discordar porque a comunidade é nossa. A plataforma (engine) é deles, ou seja, eles são donos da bola e podem acabar com o jogo se a comunidade passar do limite e não contribuir para uma [internet melhor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124576/is-making-the-internet-a-better-place-still-a-useful-or-relevant-test-for-indi)<sup>(em inglês)</sup>, mas as regras *desta* comunidade são definidas aqui.

Se você discorda de um ou mais pontos específicos (em oposição a discordar de tudo), por favor, abra uma disussão específica como foi aberta [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/98/perguntas-gerais-sobre-computadores-no-topico).

Vamos lá, site por site o que **eu** considero que faz parte do SOpt:

### [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

Esse é fácil, pode ser perguntado tudo que seja:

- um problema específico sobre programação
- um algoritmo de software
- uma ferramenta normalmente usada por **programadores**
- problemas práticos que **podem ser respondidos** e que **sejam únicos para desenvolvimento de software**

Perguntas de baixa qualidade que não tornam a internet melhor não podem ser feitas, isso inclui:

- Questões gerais sobre software ou hardware. Mesmo aquelas que são úteis para o desenvolvedor em algum momento da vida dele. Precisa estar relacionado ao trabalho de desenvolvimento em qualquer fase. Muitos desenvolvedores exercem outras atividades em conjunto com o desenvolvimento e muitas vezes nem se dá conta disso. Não podemos cobrir tudo o que o desenvolvedor **por acaso** exerce.
- Questões com problemas de código que NÃO descreve o **problema específico** e que não contenha um trecho de código válido que pode ser reproduzido. Veja o [guia SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org)<sup>(em inglês)</sup>
- Questões que NÃO demonstrem um mínimo entendimento do problema perguntado. Um site de Q&A não é tutorial ou curso para iniciantes, é um site de **perguntas** e **respostas**. Ajuda quando o autor da pergunta coloca o que ele tentou, porque não funcionou e os resultados esperados. Um *[checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)*<sup>(em inglês)</sup> foi escrito pela [lenda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).
- Questões sobre servidores, redes ou infraestrutura, a não ser que elas estejam relacionadas a programação como scripts e instaladores (não instalação). *aqui cabe discussão mais aprofundada*
- Questões pedindo recomendação ou pesquisa de opinião sobre ferramentas, metodologias e recursos de informação externos ao SOpt NÃO fazem a internet melhor. Pode-se colocar alguma coisa na *tag wiki* para ajudar iniciantes terem uma referência de onde começar. É possível obter recomendação fazendo uma pergunta que possa ter uma resposta razoavelmente objetiva. É obrigação do autor fazer a pergunta que facilite a resposta nesses termos.

Lembrando que os sites de SE não foram criadas para permitir discussões sobre assuntos. Nós discutimos aqui no meta e mesmo assim apenas sobre o próprio funcionamento da comunidade e não sobre nossa profissão (ou hobby para alguns). Isso inclui perguntas que deveriam estar em um blog. Discursos ou postagens basicamente opinativa não são nem perguntas nem respostas, portanto não cabem em um site de Q&A. Perguntas hipotéticas ou que exercem futurologia também não são boas.

Algumas questões subjetivas podem ser feitas observando que elas:

- inspirem respostas que expliquem "porque" e "como"
- facilitem respostas longas e não curtas (evitando discurso ou capítulo de um livro)
- usem um tom construtivo, justo e imparcial (de outro modo caracteriza discurso retórico)
- incentivem o compartilhamento de experiências reais e não opiniões
- reforcem que qualquer opinião seja apoiada por *fatos* e *referências*
- demonstrem que você não quer apenas diversão

Veja mais sobre o que é [subjetivo bom](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)<sup>(em inglês)</sup>. E o como fazer [perguntas que tenham resposta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)<sup>(em inglês)</sup>.

E perguntas do tipo "fiquei jogando truco na faculdade, tenho que entregar esse trabalho amanhã e quero que alguém faça para mim já que não sei nada" devem ser fechadas imediatamente, possivelmente alertada à moderação. Pergunta para um problema específico, bem definido pode ser respondida independente de onde ele será usado.

### [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Inicialmente conhecido como Not Programming Related, foi um dos primeiros sites propostos dentro do chamado Stack Exchange 2.0, onde as pessoas propunham sites e se tivessem apoio na comunidade, eram criados pela equipe. O mesmo processo que permitiu a criação do SOpt.

Na minha opinião, é um site que nunca devia ter sido criado (participei bastante dele e fui moderador lá no pior momento da sua existência quando havia uma crise de identidade enorme). Ele foi criado para retirar do SO original questões de baixa qualidade que algumas pessoas gostam mas que os "especialistas" que mais contribuíam para SO abominavam. Depois o formato foi redefinido pela equipe do SE entendendo que certos tipos que questões nunca poderiam ser feitas na rede SE. Então o site virou o local para se perguntar sobre a profissão ou atividades relacionadas ao desenvolvimento de software que não fosse programação.

O objetivo nunca foi alcançado e até hoje você encontra muito mais perguntas abertas não relacionadas a programação no SO do que no Programmers inteiro (fiz um estudo informal sem muita precisão há algum tempo e a proporção era bem grande). O Programmers não se funde com o SO porque algumas pessoas se sentem melhor assim. Meu medo é o SOpt ter rejeição por parte de membros importantes que podem dar qualidade ao site se tiver muitas perguntas de baixa qualidade, mas não me preocupo com perguntas que são apenas abrangentes a toda profissão.

Porque estou dizendo tudo isso (até fazendo discuso :) )? Não podemos cometer o mesmo erro e separar as questões em vários sites. Isso foi um erro e mais dificultou a vida das maioria dos membros do que ajudou alguns poucos. Temos mecanismos para minimizar os efeitos de ter uma abrangência maior e de qualquer forma não teremos a imensidão de perguntas que o SO tem.

Então (o que realmente interessa :) ) também devemos aceitar perguntas com:

- conceitos sobre algoritmos e estrutura de dados
- padrões de projeto (design patterns)
- desenvolvimento de testes
- metodologias de desenvolvimento
- comercialização de serviços de desenvolvimento
- garantia de qualidade (QA)
- arquitetura de software
- engenharia de software
- licenciamento de software

Obviamente que ninguém é obrigado participar de todos esses assuntos. Da mesma forma que um usuário que entende de javascript pode não saber nada ou não se interessar por assembly, isso vale para qualquer assunto ou tag.

O Programmers (e em linhas gerais acho que deveríamos adotar a mesma postura) NÃO permite:

- assuntos gerais do ambiente de trabalho, políticas de escritório, ajuda com currículo
- qual tecnologia é melhor
- o que devo aprender, ler ou fazer em seguida
- conselhos **gerais** sobre carreira, entrevista, remuneração, estilo de vida, relacionamentos e qualquer coisa que não esteja diretamente ligada ao desenvolvimento de software
- questões legais específicas (só um advogado pode responder)

### [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Muitos desenvolvedores são administradores de banco de dados também. Mas são a mesma atividade? Me parece ser uma atividade muito comum mas precisamos estabelecer uma linha.

Perguntas que podemos aceitar facilmente:

- programação do lado do cliente
- qualquer coisa que envolva SQL
- programação de *Stored Procedures* e gatilhos
- modelagem de dados

**Talvez** devêssemos aceitar também outras perguntas envolvendo:

- administração e configuração do servidor de banco de dados, incluindo *backup* e afinação (tunning)
- Data Warehousing e Business Intelligence, incluindo relatórios e OLAP

Uma discussão mais específica pode ser necessária.

### [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com)

Questões específicas sobre a construção de interface ou experiência do usuário fazem parte do trabalho do desenvolvedor e podem ser perguntadas aqui.

Claro que corremos o risco de não termos especialistas que consigam responder algo mais complexo.

### [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Obviamente essas perguntas envolvem sempre a colocação de código, mostrar o problema específico e o tipo de resposta que você deseja encontrar, além é claro você deve deixar claro que procura por uma revisão de código. Você pode estar procurando saber se o código tem problemas com:

- melhores práticas e padrões de uso
- segurança
- performance
- correção em casos imprevistos

Note que o código deve ser real, válido, preferencialmente feito por você.

### [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com)

Quebra-cabeças sobre programação que não sejam só diversão e perguntas mais específicas buscando o menor código possível, o chamado Code Golf. Nesses casos observe que a pergunta deve ter:

- um critério objetivo de vitória evitando que haja disputa quem venceu
- especificação clara do que é uma resposta correta (não necessariamente vencedora). Preferencialmente inclui um teste de caso
- pedido de dicas para participar de um concurso de *code golf* podem ser feitas também

Possivelmente questões de programação para serem usadas em testes de seleção e entrevistas possam entrar aqui também.

Note que esse tipo de pergunta é difícil de ser bem formulada. Não o faça se não tiver paciência ou capacidade de escrevê-la muito bem.

### [Software Quality Assurance & Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/)

Tudo que se relaciona a controle de qualdiade de software, automação e criação de testes.

### [Cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com)

Questões sobre:

- algoritmos assimétricos e simétricos
- protocolos
- técnicas de análise (mas não a análise em si)
- funções de hash
- entropia e teoria da informação
- geração de números aleatórios

O que envolve a matemática da criptografia terão mais dificuldade de serem respondidas.

### [Reverse Engineering](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com)

Questões sobre:

- análise estática ou dinâmica de software
- desmontagem ou descompilação de software
- ferramentas usadas para essas tarefas

### [Project Management](http://pm.stackexchange.com)

Pelo menoos tópicos relacionados ao desenvolvimento de software, incluindo:

- Agile
- Scrum
- RUP
- ferramentas usadas para gerenciamento
- boas práticas em gerenciamento de **projetos de software**

Não entra nada que seja usado em gerenciamento de projetos de outro tipo, mesmo relacionados com informática.

### [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com)

Em geral as questões contidas nesse site são de domínio específico mas algumas podem constar aqui:

- arquitetura de *engine* de jogos
- API de games
- programação para multiusuário
- algoritmos que costumam ser de conhecimento geral que podem ser usados em jogos

### CMS

Isso inclui alguns já criados, tais como: [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/), [SharePoint](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com), [SalesForce](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), [Magento](http://magento.stackexchange.com) e [Expression Engine](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com)

O motivo que eles podem ser incluídos é que todos tratam do desenvolvimento dessas plataformas.

Obviamente as questões de administração do conteúdo, da comunidade, e aspectos específicos da publicação não entram no nosso site.

Os aspectos que podem ser incluídos podem ser:

- desenvolvimento de *plugins*, módulos e extensões
- programação de temas (não a parte gráfica em si)

Podemos incluir, instalação e configuração dos softwares de CMS dependendo do que for decidido sobre outros tópicos.

### [Theorical Computer Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com)

Incluo aqui [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com). Mas não incluo [Computacional Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com) que me parece ser mais para usuário da computação em trabalhos e estudos científicos diversos do que tenha qualquer ligação direta com desenvolvimento de software. Se esse tipo de pergunta puder ser feita aqui, então vamos ter que permitir também questões sobre administração, engenharia, agricultura, medicina, biologia, física, enfim, qualquer área do conhecimento humano que possa ser colocado em um software. Somos desenvolvedores e vamos trocar conhecimento sobre o processo de desenvolvimento e tecnologias específicas para os desenvolvedores. Não dá para falar de todos os domínios que eventualmente um desenvolvedor se depare quando vai desenvolver alguma coisa.

Não vamos colocar toda computação aqui, inclusive porque se essas perguntas ficarem sem resposta, elas passam ser ruído na comunidade. Mas algumas coisas não devem fazer mal, porque faz parte do domínio específico do desenvolvedor

Podemos (?) incluir questões sobre:

- ciência da computação em geral
- algoritmos e modelos computacionais
- arquitetura de computadores
- inteligência artificial
- outros conceitos computacionais básicos

### [IT Security](http://security.stackexchange.com)

Apenas o que importa para desenvolvedores:

- técnicas e ferramentas para verificação de softwares
- políticas e metodologias usadas para evitar o comprometimento de softwares
- ataques comuns em softwares

Não entra questões sobre antivírus, segurança física, legislação e suporte envolvendo segurança.

### [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)

Certamente cabe mais discussão aqui. O quanto também interessa ao desenvolvedor aspectos de administração de sistemas. Não conta a parte de scripts e automação de tarefas do seu software, isso acho que pode ser facilmente incluso aqui no SOpt.

**Talvez** podemos incluir também os aspectos de software (exclui-se hardware) de:

- administração de sistemas operacionais e serviços comuns de servidores
- virtualização e computação em nuvem
- armazenamento, segurança e recuperação de dados
- configuração de redes, *firewalls*, etc.
- monitoramento e manutenção de serviços

Alguém vai dizer: porque aceitar administração de sistemas e não assuntos em geral que envolva computadores? Provavelmente porque administrar sistemas é uma tarefa profissional que muitos desenvolvedores acabam se envolvendo **diretamente** e guardam semelhanças na atividade. De qualquer forma, essa é uma decisão polêmica que merece mais discussão.

Pode-se argumentar que o desenvolvedor também pode trabalhar como técnico de suporte, e aí envolve qualquer coisa sobre computadores. Então digo que:

- o trabalho de suporte envolve um nível de conhecimento bem diferente do encontrado na administração de sistemas
- se for para abrir para tudo o que eventualmente o desenvolvedor faz, o site fica abrangente demais no alvo. Ficará complicado diferenciar quem é profissional e quem é usuário. Isso faz uma diferença enorme de quem é a comunidade
- se isso servir de argumento para incluir o SU e os afiliados, então prefiro que o SF não seja incluído

Particularmente questões *high profile* de administração de sistemas são mais interessantes.

Obviamente que qualquer outro site que seja criado em inglês que envolve o desenvolvimento de software, será um *subset* do que temos aqui.

---

Vou fazer uma referência especial a alguns sites que NÃO devem ser incluídos aqui. Na verdade todos eles são derivados do primeiro:

- [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)
- [Web Appplications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)
- [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)
- [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)
- [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)
- [Windows Phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/)
- [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Para esses sites já há uma discussão [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/98/perguntas-gerais-sobre-computadores-no-topico). Resumindo: Atividades relacionados ao computador (software ou hardware) que qualquer pessoa poderia realizar, ou seja, que não tenha exclusividade no processo de desenvolvimento de software, não pode ser postada aqui, caso contrário, teríamos um site de Q&A sobre informática em geral.

Mas note que a programação que envola um sistema operacional ou serviço específico, incluindo API para web faz parte da nossa comunidade.

Alguns sites que não acho que devem ser incluídos, mas estou aberto a discussão se alguns elementos puderem estar diretamente ligados ao desenvolvimento. Na prática alguns desses assuntos provavelmente já estariam incluídos nos itens cobertos pelo Programmers. Na sua forma geral e não específica para desenvolvedores NÃO inclui:

- [Personal Productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/)
- [Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com)
- [Freelancing](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/)

Considero domínio específico ou um problema de hardware e não diretamente relacionado ao desenvolvimento de software. Se for algo geral sobre desenvolvimento de software que por acaso será usado em nesse domínio, tudo bem, claro:

- [Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com)
- [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) (diferente de computação)
- [Robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/)
- [Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)
- [Network Engeneering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/)
- [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) (SEO, domínios e hospedagem)
- Qualquer site que envolva gráficos e design, mesmo que para web (que é diferente de usar gráficos no desenvolvimento. Ex.: "Como fazer um objeto tal e tal?" não pode, mas "Como colocar um thumbnail na página usando XYZ?" pode)
- Os demais que são obviamente muito distantes do nosso foco

Você chegou até aqui? Vai tomar uma água e depois venha dizer o que acha, talvez dando uma outra resposta para essa pergunta.

Comment: Acho uma boa lista. Talvez pode ser bom sim que alguém em algum ponto, por exemplo usando software Open Source segundo a ideia de SO/SE, cria alguns desses sites (principalmente o SuperUser me parece algo que será interessante para o público lusófono). Essa lista me parece bem-pensado e vou manter como referência.

Comment: Wow essa é a maior resposta que já vi em qualquer site do StackExchange!

Comment: Linda resposta!

Comment: Só 3 votos? Será que o pessoal não gostou ou não quis ler tudo?

Answer (score 5):

Acho que um bom exemplo é um fórum conhecido, como o clube do hardware.
Não visito, não confio e não gosto das respostas que encontro por lá, por serem todas mal embasadas e mal executáveis.

Veja bem, tenho certeza de que o CdH é muito útil, e muita gente é feliz com ele, só não é a minha praia.

Agora, se permitirmos aumentar a abrangência do SOPT, quanto tempo até que o site seja inundado com perguntas do tipo "como rotear meu modem?", ou "como quebrar a chave do Win7"?

Acho que, dadas as nossas inclinações culturais, talvez seja mais proveitoso que tenhamos um escopo mais reduzido e focado --- ajuda a manter a qualidade.

Comment: Para esses exemplos que deu, acho que seria melhor aplicar a regra "em outro lugar já tem resposta?". Se for assim, pode fechar sem medo. Se bem formulado, esse tipo de pergunta até pode contribuir, também pq programação não é uma ilha.

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade o StackOverflow em Inglês nunca se limitou para só perguntas de programação até a comunidade decidir nisso. Daí seguiram os outros sites. Eu não acho nenhum razão para deixar o StackOverflow em Português tão limitado, também pq a necessidade geral de informações sobre tecnologia no Brasil é bastante grande. Tendo dito isso, acho que será difícil manter isso ao menos no começo por causa de muitos programadores no site que já tem experiência com o SO...