# Posso fazer perguntas sobre Shell Script ou Ubuntu?

Tags: debate, perguntas, escopo-do-site

1 - Aqui no StackOverflow em Português, eu posso fazer perguntas sobre Shell Script?

2 - Posso fazer perguntas sobre Ubuntu (ou qualquer outro sistema operacional)?

Comment: Poder podes, agora se ficam abertas é que já não sei ;)

Comment: Acredito o 1 será bem aceito, já o 2 depende, se for a nível de usuário, diria que será fechada logo, se preferir pode tentar e ver no que dá.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Questões que falam de linha de comando podem ser aceitas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2471/quest%c3%b5es-que-falam-de-linha-de-comando-podem-ser-aceitas)

Comment: Mas, no ubuntu, eu posso perguntar sobre um erro, e não estar falando de linha de momando, @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @WallaceMaxters acredito que se você notar na pergunta verá links sobre linux e a resposta do Gabe, Bigown e Bfavaretto dão uma boa explicação do que pode ser aceito, ou seja, mesmo que a minha pergunta não se assemelhe de inicio a respostas nela parecem que respondem ao problema.

Comment: Então, depende muito da pergunta, "Ubuntu" ou "sistema operacional" pode englobar muita coisa. O melhor é mesmo postar e ver no que dá. Se a pergunta for fechada, não é nada de mais, não é demérito seu; quer dizer apenas que a comunidade achou que o site não é o melhor lugar para aquela pergunta.

Comment: vou fazer uma pergunta de teste. Se vocês cancelarem...

Comment: Shell scipt cai em programação, agora perguntas de sistemas operacionais não tenho ideia do que seja, poderia colocar mais de um exemplo desse tipo de pergunta.

Comment: Exemplo: Como faço para instalar o PHP e escolher a versão que eu quero via terminal no Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Essa eu acho que seria aceita, já que o PHP é uma linguagem de programação. Já algo como "O GIMP não abre" não seria aceito.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Claro! O stackoverflow é uma comunidade que engloba todas as plataformas e linguagens, no entanto, existem certo padrões que devem ser seguidos para garantir a qualidade das perguntas.

O texto abaixo foi retirado desse post
[Stack Overflow em português é somente o StackOverflow em português ou é mais abrangente?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/112/stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas-%c3%a9-somente-o-stackoverflow-em-portugu%c3%aas-ou-%c3%a9-mais-abr/119#119) 
:

> **Pode ser perguntado tudo que seja:**
>
> • um problema específico sobre programação
>
> • um algoritmo de software
>
> • uma ferramenta normalmente usada por programadores
>
> • problemas práticos que podem ser respondidos e que sejam únicos para
>   desenvolvimento de software
>
> **Perguntas de baixa qualidade que não tornam a internet melhor não
>   podem ser feitas, isso inclui:**
>
> • Questões gerais sobre software ou hardware. Mesmo aquelas que são
>   úteis para o desenvolvedor em algum momento da vida dele. Precisa
>   estar relacionado ao trabalho de desenvolvimento em qualquer fase.
>   Muitos desenvolvedores exercem outras atividades em conjunto com o
>   desenvolvimento e muitas vezes nem se dá conta disso. Não podemos
>   cobrir tudo o que o desenvolvedor por acaso exerce.
>
> • Questões com problemas de código que NÃO descreve o problema
>   específico e que não contenha um trecho de código válido que pode ser
>   reproduzido. Veja o guia SSCCE(em inglês)
>
> • Questões que NÃO demonstrem um mínimo entendimento do problema
>   perguntado. Um site de Q&A não é tutorial ou curso para iniciantes, é
>   um site de perguntas e respostas. Ajuda quando o autor da pergunta
>   coloca o que ele tentou, porque não funcionou e os resultados
>   esperados. Um checklist(em inglês) foi escrito pela lenda.
>
> • Questões sobre servidores, redes ou infraestrutura, a não ser que
>   elas estejam relacionadas a programação como scripts e instaladores
>   (não instalação). aqui cabe discussão mais aprofundada
>
> • Questões pedindo recomendação ou pesquisa de opinião sobre
>   ferramentas, metodologias e recursos de informação externos ao SOpt
>   NÃO fazem a internet melhor. Pode-se colocar alguma coisa na tag wiki
>   para ajudar iniciantes terem uma referência de onde começar. É
>   possível obter recomendação fazendo uma pergunta que possa ter uma
>   resposta razoavelmente objetiva. É obrigação do autor fazer a pergunta
>   que facilite a resposta nesses termos.

Comment: Não sei se é assim tão claro...

Comment: Por isso é que eu perguntei, @JorgeB. rsrsrsrsrs

Comment: Não é bem assim não, @Fernando. Dê uma olhada nesse tópico.  http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264

Comment: Minha resposta acabou tendo pouca fundamentação, segue um texto encontrato em outra reposta