# Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?

Tags: debate, escopo-do-site, big-7, votação

IMPORTANTE

Esta pergunta é do começo do site, e foi utilizada como diretriz enquanto o site estava amadurecendo. Muitas das discussões aqui foram melhor detalhadas e discutidas em postagens mais novas, e novos entendimentos criados depois da não aceitação de termos um SuperUser em português, novos sites da rede sendo criados e outros tópicos discutidos individualmente.

Atenha-se a documentação do site como um todo e a outras postagens do Meta para verificar de fato o que está dentro do escopo ou não.

Consulte a [lista completa de sites da rede](https://stackexchange.com/sites) para ver se não há um mais específico para sua dúvida.

---

Essa é uma pergunta do tipo *poll question* para avaliarmos como os membros pensam sobre o que deve estar em tópico aqui.

Se tem algum item não coberto, não se acanhe, poste uma resposta com esse item para votarmos.

Se você deseja debater algum item específico em profundidade, não hesite em abrir uma pergunta específica para isso, como feito [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/98/perguntas-gerais-sobre-computadores-no-topico).

Lembre-se que **perguntas ruins não serão aceitas nunca**. Aqui não se debate se deve aceitar algo ruim de um tópico. Algo ruim já está certo que não se aceita. Nada! A questão é se devem ser aceitas **perguntas boas** dos tópicos relacionados.

A intenção desta pergunta é ter uma referência mais completa que a Central de Ajuda para os membros mais ativos da comunidade usarem nas suas decisões e avaliar a receptividade da comunidade sobre assuntos polêmicos.

Vou evitar colocar em votação os assuntos que eu acredito são (quase) unânimes, basicamente o que já foi possível perceber que não há polêmica aqui no SOpt, como foi discutido [nesta pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1412/7261).

Então os itens à seguir já são considerados dentro do escopo do SOpt (os itens que entraram em votação, alguns eram aceitos de forma óbvia, mostram os apoiadores e detratores entre parenteses):

- Problemas práticos específicos sobre programação que podem ser respondidos.
- Conceitos sobre algoritmos e estrutura de dados.
- Algoritmos de software específicos para uma linguagem ou independentes.
- Ferramentas normalmente usadas por desenvolvedores exercendo sua função programando, depurando, preparando ou implantando softwares e controlando o processo.
- Padrões de projeto (design patterns).
- Programação de banco de dados do lado do cliente.
- Personalização (programação) de ferramentas de CMS como WordPress, Drupal, Joomla, PHPBB, Magento, SalesForce, SharePoint, etc.
- Modelagem de dados, diagramas ER e assemelhados. (28/1)
- Arquitetura e engenharia de software. Conceitos e prática. (37/0)
- Qualquer pergunta de banco de dados que envolva SQL em servidor (não ligado ao desenvolvimento de software em si). (35/0)
- Programação de Stored Procedures e gatilhos. (35/0)
- Expressões Regulares - Regular Expressions - Regex. (18/1)
- Criptografia (programação, conceitos e uso). (37/0)
- Técnicas e ferramentas para verificação de segurança de softwares. (22/0)
- Políticas e metodologias usadas para evitar o comprometimento de softwares. (22/0)
- Ataques comuns em softwares. (22/0)
- Experiência e interface com usuário (utilizador). (33/0)
- Projeto/implementação de compiladores e linguagens de programação. (32/1)
- Projeto/implementação de Sistemas de Gestão de Bancos de Dados (relacional ou não). (20/0)
- Projeto/implementação de Sistemas Operacionais. (20/0)
- Desenvolvimento de testes em geral. (27/0)
- Garantia de qualidade (Quality Assurance). (27/0)
- Code Review (Pedido de análise de código específico). (34/2)
- Inteligência artificial em geral. (32/2)
- Ciência da computação em geral (teoria). (26/1)
- Técnicas de domínio específico para um sistema (Ex.: checagem de CPF, cartões, consumo de web services específicos, padronizações, legislações que afetem sistemas). (22/1)
- Desenvolvimento de scripts para servidores. (23/0)
- Visão Computacional, manipulação programática de imagens ou vídeos e assuntos relacionados. (21/1)
- Dificuldades técnicas e administrativas (legais) com publicação de aplicativos, incluindo licenças e documentação. (21/2)
- Otimização. Ex: como resolver um problema de forma mais rápida, ou com menos memória. (16/1)
- Atividades de Data Warehousing e Business Intelligence, incluindo relatórios e OLAP. (17/0)
- Customização no desenvolvimento de ERP ou outros softwares administrativos (SAP e afins) sem envolver código. (30/8)
- Processamento de sinal e assuntos relacionados. (31/9)

Se discorda de algum item, coloque-o em votação, Mas já adianto que ele foi testado antes e foi bem aceito.

Comment: Teremos um [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) Pt algum dia? Acho q temos muito espaço para isso além do que ajudaria a evitar perguntas _off-topic_ no SO Pt.

Comment: @Math Quem sabe um dia. Mas vamos nos concentrar em fazer deste site um sucesso. Só assim poderemos pensar em outro.

Comment: Francamente, no início do SOEN tinha muita coisa off-topic, e muitas delas serviram para impulsionar o site, assim como para criar as especializações do site (leia-se rede do StackExchange)... perguntas off-topic (que tenham o mínimo de interessante para um desenvolvedor) deveriam ser mantidas como forma de criar uma pressão para a criação de outros sites StackExchange em PT... tipo, alguém vai no http://area51.stackexchange.com/ cria uma proposta e começa a angariar votos nas questões off-topic... até ter sucesso. É como se fossem portas abertas... não acho que devemos fechá-las.

Comment: Queria só deixar registrado o formato muito legal que [o pessoal do Meta TeX arrumou pra fazer *Poll Questions*](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1564). No Meta SO a idéia [não teve muito sucesso](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203047/185667) porém...

Comment: @bfavaretto os assuntos abaixo, nas respostas, com pontuação positiva (por exemplo, +7/-6 = 1) estão dentro do escopo?

Comment: @JorgeB. Pelo jeito qualquer tópico está dentro, basta 2 ou 3 pessoas acharem que está dentro, não importa se a pessoa só está querendo atender seu interesse específico, não importa se as pessoas que realmente se comprometem acham o contrário. No SOpt é assim, eme nenhum outro *site* da rede é assim, mesmo os criados depois do SOpt, mas aqui nós temos que engolir isto.

Comment: @bigown https://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=SOPtMesaDeBar

Comment: Pronto, agora o SOPT já é um sucesso e temos a proposta do SUPT no ar :D

Comment: @Math Pronto, agora o SOPT já é um sucesso, e temos a proposta do SUPT derrubada do ar :'( `#FreeSUPT`, `#Je Suis SUPT`

Comment: @VictorStafusa realmente :D

Answer (score 22):

- Gerência de Projeto específico para desenvolvimento de software (Agile, Scrum, RUP, etc.)

Answer (score 22):

- Arquitetura de engine de jogos existentes.
- API de games específicos existentes (uso da API).
- Projeto/implementação de *engines* para jogos.

Answer (score 20):

Localização para o português - ferramentas e técnicas de tradução de softwares, frameworks, templates e similares.

Comment: +1 Acho que já faz parte do escopo, só mesmo para formalizar.

Answer (score 17):

- Técnicas de Hacking, Pentest e técnicas de invasão.

Comment: Concordo, não há motivo de esconder conhecimento, não importa o tipo.

Comment: Eu diria que estas perguntas podem ser sempre formuladas do ponto vista do defensor e nao do ponto de vista do atacante. O que eu quero dizer é que é totalmente legitimo saber como o ataque é feito, mas mais importante que isso, saber a forma de se defender do ataque.

Comment: Mas é muito complicado o defensor defender sem saber por onde será atacado. O problema, até onde eu vejo, não é saber de vulnerabilidade x ou y, mas como proceder para defendê-las (ou atacá-las, ninguém sabe se o intuito é mostrar a falha pra alguém), mas, sem saber como atacar, nunca saberemos como defender, na minha concepção.

Comment: Lembrando que sempre tem que ser aplicado ao desenvolvimento de software (por exemplo, como as perguntas que já temos sobre como evitar um SQL Injection (e não como se proteger de um HeartBleed no OS, claro).

Answer (score 15):

- Dúvidas sobre como utilizar o Excel ou similar: LibreOffice Calc e OpenOffice Calc.

**Inclui:** dificuldades ao usar/criar fórmulas, tabela dinâmica, macros, filtros. (transformação de dados é programação, mesmo se feita visualmente)

**Exclui:** dúvida de como instalar tais ferramentas, alterar cor, formatação simples.

Comment: +1 se e só se se cingir a isso mesmo, e que não comecem a chover pedidos de ajudas "como formatar tabelas", etc...

Comment: @JorgeB. eu criei por causa dessa pergunta aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/18879/3117 que estão votando para fechar. Realmente, ajuda como formatar é de doer, eu pensei nas coisas mais avançadas, como macros e fórmulas, por mim podem ser consideradas dentro do escopo. Talvez eu devo melhorar a resposta e deixar mais claro, mas acho que vou esperar para ver se alguém mais se manifesta.

Comment: Também acho que está dentro do escopo, é deixar para ver...

Answer (score 12):

SEO, White Hat e Black Hat (Otimização que segue ou não diretrizes para melhorar o posicionamento em motores de busca)

Comment: Cabe notar que temos uma tag [`seo`](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo), e que atualmente das 9 perguntas 7 tem avaliação positiva, e 2 neutras. Sugiro a todos reavaliar as razões pelas quais esse tópico está desfavorável (se possível, comentando aqui por que acha que esse tipo de pergunta é indesejável no site).

Comment: Eu utilizo técnicas de SEO recomendadas pelo Google e elas são importantíssimas pro meu site (uma pizzaria delivery que está muito bem posicionada na pesquisa, atraindo vendas). A documentação está na internet, mas seria muito bom poder encontrá-las aqui através de perguntas, pois temos a chance de pedir explicações mais detalhadas para quem entende bem. Obs: Algumas técnicas estão totalmente ligadas a programação, visto que se utilizam de tags específicas (rich snippets) e não são poucas.

Answer (score 12):

Assuntos relacionados a hospedagem, deploy, escalabilidade e computação em nuvem

Comment: Acho que tens isso muito abrangente. Assuntos relacionados como assim? programação? opinião? melhor solução para x problema?

Comment: @JorgeB. Perguntas que não sejam baseadas em opinões e que estejam relacionadas ao tópico.

Answer (score 8):

**Dúvidas ou erros na utilização ou configuração de Softwares**

**Exemplo**:

- Mensagens de erro no processo de instalação de um software
- Mensagens de erro ao iniciar um software ( instalou mas não inicia o programa )
- Mensagens de erro durante o funcionamento do software

**Exemplo de programas que pode aconter isso**:

- Mysql
- Apache
- Tomcat
- Eclipse
- NetBeans
- Samba
- Etc....

---

**Edit**

**Softwares estes que sejam comum entre pessoas da area de TI e/ou utilizados pelos mesmos**

Comment: Sua sugestão se refere a **qualquer** software? Ou software que estejam envolvidos no processo de programação em si.

Comment: Editei para para deixar mais claro

Answer (score 1):

Administração e configuração do servidor de banco de dados, incluindo *backup* e afinação (tunning). Assunto não relacionados diretamente com o desenvolvimento em si.

Answer (score -3):

- SEO, Mecanismos de busca, Design de websites ([webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/))

Comment: Acho que esta questão está recebendo votos negativos por causa da palavra "Design".

Comment: @Orion eu votei down pelo SEO.

Comment: @Bacco acho que o certo era separar em tópicos, pois não faz sentido a escolha de um anular os outros.

Comment: @Orion concordo. Mas só pra ficar claro, considere minha resposta como "votei down principalmente por causa do SEO" :)

Comment: @Bacco, como você disse ser contra o SEO sugiro comentar [nessa resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1460/8917) o por quê.

Answer (score -6):

- Orçamento de projetos de software
- Questões relativas à contratação de terceiros para projetos de desenvolvimento (seja do ponto de vista do contratante [terceirização] ou do contratado [mais comum])

Comment: Embora eu ache um assunto interessante e eu próprio gostaria de saber mais, acho que não se encaixa no escopo do SOpt, porque as perguntas acabam por ser baseadas em opiniões.

Comment: Um exemplo de pergunta real: [Como fazer o orçamento inicial de um projeto de software?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23185/3117)

Comment: Acho a pergunta interessante, e ainda que abra espaço para opniões, pode ser útil ao mostrar as técnicas que os usuários do SOpt utilizam e isso pode ajudar outra pessoas com a mesma dúvida e até mesmo desenvolvedores iniciantes.

Comment: Acho que este tópico tem ligação com programação, visto que certo programas são calculados por linha de códigos, fora que a tecnologia utilizada para o desenvolvimento e manutenção do programa influencia no orçamento.

Answer (score -9):

- Dúvidas sobre treinamento e certificação em tecnologias relacionadas a programação.

Comment: Dúvidas sobre as certificações sim. Dúvidas sobre qual a importância de uma certificação como a que foi linkada para essa questão absolutamente não (o único propósito para essas questão é gera polêmica).

Comment: Só para acrescentar, [essa é a pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7766/3117) que foi linkada. Partilho da sua opinião @AnthonyAccioly

Comment: Já teve também gente perguntado em que site se cadastrar para tirar certificação: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9387/qual-o-site-para-tirar-a-certificacao-java

Answer (score -12):

Configuração de redes, *firewalls*, *proxies*, etc.

Comment: Eu sou contra, mas não posso votar contra na minha própria resposta.

Comment: A limitação no conhecimento sobre redes e firewall tem deixado muitos programadores com dor de cabeça. Essa seria uma excelente oportunidade de mudar a cena.

Comment: +1 eu tive muitas dificuldades inicialmente para aprender esse tipo de coisas, acho que seria bom alguma coisa em PT

Answer (score -12):

Uso de ferramentas de produtividade como editor de texto (não de código), planilhas, gerência de projetos, etc. É o uso básico mesmo, formatação, opções do menu, instalação.

Comment: É um contraponto para http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1436/101. Precisamos ver qual é o limite do assunto. Não considerem meu post como um voto favorável, sou contrário a ideia.

Comment: Poderia dar exemplos? Seria Word, Excel, MS Project? É isso?

Answer (score -13):

- Tendências de linguagens de programação.

Comment: Acho que isto cabe discussão em separado. Me parece que este não é um tópico a ser considerado na votação já que ele tem um problema por si próprio que é a especulação sobre o futuro. Aconselho discutir o assunto melhor em outra pergunta, quem sabe reverte os votos negativos, embora eu duvide. Para limpar a votação acho que seria melhor remover esta resposta. Dependendo do debate específico do assunto, voltamos colocar em votação, quem sabe na próxima, tenha mais chance de sobreviver.

Comment: @bigown acho difícil esse tópico conseguir votos positivos mesmo explanando mais sobre a questão, não é nem por causa do assunto poder ser subjetivo, mas sim porque creio que não faz parte do escopo de perguntas ligadas a programação, eu vejo esse assunto hoje mais como caráter informativo.

Answer (score -15):

- Produtividade pessoal e técnicas de administração do próprio trabalho.

Comment: Este tópico é essencial para todo profissional de TI.

Comment: poderia dar um exemplo? ficou vago para mim

Comment: O item foi retirado de outra questão, mas pelo que entendo poderia englobar perguntas como encontro frequentemente no <http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/>. Exemplos: "é justo cobrar do cliente o tempo que gastei pesquisando?", "Existe um processo específico para um projeto com apenas uma pessoa?", "É antiético ler livros durante o horário de trabalho?".

Comment: @Math Eu coloquei esse item porque são questões que todos passamos alguma vez na carreira e, embora as respostas geralmente sejam baseados em opiniões, seria muito interessante contar com experiência de pessoas mais maduras que podem responder com propriedade, quase objetivamente, à questão. No entanto, eu compreendo que seria um grande problema gerenciar opiniões toscas de alguns usuários. Eu acredito que, se bem gerenciadas, essas questões poderiam gerar um conteúdo de muita qualidade, o que não seria alcançado no formato de fórum.

Comment: Cara, gostei.. +1

Comment: +1 muito interessante

Answer (score -15):

- Assuntos relacionados a mercado de trabalho e contratações.
- Plataformas de busca de vagas e currículos.
- Assuntos relacionados com trabalho freelance.

--

**OBS**: Não contempla propostas de emprego. Para tanto use o [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score -16):

- Perguntas de entrevista, "pegadinhas", etc.

Comment: Acho difícil achar uma única resposta correta no meio de inúmeras quando o assunto é tão abrangente. Isso tá mais pra um fórum que um site de Perguntas e Respostas.

Comment: **Code Golf** no mesmo tópico que os demais é um pouco complicado. Perguntas de entrevistas e "pegadinha" soa com um tom bem mais negativo do que code golf e certamente puxou esse tópico para baixo.

Comment: Concordo com o Emerson, acho que Code Golf deveria estar separado.

Comment: Coloquei o Code Golf separadamente em outra resposta.

Answer (score -22):

- Ambiente de trabalho e políticas de escritório.

Comment: Difícil de vingar, mas depois de acompanhar por alguns meses  o [workplace.stackexchange.com](http://workplace.stackexchange.com) considero um tema muito bom e produtivo.

Comment: A pergunta [Qual a diferença entre trainee, júnior, pleno, sênior?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8116/qual-a-diferenca-entre-trainee-junior-pleno-senior) faz parte desse item? Pra mim parece que sim, e é justamente um exemplo em que o assunto extrapola os limites da área de desenvolvimento de software (que eu entendo como o foco desse site) e por isso seria *off-topic*.

Comment: @LuizVieira A primeira parte da pergunta eu não sei, mas a segunda sobre atribuição de tarefa com certeza. Eu concordo que seja *off-topic* quanto à programação, mas discordo completamente sobre "extrapolar os limites da área de desenvolvimento de software". Na semana passada tivemos aqui na empresa uma discussão sobre o que um Junior poderia ou não fazer numa tarefa de desenvolvimento. É um assunto que todo desenvolvedor e todo líder enfrenta. Desenvolvimento de software, se você ler os grandes autores, é afetado muito mais por pessoas do que por tecnologias. Mas, enfim, não é programação.

Comment: @LuizVieira Porque não manter esse tipo de pergunta? Me parece que é algo que possa ser respondido por um desenvolvedor, e talvez possa ser respondido por todos os desenvolvedores experientes. Fazer pudim não é algo que todos os desenvolvedores saberiam responder, talvez nem tenham interesse, mas essa pergunta me parece interessante o suficiente para a maioria dos desenvolvedores que eu conheço.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Eu gostaria de ter esse tipo de pergunta, mas ao mesmo tempo entendo perfeitamente que é complicado gerenciá-las para não virar pedidos de conselhos pessoais. Infelizmente, acho difícil termos logo um site como o "workplace" em Português. Faz uns 6 meses que eu acompanho o "workplace" e já aprendi muita coisa, porém muitas que não se aplicam aqui no Brasil. Por enquanto, tem que torcer para perguntas boas desse tipo vingarem individualmente.

Comment: @utluiz De pleno acordo!

Comment: @utluiz Por "extrapola os limites" eu quero dizer que vai além do escopo de desenvolvimento e não que o exclui. Esse tipo de definição (de cargos) pode ter semelhanças em diferentes áreas, de forma que argumentos sobre o que um júnior pode/deve ou não fazer não necessariamente se manterão em critérios técnicos da nossa área. Você tem razão em relação ao aspecto humano, mas eu só tenho receio que esse argumento seja muito genérico e possa abrir espaço pra questões que não iremos conseguir justificar ou refutar. Ou seja, *talvez* o SOPT não seja o melhor lugar pra esse tipo de conteúdo.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Há muita coisa que desenvolvedores são capazes de responder e nós não incluimos no escopo, como é possível perceber em alguns tópicos acima nesta mesma página. Acho que o ponto não é esse, e sim a respeito do tópico ser ou não justificável. Manter a pergunta é aceitar o tópico como sendo pertinente ao escopo.

Comment: -1 baseada em opiniões e *offtopic* para a pergunta [Qual a diferença entre trainee, júnior, pleno, sênior?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8116/7210)

Comment: @JorgeB. Conceitos como "júnior", "pleno" e "sênior" são universalmente usados. Obviamente há variações e interpretações, mas isso também vale para qualquer outro princípio não matemático (orientação a objetos, metodologias, melhores práticas de codificação). Portanto, não considero essa pergunta totalmente baseada em opiniões. Mas realmente é *off-topic*, embora eu preferisse que ela fosse aceita.

Comment: Não é totalmente baseada em opiniões mas tenho a certeza que é o que vai acontecer. Eu as vezes gosto da pergunta e das respostas que poderia vir. Mas temos de pensar: Será que é realmente isso que vai acontecer @utluiz? Eu tento não votar quando tenho dúvidas porque as vezes é difícil avaliar...

Comment: Mais uma coisa, acho que futuramente poderíamos ter um outro site pt mo SE. Um que englobasse perguntas que não se encaixem diretamente na programação.

Comment: @JorgeB. Ótima a ideia de ter um outro site. Poderíamos pensar e formular uma proposta futuramente.

Comment: @utluiz talvez um site que englobasse mais esse tipo de conteúdo. pt.trabalho.stackoverflow.com ;)