# Quais motivos de fechamento devemos ter em "descontextualizada > outros"?

Tags: debate, razões-fechamento

Hoje, as opções de voto para fechar perguntas descontextualizadas (*off-topic*) são:

- A pergunta não é sobre programação, conforme a definição presente na central de ajuda
- A pergunta pertence a outro site da rede
- Outro motivo

<sup>No momento esses textos ainda estão em inglês.</sup>

Em outros sites da rede existem mais opções prontas – por razões diversas, incluindo evitar que os usuários abusem da opção "outro motivo".

Devemos ter outras opções aqui também? Quais? É possível derivar essas opções das posições que já temos na [lista de assuntos que compõem ou não nosso foco](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264?)?

Comment: Quais questões já foram fechadas por "outro motivo" aqui no site? Não me recordo e já ter acontecido

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal A que inspirou minha pergunta foi esta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5291/sucess-ajax-retorna-200-ok-mas-retorno-json-nao-e-exibido