# Fechamento devemos ter em “descontextualizada > outros” e publicação em App Stores

Tags: debate, perguntas, razões-fechamento, perguntas-fechadas

Temos uma pergunta sobre [publicação de aplicativos na App Store da Apple](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4507/autorizacao-de-empresa-para-submissao-de-app) suspensa por motivo de não ser sobre programação. E realmente não é, mas é tão intricicamente ligado com o motivo porque se programa para iOS (iPhone e iPad) que não faz nem sentido programar se não for colocar na App Store.

Sei que aqui temos como motivo da pergunta estar descontextualizada ela [não ser de programação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/835/quais-motivos-de-fechamento-devemos-ter-em-descontextualizada-outros), mas gostaria de discutir aqui se não devemos abrir uma exceção para os processos de publicação em stores, que temos algumas:

- Google Play no Android
- AppStore no iOS
- Windows Store no Windows 8 e Windows Phone

Muita gente vai ter dúvidas sobre esse processo, principalmente quem está iniciando ou nunca publicou. Quem sabe marcamos esse tipod e perguntas com uma tag especial ou algo similar, mas creio que devemos permití-las

Comment: Relevante: o tópico está com +3/-1 na lista/enquete do que é on-topic. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/791/74

Comment: Agora está +8/-1, @bfavaretto.

Answer (score 5):

A minha opinião é, foi e será sempre que o SOPT é um site sobre programação e tudo a ela relacionado.

A ideia base de ter um site sobre programação em Português é podermos discutir, ensinar e aprender sobre as diversas coisas com o qual o programador tem que lidar no seu dia a dia.

Quando estamos a desenvolver algo, precisamos de:

- Utilizar um IDE ou outro programa para o efeito;
- Realizar testes;
- Saber técnicas do sistema operativo alvo;
- Saber sobre a linguagem em uso;
- Saber sobre compatibilidade ou outros potenciais problemas;
- Interagir com API's de terceiros;
- Publicar aplicações desenvolvidas;
- Optimizar código;
- Refatoração de código.

Estes tópicos e muitos outros carecem aprendizagem e/ou ensinamento sendo ideais para um site como o SOPT.

De notar que mesmo no SOEN vejo muita pergunta no foro da mesma a que te referes:

- Exemplos Apple:

  - [iPhone - App store: Regarding the Document of permission of use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17127860/352449)
  - [Will Apple reject my app if uses custom fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13594007/352449)
- Exemplo Android:

  - [Android app publishing language question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6011056/352449)
  - [Google Play Beta testing without a published app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16836873/352449)

<sup>Os exemplos podem não ser os melhores mas é só para ilustrar que as duvidas existem e são aceites pela SE. No caso do SOEN existem outros sites para onde perguntas deste género podem ser migradas, mas no caso do SOPT não, pelo que devem ser tratadas aqui mesmo!</sup>

São perguntas que tratam problemas com os quais o programador tem que lidar, e se estamos a criar um site para os programadores que falam Português, não vejo porque devam ser rejeitadas perguntas como essa.

---

**Nota:**
Convém salientar que concordo com perguntas que espelhem dificuldades em trabalhar com "mercados de aplicações", mas não vamos andar a discutir processos burocráticos, para isso usa-se o chat. Estou a deixar esta nota porque a pergunta em questão fala em documentos a enviar para a Apple, acho que "papelada" já foge um pouco ao âmbito da programação, mas podem achar que está na área cinzenta:

[image: Área cinzenta]

Votem e ajudem a decidir:

## [Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/791/223)

> Dificuldades (técnicas e administrativas) com publicação de aplicativos (apps) em mercados online (Apple Store, Play Store, Chrome Web Store, etc).