# Como uma pergunta dessa pode ter tanta pontuação

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, pergunta-subjetiva

Pergunta 100% por opinião pessoal, mas ninguém fechou ela

[As mensagens de erro devem se desculpar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2539/as-mensagens-de-erro-devem-se-desculpar)

Comment: Entendi absolutamente nada. Pode explicar melhor seu ponto de vista?

Comment: Usabilidade não é uma questão de opinião.

Comment: Esse assunto está como on topic [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/269/91)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Discordo que seja "100% por opinião pessoal" - ainda que admita que esse tipo de pergunta atrai respostas indesejáveis na prática. Entretanto, é uma pergunta que pode ser respondida objetivamente. A experiência do usuário (*User Experience* - UX, Usabilidade, etc), além de [estar no foco do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic/269#269) conforme decisão da maioria, é algo que pode sim ser estudado cientificamente e trazer resultados concretos, com impacto real nos sistemas e na sua percepção por parte dos utilizadores.

É claro, essa disciplina ainda que faça parte da Computação é mais *soft* que *hard* (i.e. não se baseia em regras axiomáticas rígidas e métodos formais de inferência e dedução). Isso torna mais difícil chegar a uma "resposta correta", no máximo teremos modelos que podem ser validados ou não via experimentação - e modelos diferentes testados em circunstâncias distintas podem apresentar resultados aparentemente conflitantes. No fim, cabe ao leitor interpretar as respostas no contexto do seu problema atual, e não ter a expectativa irreal de que a solução terá 100% de sucesso (talvez no seu caso outras variáveis não consideradas nos experimentos anteriores estejam em jogo).

O importante é que essa pergunta "sobreviveu ao tempo": o número de repostas é grande (13) mas não é excessivo, e destas apenas três parecem somente expressar opinião, sem embasá-las em argumentos concretos (4 já foram excluídas, e das 3 votadas negativamente duas pelo menos tentaram argumentar - ainda que os argumentos não tenham sido bem aceitos). Se a pergunta é útil, *on-topic*, e não "tumultua" a comunidade, não há razão para que não seja bem-vinda aqui.

Comment: Concordo. Eu não gostava dessa pergunta inicialmente, e passei um bom tempo pensando como votar nela. Até que surgiu a resposta do Luiz Vieira, que achei excepcional. Provou que uma pergunta desse tipo pode receber boas respostas, e não somente ruído. Coloquei uma recompensa na pergunta para prestigiar essa resposta. Isso acabou atraindo muitos votos para a pergunta durante o período em que a recompensa esteve ativa (+20/-1 em 3 dias).