# Quais vão ser os tópicos do nosso site?

Tags: debate, escopo-do-site

Atualmente a nossa [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) contém essa instrução:

> Dê uma olhada para detectar se sua pergunta foi feita anteriormente. Também está certo fazer e responder à sua própria pergunta.
>
> Se a sua pergunta não for especificamente contextualizada para o Stack Overflow em Português, pode ser contextualizada para outro site do Stack Exchange. Se não existir nenhum site que aceite sua pergunta, você pode se comprometer ou propor um novo site em Area51, o local onde novas comunidades Stack Exchange são criadas democraticamente.

Convenhamos, isso diz nada sobre coisa nenhuma. Um tempo atrás houve uma tentativa de decidir o que faria parte do tópico do site:

[Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic)

Mas com, segundo meus cálculos, 26 mil assuntos diferentes esse post serve muito pouco de **instrução**, seja para novatos ou para os mais cascudos. A idéia da Central de Ajuda é servir de guia para que as pessoas saibam como o site funciona. Ter um artigo com 50 elementos diferentes é um jeito infalível de garantir que ninguém vai ler, muito menos entender, o que tá escrito lá.

Precisamos de uma definição de escopo que seja simples, rápida, fácil de entender e útil. À título de comparação, essa é a definição básica do SOEN:

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!
>
> ---
>
> O Stack Overflow é voltado para programadores profissionais e estudantes, pessoas que escrevem programas por amor. Acreditamos que as melhores perguntas no Stack Overflow têm sempre um pouco de código, mas se a sua pergunta tem a ver com...
>
> - um problema específico de programação
> - um algorítmo de software
> - ferramentas comuns entre programadores
> - problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software
>
> … então este é o lugar certo para fazer sua pergunta

4 regras. 4 regrinhas básicas que são fáceis de entender e servem como um guia muito útil sobre que tipo de perguntas são **imediatamente não aceitas**. O Help Center do SOEN tem mais alguns pontos, mas precisamos lembrar o tamanho deles, e essas regras são úteis lá. Não necessariamente aqui.

Precisamos definir que tipo de perguntas nós **definitivamente não queremos**, e essa lista é um ótimo começo. Alguém sugere mais ou ou dois pontos (ou uma alteração dos que já existem), para que sejam adicionados à nossa Central de Ajuda?

## Update

Nossa [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) foi atualizada com a sugestão desse post e a do @bfavaretto.

Comment: Possível duplicata de: [O que nossa documentação deve conter?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/565/223).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### A lista de assuntos *on-* e *off-topic*

A tentativa anterior, que você linkou, não foi pensada para substituir o que está na Central de Ajuda, mas para auxiliar a comunidade, durante o beta (e desde o beta privado), a determinar os assuntos que vamos aceitar e os que não vamos. Eu ainda considero aquilo um excelente material para podermos analisar e finalmente derivar o conteúdo que vai para a Central de Ajuda.

#### O texto da Central de Ajuda

Tem uma coisa na maneira como a discussão está formulada que está me confundindo:

> [...] servem como um guia muito útil sobre que tipo de perguntas são **imediatamente não aceitas** [...]. Precisamos definir que tipo de perguntas nós **definitivamente não queremos** [...]

A página de ajuda em questão é sobre os tópicos *permitidos* no site, mas você fala mais sobre o que seria *proibido*. Para o que se deve evitar existe um tópico separado na Central de Ajuda, conhecido como *[don't ask](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)*. Lá talvez seja o melhor lugar para colocar a sugestão do @Cigano, com a qual concordo, em relação a evitar perguntas que peçam recomendações ou gerem listas.

> 4 regras. 4 regrinhas básicas que são fáceis de entender e servem como um guia muito útil sobre que tipo de perguntas são imediatamente não aceitas. O Help Center do SOEN tem mais alguns pontos, mas precisamos lembrar o tamanho deles, e essas regras são úteis lá. Não necessariamente aqui.

Você quis dizer "imediatamente aceitas"? Essas 4 regras para mim não são fáceis de entender, são muito vagas. Talvez por isso mesmo outros as considerem fáceis de entender, pois se encaixam em muitas coisas diferentes. No SO isso é um problema, tanto que precisaram incluir um monte de conteúdo embaixo para tentar especificar. Só que desviaram da questão do *assunto* do site a acabaram focando no *formato* das perguntas (até porque essa confusão existe, por motivos técnicos, no próprio diálogo de fechar perguntas).

#### Redação sugerida

Partindo da sua tradução do inglês, sugiro algumas pequenas mudanças no texto. A principal é que condensei os tópicos em três, que me parecem um pouco mais específicos e menos redundantes (porém são mais longos, e por isso menos atraentes).

> O Stack Overflow é voltado para programadores profissionais e apaixonados por programação. Acreditamos que as melhores perguntas têm sempre um pouco de código, mas se a sua pergunta tem a ver com...
>
> - um problema específico no seu código ou algoritmo
> - ferramentas comuns entre programadores (IDEs, controle de versão, compiladores, shells)
> - problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software
>
> … então este é o lugar certo para fazer sua pergunta

Para responder sua pergunta objetiva, talvez possamos incluir como quarto item algo nesta linha:

- dúvidas teóricas sobre conceitos e práticas aplicados ao desenvolvimento de software

Um link para o *[don't ask](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)* em algum lugar dessa página também me parece uma boa ideia, já que qualquer um dos assuntos listados acima ainda pode gerar perguntas inadequadas (que fomentem basicamente respostas opinativas, por exemplo).

Comment: Sim, a sugestão do @Cigano tem mais a ver com o formato e não o conteúdo

Comment: @Gabe Complementei a resposta.

Comment: A lista anterior acho que faz muito sentido já que ainda estamos construindo o SO que gostaríamos ser quando crescer... Mas como lista definitiva eu concordo com o @Gabe. Se você quiser listar regras pra tudo vai ficar muito complexo. O melhor é deixar os princípios ali e no caso de "áreas cinzas", que se meta Meta nelas. :)

Comment: Quando digo "*perguntas que não queremos*", minha ideia é olhar para a lista de tópicos sob um olhar inverso. Ela pode ser insuficiente para determinar **todos** os tipos de perguntas que queremos, mas se uma pergunta não se encaixa em **nenhum** daqueles itens, certamente é uma que não queremos. Um conjunto vago de regras certamente não vai abordar todos os casos limítrofes, mas esses casos podem ser tradados à medida que acontecem. Poucas e pequenas regras já servem como um filtro bom o suficiente, para coisas que temos certeza que não se encaixam no site.

Comment: Eu concordo, sempre acho o fim daquela lista, os tópicos com placar negativo, mais interessantes para análise. O que tiro dali basicamente é que "não é programação, não vale". As regras da central de ajuda precisam ir um pouco além (já vão), mas é basicamente isso. @Gabe

Comment: Não sei se concordo com a condensação dos dois primeiros pontos em um só. Uma pergunta sobre um algorítimo pode ser feita sem que eu tenha necessariamente um problema de implementação. Não acredito que valha a pena exigir que as perguntas aqui sejam sempre práticas. Mas concordo com o ponto extra sobre práticas de desenvolvimento.

Comment: @Gabe Eu fundi os dois primeiros pontos porque "specific programming problem" não me diz muita coisa, e em português diz menos ainda (engraçado, né?). O "específico" não acrescenta, porque pode ser interpretado de várias maneiras. Aí achei essa solução de falar de código ou algoritmo, puxando do item de baixo. Mas não precisa ser sobre a *implementação* do algoritmo. Concordo que o ponto extra seria uma boa, desfaz essas dúvidas e abre caminho para perguntas mais teóricas.

Answer (score 6):

> Ter um artigo com 50 elementos diferentes é um jeito infalível de garantir que ninguém vai ler, muito menos entender, o que tá escrito lá.

Concordo em parte, realmente um usuário novo não vai ler nem entender todas essas regras. Isso é claro, caso algum usuário mais experiente tenha postado o link para o tópico que você linkou, caso contrário ele nem saberá da existência do mesmo.

Entretanto, eu acho que aquele tópico é um excelente guia para quem é mais experiente. Frequentemente eu visito ele quando surgem publicações na fila de análise que estão no meio termo, logo, através do tópico é possível embasar suas ações de acordo com a opinião da comunidade.

Eu faço isso e espero que todo mundo que analisa faça o mesmo, e quem não faz, que de alguma forma adquira esse hábito ao longo do tempo.

Entretanto existe um problema com aquele tópico (na minha opinião, é claro), ele é muito bagunçado! Mas eu não vejo uma forma melhor de levantar os assuntos on-topic até então, portanto que continue daquele jeito mesmo.

Eu acho que temos que ter **duas definições** do que é on-topic ou não:

- Uma simples e focada, para os iniciantes; e
- Uma complexa e abrangente, para ser discutida no meta.

---

Eu descobri recentemente que essa página que você citou pode ser alcançada através de um link dentro da página da central de ajuda que é listada quando se usa o magic link [ask], por isso ela deveria ter uma atenção especial, já que é uma das primeiras páginas que o iniciantes lerão ao chegarem no SOPT.

Graças a [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16802/3117) eu percebi a importância dessas regrinhas, e acho que deveríamos nos empenhar mais em defini-las, pois do jeito que está não instrui absolutamente ninguém a fazer a pergunta correta. Portanto aí vai minha contribuição:

> Caso sua pergunta seja sobre um dos assuntos:
>
> - Ajuda em algoritmos ou trechos de código;
> - Dificuldades com ferramentas de programação;
> - Problemas conceituais de arquitetura e gerenciamento de projetos de software.
>
> ...aqui é o lugar certo para fazer sua pergunta.

Sobre sua pergunta:

> Precisamos definir que tipo de perguntas nós definitivamente não queremos, e essa lista é um ótimo começo. Alguém sugere mais um ou dois pontos (ou uma alteração dos que já existem), para que sejam adicionados à nossa Central de Ajuda?

**Na minha opinião**, além disso, assim como no StackOverflow.com teríamos que ter as perguntas off-topic na mesma página das perguntas on-topic.

[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Para mim a lista off-topic seria :

> Entretanto, sua pergunta pode ser descontextualizada caso se encaixem em ao menos um dos tópicos abaixo:
>
> - Perguntas que não demonstram esforço que tornem a resposta muito ampla;
> - Recomendações de livros, sites e tutoriais;
> - Configurações de usuário, não-programador. Exemplo: configurações de computador, roteador, antivirus, etc;
> - Perguntas relacionadas a programação que não permitem que exista uma resposta certa ou errada, ou seja, pergunta que visam unicamente levantar um debate. [Exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/301/3117).

---

Existe outra coisa que eu estive pensando esses dias mas não encontrei como encaixar na minha resposta (talvez eu edite mais tarde, to meio sem tempo agora). Mas esses dias durante um almoço um amigo meu falou que leu numa revista de carros um comparativo entre dois carros similares, e a matéria hora citava pontos positivos de um modelo hora citava pontos positivos de outro modelo e foi assim item por item até encerrarem a matéria, e no final não ficou claro para ele qual carro era melhor, e isso deixou ele indignado pois parecia que a revista queria *tirar o corpo fora*, eu logo em seguida afirmei: *"- Mas é claro que eles não falaram qual carro era o melhor dentre os dois, pois o que você leu segundo eles mesmos era um **comparativo**, não era um **veredito**!"*. Ou seja, precisamos por muitas vezes enfatizar que aqui no SOPT a intenção é dar vereditos, respostas concretas e absolutas, por mais que as vezes existam respostas que se completam o foco não é deixar a resposta solta no ar, por isso temos a marcação de resposta correta, ou resposta que melhor ajudou ao autor da pergunta a solucionar o problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu também estava pensando nisso (veja o complemento/atualização na minha resposta). O *este site não é para você* já tem um lugar na central de ajuda, o http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: @bfavaretto tb estava pensando nisso oq? o don't ask?

Comment: É, formulei mal. É que li sua resposta quando estava terminando o update da minha e vi muitos pontos de contato. Um é que quatro regrinhas não bastam. Outro é que parece mais fácil orientar por meio do don't ask. A pergunta do Gabe acabou misturando o /help/on-topic e o /help/dont-ask

Comment: @bfavaretto é vdd, pois ele citou "Central de ajuda" como um todo, e pediu uma definição de escopo. Vou ler sua atualização logo logo.

Answer (score 3):

Perguntas de recomendações e listas de softwares, frameworks ou linguagens.

Se for o caso, essas recomendações e listas devem ir para o Wiki de uma tag.

Comment: Eu não consigo enxergar qual o problema de um usuário pedir uma recomendação, pode até ser uma resposta subjetiva, mas acho que indicações desse tipo pode contribuir sim para quem busca alguma referência baseado em experiências de outros usuários.

Comment: Porque é uma pergunta cuja resposta é baseada em opiniões, e nós aqui tentamos evitar esse tipo de pergunta porque uma pergunta dessa pode ter várias respostas, e é difícil determinar com objetividade qual é a correta.

Comment: Acho que a questão principal é se esse tipo de pergunta contribui ou não para a comunidade, pois apesar de ter muitas respostas e ser difícil de identificar a melhor, estas podem trazer novas informações sobre o tema da questão, além de servir como referência para aquele que perguntou. As vezes não é a resposta correta para nós, mas é uma resposta que irá contribuir para o autor tomar decisões.

Comment: @PauloMaciel A plataforma deste site foi construída para que as respostas sejam encontradas com agilidade, logo abaixo da pergunta, como a resposta aceita pelo autor e/ou mais votada pela comunidade. Em pedidos de recomendação, o resultado costuma ser uma longa lista de respostas, muitas do tipo "eu uso X e gosto", sem explicação dos motivos. Ou seja, respostas ruins (não necessariamente os produtos são ruins, mas as respostas sim). E com o passar do tempo, vários links quebram, e a resposta mais votada acaba se referindo a alguma tecnologia obsoleta.

Comment: @PauloMaciel O seu questionamento é feito *muitas* vezes. A chave é entender a diferença entre o SO e um fórum. O SO não é um fórum nem um site tipo wiki.