# Podemos reorganizar a pergunta sobre o que é on-topic?

Tags: debate, comunidade

Comecei reorganizar a pergunta de [votação de *on-topic*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/264/101). Ela serviu bem no início do site e ainda servirá. Não faz mais sentido ficar votando no que já ficou claro que a comunidade aceita.

Além disto não preciso ficar explicando mais certos detalhes para todo mundo.

Outro ponto é que a comunidade já consegue colocar lá novos assuntos por conta própria conforme a necessidade.

Minha proposta é **apagar as respostas que já são quase unânimes**. De fato eu já coloquei todos os itens neste estado diretamente na pergunta. Só falta apagá-los. O que acham? Podemos apagar? **Alguém tem alguma objeção**?

Se for aprovado, vou sugerir os autores apagarem e se algum não puder mais, veremos o que pode ser feito para limpar.

Isto é importante para **deixar a votação mais limpa e nos concentrar no que ainda gera polêmica**. Com muitas respostas, fica mais difícil votar.

Eu pensei até em apagar as respostas com muitos negativos, que são (quase) unânimes que não queremos. Mas talvez seja bom deixar lá. Quem sabe isso mude no futuro. Vamos dar a chance de aparecer pessoas que querem incluí-los. Alguém tem alguma sugestão para tirá-los da votação e ainda dar a chance deles se recuperarem (não que eu queira que eles se recuperem, mas precisamos ser justos :) )?

Também acho interessante que todas as respostas remanescentes sofram edição para permitir que as pessoas troquem o voto agora que podemos ter uma visão diferente do site.

Quero lembrar que qualquer decisão pode ser revertida a qualquer momento se necessário. Não é porque algo foi votado de um jeito que o assunto fica *on* ou *off-topic* para sempre.

Casos que não são unânimes mas que a comunidade parece gostar (vamos ver o que acontece, no futuro são candidatos a aceitação oficial):

cerca de 30% de dissidência no momento
- Gerência de Projeto específico para desenvolvimento de software (Agile, Scrum, RUP, etc.)
- Customização no desenvolvimento de ERP ou outros softwares administrativos (SAP e afins) sem envolver código.
- Dificuldades na instalação ou uso de ferramentas de desenvolvimento.

Me parece estranha a votação da última já que o uso da ferramenta foi muito bem votado.

40% de dissidência no momento
- Code Golf: desafios de escrever determinado algoritmo na maneira mais curta possível ou com algum tipo de restrição.
- Problemas administrativos ou legais relacionadas a software, como casos de uso e aplicação de licenças ou documentação requerida para publicação de aplicativos.

Este último me parece tão próximo "Dificuldades (técnicas e administrativas) com publicação de aplicativos (apps) em mercados online." que eu acho que uma simples edição nesta resolveria, acho que esta deveria ser excluída pela semelhança.

Coloquei novos assuntos "na roda", um deles parece que está para um caminho da aceitação também.

Editei todos os assuntos para os **usuários poderem trocar seus votos** se quiserem.

Comment: Talvez as que fossem "equilibradas" como a do code golf (tem resultado, porém com muita discórdia), devessem ficar. Creio que um ratio de 25 votos para apenas 5 pontos de resultado não seja nem parecido com unânime.

Comment: Dá uma olhada lá na lista que eu subi para a pergunta. Não subi nenhuma que não fosse (quase) unânime. Code Golf está longe disto. Ainda merece ficar para votação. A mais "polêmica" que peguei tinha 30 apoiadores e 4 negativos (1 deles é meu e eu poderia inverter o voto). E é algo que na prática está sendo sempre aceito. Ou seja, não peguei nada que ainda cabe debate.

Comment: Acho muito boa ideia mesmo. Só não percebi porque desta: Legislação e conceitos de domínio específico ligados a processos em geral não diretamente relacionados ao desenvolvimento (questões fiscais, financeiras, controle de materiais, contabilidade, etc.).

Comment: @bigown se for apagar as respostas que já são claramente aceitas na comunidade deve-se pelo menos registrá-las como já aceitas na pergunta, na minha opinião, é claro

Comment: Sobre as respostas com milhões de negativos, acho que devem permanecer já que ficam para o fim mesmo eles não causam problemas, para mim o ruído está nos assuntos com muitos votos, continuar votando neles não vai ajudar em muita coisa e vai tirar o foco dos tópicos que geram debate.

Comment: @Math não sei se entendi ou se você não viu a edição que eu fiz lá, as mais votadas (e que tem zero ou poucos negativos) já estão na pergunta.

Comment: @JorgeB. Foi engano meu, acabou ficando sem sem querer, obrigado por alertar, já vou arrumar.

Comment: @bigown fui eu que não vi _direito_ a atualização, por mim pode apagar então

Comment: Se for pra apagar respostas, acho que seria legal colocar o *score* na pergunta, como forma de registro histórico.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Para mim isso é totalmente válido.

Como o @Math já citou em comentários, a quantidade de opções gera muito ruído e a maioria das pessoas somente irá dar atenção aos primeiros itens.

Além disso, o que foi votado como *on-topic* dificilmente mudará. Os demais itens negativos ou "em dúvida" devem ficar ali como documentação e para dar possibilidade de novas discussões.

Enfim, a exclusão dos itens "unânimes" só vai trazer benefícios, no sentido de que vai possibilitar novas discussões sobre os demais tópicos.

Comment: Acho que podemos começar excluir entre hoje e manhã.

Answer (score 6):

Eu concordo em excluir as unanimidades, quanto mais ruído removermos dali, melhor. Só não sei qual será o destino da pergunta a partir daí. Devemos continuar postando novos itens para votação ali, ou abrir uma discussão à parte no meta sobre cada caso específico? Ou talvez ambos?

Considerando que já passamos do momento inicial do site, quando tudo estava em aberto, essa pergunta do on-topic está deixando de fazer sentido. É hora de [resumir nossas conclusões na Central de ajuda](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1216/quais-vao-ser-os-topicos-do-nosso-site).

Comment: Boa sub-questão. Eu acho que podemos colocar novos itens para sentir o que pensa a comunidade. Eu mesmo já coloquei alguns. Acho que sempre foi a intenção deixar a possibilidade de abrir um debate específico quando necessário. Esse debate pode ser servir como um catalizador de opiniões e quem sabe direcionar a votação para uma decisão definitiva. Particularmente não sinto necessidade ainda de abrir discussão para cada um dos itens polêmicos, acho que poderia ser orgânico como aconteceu como o Code Golf. Mas também não tenho objeção se alguém o fizer.

Comment: Não o quanto a Central de Ajuda pode ser usada para o detalhamento dos tópicos. Me parece que a Central é para orientar quem não conhece bem o aceito e isto provavelmente seria demais lá. Mas posso estar enganado. Em princípio, eu ainda vejo o meta como o local para o detalhamento. No fim, essa informação servirá para os moderadores e usuários mais ativos. Ela não é útil para o novato ou usuário mais eventual. Só uma opinião.

Comment: Concordo, a central de ajuda não serve pra detalhamento mesmo, isso é papel do meta. O que precisamos lá é um resumão do que vale e do que não vale. Casos pontuais a gente discute no meta.