# Desafios e code golf

Tags: debate, escopo-do-site

Olá, depois de fazer uma pergunta desafio para o pessoal, uma pessoa me disse que Code Golf não está no scopo do site e estaria votando para fechar a pergunta.
Bom, primeiramente, Code Golf pelo que eu sei se trata de resolução de problemas com o mínimo de linhas possível. Meu desafio não se enquadra nisso. E aquela mesma pessoa disse que Code Golf não está bem definida no site...
A minha pergunta foi essa: [Exibir de 1 até 1000 em C++ sem usar o ponto e vírgula](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16239/exibir-de-1-ate-1000-na-tela?noredirect=1#comment29895_16239)

Bom, eu gostaria que vocês me dissesem se eu posso postar desafios de programação, que envolvam ou não Code Golf, e caso não, não seria melhor se aceitasse? Não sei o porquê pessoas que não gostam da categoria defendem a não postagem delas...

Eu mesmo não gosto de algumas categorias, e eu não brigo para poder retirá-las do site.

Pois bem, o que vocês acham?

Comment: Você também pode participar da decisão: [*Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?*](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264/201)

Comment: Pra mim não faz muita diferença, não acho que atrapalharia o site no estágio atual, mas também não sei se ajudaria alguma coisa. Como é algo que cabe na ferramenta e não há outro site para colocar isso, porque não? Eu não gosto e prefiro não ver uma pergunta dessas, mas quando aparece não me causa urticária.

Answer (score 18):

## Por que não?

A grande questão é que mal este tipo de pergunta está fazendo no site?

Eu não gosto deste tipo de pergunta, mas não gosto muito mais de outros tipos que pipocam todos os dias.

Será mesmo que causa tão mal **hoje** que precise ser fechada? Temos tão poucas perguntas, a maioria que não ajuda ninguém além do OP, não faz quem responder ou quem lê aprender algo mais, que eu acho que é o grande objetivo de grande parte dos usuários aqui (exceto os *help vampires*, que são muitos).

Neste ponto eu concordo com o Gabe que o pessoal está muito preso a mentalidade dos piores usuários do SO. Nós temos tão poucas perguntas, porque não podemos ter alguma pergunta que pode nos ensinar alguma coisa?

**Ninguém é obrigado responder ou mesmo lê-las**. Dá o menos trabalho começar a ler uma pergunta assim e ignorar do que ler e fechar. O fato de nós não aceitarmos perguntas de Code Golf não significa que elas não aparecerão.

Porque precisamos nos concentrar tanto em limitar conteúdo que faz parte do trabalho de um programador quando temos tão poucas perguntas no site?

Não vamos aceitar todo tipo de de pergunta. Falando apenas no escopo (esquece os outros problemas que uma pergunta pode ter), pelo que observamos [nesta votação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic) e nos fechamentos existentes, parece claro que não há aceitação de perguntas de uso de computadores e softwares em geral (exceto ferramentas de desenvolvimento), redes, e administração de de sistemas. Além de carreira e ambiente de trabalho.

Dá para entender que não devamos aceitar tudo só porque tem a palavra programação. Mas desafios bem escritos (os demais não devem ser aceitos pelos seus próprios problemas específicos) é totalmente programação e ajudam as pessoas que se interessem por eles. É algo que é bem aceito na rede (**tem até um site especializado**) e não causaria mal no SO se tivesse continuado lá. Uma ou outra pergunta dessas por dia no meio de 7 mil perguntas por dia, não faz a menor diferença. Mesmo que aqui a proporção seja diferente, eu duvido que apareça muito mais que uma ou duas pergunta dessas por semana. Totalmente administrável.

Achei um erro o Code Golf ter sido separado do SO e se há demanda por ele em português, certamente não haverá um site separado para isto, então é aqui que deveremos aceitar.

E se ficar exagerado? Aí **pode** ser que tenhamos um problema e vamos lidar com ele. Mas precisamos tentar agora para ver o que acontece. E se der problema real, aí voltamos atrás.

Às vezes é melhor termos algumas perguntas fechadas indicando que elas estão lá por motivos históricos do que não ter nenhuma dessas perguntas para as pessoas verem e elas acabarem postando algo que vai ser fechado porque nem tem exemplo que ela seria fechada.

Antes de termos essas perguntas fechadas, elas precisam ser testadas. **Precisamos ver resultados**. Se eles não forem bons, teremos melhores subsídios para decidir por não aceitá-las. Fechar antes de dar a chance não ajuda o site evoluir.

Reforço que acho que uma pergunta deste tipo mal escrita deve ser fechada como qualquer outra. Este é o tipo de pergunta que precisa de mais cuidado para ser feita, mas sem olhar o conteúdo não para saber de antemão se ela é boa ou não. Ela se encaixa bem no funcionamento dos sites da rede e não precisa de nenhuma intervenção extra.

São perguntas difíceis de serem feitas e respondidas. Normalmente cada ponto ganho é merecido. Vamos votar se a pergunta é boa ou não, como qualquer outra. Vamos votar se uma resposta está correta e é útil como qualquer outra. Vamos avaliar código. Vamos ter respostas objetivas com código. Temos perguntas práticas (se o código pode ser aplicado na prática em produção, é outra estória) que podem ensinar alguma coisa para os usuários, mesmo que indiretamente. Não estamos falando de piadinha ou coisas que as pessoas podem ganhar reputação sem esforço, sem a sua resposta ter mérito. Claro que pode haver alguma distorção eventual, mas isso pode ocorrer com qualquer pergunta. Já vi inúmeros casos. Mas não vi o que acontece com Code Golf aqui. Não tive esta oportunidade.

**Não estamos mais no começo do site** que precisava dar o exemplo, não podia sair aceitando qualquer coisa. Usuários experientes que queriam o site, já estão nele, os demais vão aparecer ou fugir do site independente de ter algumas perguntas de Code Golf. Não precisamos ter a mesma preocupação que tínhamos no beta privado ou início do beta público (no fundo já estamos graduados, isto não ocorre oficialmente por questões políticas).

Realmente vocês acham Code Golf pior que "acha o erro aí pra mim" ou "não sei nada de como fazer isso e quero que alguém faça" que é o grosso das perguntas que temos aqui?

Eu entendo a preocupação mas acho que ela é exagerada. O **conteúdo aceito não está sendo o grande vilão do site** e acho que deveríamos ser um pouco mais permissivos com o escopo (não com a falta de qualidade do conteúdo, com a forma desorganizada dele).

Quem quiser que pesquise e veja que essa sempre foi minha posição. Eu abri a questão do *on-topic*, não compreendida por alguns, para ver o que a comunidade pensa. Dei meus votos pessoais, <strike>inclusive negativei o Code Golf</strike>, mas nunca me posicionei contra algum escopo, apenas contra o que fere a filosofia da rede, o que não é o caso.

Não acho que precisa muita coisa diferente neste tipo de pergunta. A forma deve ser específica, mas não acho que precisa da meta-tag [code-golf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) e nem indicar nada no título. Mas eu até aceitaria isto se ajudar a pergunta ser aceita. Talvez seja uma boa ter a meta-tag por um tempo para facilitar achar estas perguntas até termos certeza se elas ficam ou somem.

Como não sou moderador e meu voto não tem peso votei pela reabertura da pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16826/codegolf-escreva-um-programa-em-uma-linguagem-que-pareca-ser-em-outra-linguagem apesar de não achar uma pergunta maravilhosa. Mas é aceitável.

A comunidade parece dar indicações de divisão neste assunto. Não como vamos decidir em definitivo.

Em tópicos onde a comunidade está dividida lá na votação do *on-topic*, acho que a abertura de uma pergunta de debate específica, como esta, é muito importante para chegarmos a um resultado mais apropriado para toda a comunidade.

Então vamos deixar rolar e mais pra frente a gente vê se deu errado. Aí várias pessoas vão poder postar "eu te disse", ou quem sabe vão perceber que estávamos fazendo tempestade em copo d'água.

Comment: *"se há demanda por ele em português, certamente não haverá um site separado para isto, então é aqui que deveremos aceitar.*" **Exatamente**. . . . *"Realmente vocês acham Code Golf pior que "acha o erro aí pra mim" ou "não sei nada de como fazer isso e quero que alguém faça" que é o grosso das perguntas que temos aqui?"* **Não**.

Comment: exatamente isso.

Comment: Admito, alguns bons argumentos. Mas o meu particular receio com [tag:code-golf] é que essas perguntas acabem virando um fórum (pessoalmente não ligo muito pra questão da batalha por reputação). Fico imaginando o quão útil seria para a comunidade uma pergunta que tivesse uma centana ou milhar de respostas porque a pergunta, por mais bem feita que estivesse, estimulasse cada um a "participar com a minha ideia de pequena variação". Enfim, acho que a pergunta apropriada não é "por que não?" e sim "por que sim?".

Comment: Outra coisa: o raciocínio "Porque precisamos nos concentrar tanto em limitar conteúdo que faz parte do trabalho de um programador quando temos tão poucas perguntas no site?" vale pra muita coisa que nós como comunidade não permitimos (mas que, ainda que passível de argumentação, fazem parte do trabalho de um programador, como por exemplo [1](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1190/73) ou [2](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/284/73)).

Comment: @LuizVieira Eu entendo. Mas parece que o real problema vai ser achar quem queira responder essas perguntas :) Claro que pode mudar, pode aparecer uma pergunta que atraia não só um, como vários usuários respondendo. Mas eu acho que precisaria deixar algumas acontecer (se acontecer) e ver o que acontece. Eu te juro que vou ser o primeiro a reclamar de perguntas ruins e se aparecer várias que não está contribuindo para a boa saúde do site. Eu acho que podemos ir deixando outros conteúdos (desde que a pergunta seja bem feita) aos poucos, vamos evitar os que parecem haver pouca adesão por enquanto.

Comment: @bigown Sim, claro, também estou tentando ajudar (na medida do possível). Como eu disse, é apenas um "receio" meu - que espero honestamente que não se confirme. De todas as formas, parece que a comunidade já está [meio que se decidindo pró-code-golf](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1027/73). Então, democraticamente, deixa rolar. :) E se servir de jurisprudência para discussões futuras em outros tópicos, quem sabe isso também seja bom.

Answer (score 9):

Fiz hoje o teste com essa pergunta: [Escreva um programa em uma linguagem que pareça ser em outra linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16826/codegolf-escreva-um-programa-em-uma-linguagem-que-pareca-ser-em-outra-linguagem). Acredito ter escrito um code golf representativo que engloba todos os elementos.
O resultado do experimento veio rápido: fechamento e negativação.

---

Alguns pensamentos, divagações e opiniões sobre o assunto:

1. Desafios de codegolf exploram os limites de uma linguagem ou ferramenta. Seja por escrever um código absurdamente pequeno usando recursos obscuros ou por fazer algo incrível que não se achava ser possível com a linguagem. Após um codegolf bem sucedido, ler as respostas sempre trazem um monte de conhecimento novo e é algo interessante de fazer. Algumas submissões saltam aos olhos.
2. Codegolf pode vir a destruir o sistema de reputação. Por que é um tipo de pergunta que atrai muitos votos e eu tenho dúvidas sobre o valor que a reputação tem quando vem assim. Isso não é nenhum problema real, só um pensamento meu. Poucos codegolfs geram conhecimento real e muitos são apenas diversão que não me fariam falta se fossem deletados. Não sei, há controvésias.
3. O codegolf que você postou, está, na minha opinião, péssimo. O desafio é bastante limitado a uma linguagem só (não haverá variedade nas respostas, tem poucas formas de fazer isso). **Não há critérios para um ganhador**. Isso é fundamental se você pretende aceitar uma resposta. Duas opções: ou o jogo fica sempre aberto e nenhuma resposta nunca será aceita, ou existe um prazo limite e uma forma **objetiva** de classificar a melhor respostas. Seja essa forma o menor número de caracteres, ou a quantidade de votos (concurso de popularidade), ou o tempo de execução em um ambiente específico, ou qualquer outra coisa bem definida. Eu adicionei uma resposta e imediatamente você a aceitou. Isso fechou o codegolf com uma resposta só, o que não faz o menor sentido e tira todo o valor da coisa. Além disso tem uma mistura ali de um codegolf e de uma pergunta real. Acho que se perdeu.
4. Permitir codegolfs cria a necessidade de separar eles de perguntas normais. Eles são claramente diferentes e teriam regras ligeiramente diferentes, inclusive no tipo de resposta. Deve ser óbvio para quem olha que aquilo é um codegolf, para evitar respostas que sejam realmente respostas ou comentários de esclarescimentos. A solução é criar uma tag [code-golf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Mas... isso é uma enorme meta tag. E agora?
5. Não existe outro lugar ou alternativa para postar um code golf. Não é exatamente esse o propósito do Stack Overflow PT? Acolher esses tantos programadores desabrigados?
6. Se surgirem muitos codegolfs legais, eu vou trabalhar ainda menos! =(
7. Já vi forums morrerem após abrirem e permitirem uma sessão de "off-topic" onde acontecia todo o tipo de jogos. Acontecia de 90% do movimento do forum se concentrar nesses jogos e a produção de conteúdo sumir completamente. Não acho que isso possa acontecer assim, mas é um receio. Sei que forums são muito diferentes daqui, mas não deixa de ser uma comunidade com pessoas.

Minha mente engessada pelo SOEN ainda está em dúvida. Existe algum ponto forte de por que não devamos permitir codegolf aqui?

Comment: Boas colocações. Só discordo da premissa no item 4: se aceitamos essas perguntas, não precisa separá-las das demais perguntas, então não precisa da meta-tag.

Comment: Eu juro que pensei exatamente o que você escreveu no número 3. Deveria ter outro método quando se cria "pergunta" com desafios. Eu tentei esperar um tempo razoável, e como as outras respostas fugiram muito, te dei a melhor resposta. Porém concordo com você. Pode ser que a melhor estrutura para postagens desse tipo seja por popularidade, do tipo que nem o autor da pergunta possa votar na 'resposta correta'.

Comment: E comentando o que você disse no número 3; não faria sentido eu abrir para outras linguagens... Outras linguagens que eu conheço ficaria muito fácil de fazer o problema, não que seja difícil em C++, porém nas outras é muito fácil mesmo, na minha humilde opinião.

Comment: Acho que poderia deixar rolar e ver se causa problemas. Eu votei negativamente, mas não vejo um mal intrínseco de imediato.

Comment: Acredito que code golf torne o recurso de gamificação do site em uma pescaria de festa junina. Se fosse o caso de não atribuir toneladas de reputação para ambas a pergunta e as 300 respostas, talvez as coisas mudassem de figura.

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca Concordo. Por outro lado fazer dessas perguntas CW faria com que ninguém participasse. Não vejo forma razoável de encaixar o sistema de reputação. Isso continua me cheirando mal, parece peixe.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal exatamente meu ponto. Tire a "reputação fácil" e o jogo morre, logo, todos os outros argumentos que defendem o code golf caem, pois no final todo mundo que joga o faz pra ganhar pontinhos.

Comment: Apesar de no momento a comunidade estar pendendo para essa conclusão, as opiniões são divididas, como é possível ver na sua pergunta e na [discussão sobre o que é on-topic](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1027/74). Não dá pra concluir com tanta ênfase que "a comunidade não quer". Concordo 100% com a resposta do bigown abaixo, inclusive com o trecho sobre a meta-tag, que quase retirei da sua pergunta (da outra eu retirei na época).

Comment: Na verdade, desafios são legais, a maioria dos programadores gosta. Eu pessoalmente não gosto desse método de que ganha o menor código, mas gosto de desafios em geral. Se eles não dominarem o site (e não acho que dominariam), não vejo por que vetar.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu não quero meta-tag e acho que ela deveria ser retirada. Apenas toleraria ela em caso extremo. Prefiro que exista a pergunta sem necessidade de meta-tag. Só não vou impor nada. Eu aguardaria para ver o que o pessoal tem a dizer, mas depois eu iria lá e retiraria sem dó.

Comment: @bigown Sim, por isso deixei a tag por ora, enquanto a discussão está viva.

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca Eu respondo qualquer coisa no site para ganhar pontos, se não existe os famosos *fake internet points* que o Gabe tanto gosta de chamar, provavelmente eu não estaria aqui. Claro que a gamificação não é a única motivação, mas ela é fundamental para a maioria estar aqui. Eu não gosto de pontos ganhos sem nenhum esforço (coloca link, citar um livro, ou seja, ganhar sem ter dado uma resposta), mas ganhar pontos em cima de uma resposta, possivelmente bem difícil de produzir, qual o **problema real** nisto?

Comment: @bigown Problema real? Nenhum, assim como fazer piadinhas para ganhar upvotes não é problema real nenhum. Mas como bem disse o laurent,  O about do site já diz: [Faça perguntas, obtenha respostas, sem distrações. Este site tem o objetivo de obter respostas. Não é um fórum de discussão. Não tem bla bla bla.](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: @bigown Software recomendation também não tem *problema real* nenhum, mas também não tá no escopo e também vira concurso de popularidade.

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca não tem mesmo e até onde eu sei recomendação está sendo aceita desde que a pergunta seja feita corretamente. Não sei onde você viu que está fora de escopo. Talvez porque algumas pessoas fechem pelo motivo errado quando a pergunta é mal feita. Fazer piadinhas é um problema real, não acrescenta nada na vida profissional de nenhum programador. Code Golf não provoca discussões e consegue obter respostas, não é algo sem sentido que não ajuda ninguém a melhorar na profissão. Eu até li alguns argumentos contra interessantes, mas estes não argumentam nada contra.

Comment: @bigown essa mania de falar que "pessoas falam". Fui eu quem sinalizou o post porque acho que os malefícios surpassam e muito os benefícios em perguntas desse tipo.

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca ok, eu entendi que você acha isto, mas não há argumento contra. Eu vi argumentos na resposta do Guilherme e do Luiz. Consigo enxergar os problemas **poetenciais** que eles enxergam, apesar de eu achar que eles não vão causar mal ao site. No momento não estão causando.

Comment: @bigown todos sabemos que code golf valendo recompensas se transforma em _batalha dos egos_, e isso pra mim é um problema, na minha **opinião** joguinhos não cabem em um site de fazer perguntas e obter respostas **sem distrações**. Você pode não concordar com o meu argumento, afinal estamos em um debate.

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca E porque não podemos deixar rolar um pouco para ver se o que você diz se confirma?

Comment: @bigown Claro que podemos! Se for a vontade da comunidade, eu posso até não concordar, mas vou aceitar.

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca, o que eu entendo por `distrações` é *"nossa, que legal, nunca pensei nisso!"*, *"eu também tenho o mesmo problema*", *"fala galera, tudo bem, então, deixa eu dizer, tenho uma dúvida que tá me esquentando a cabeça"*. Lá no site [codegolf.se] também [**não tem distrações**](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Note que sua resposta mistura golfe de código com desafios. Em particular, sua pergunta-teste não é um golfe de código dado que o objetivo não é encontrar o código mais curto.

Comment: @Bavarious Estou usando codegolf=desafios para efeitos práticos. É mais uma questão de nomenclatura.

Answer (score 3):

Concordo com a resposta do Guilherme exceto pelo item 2, mas como ia ficar muito grande pros comentários resolvi postar uma resposta meio que item-a-item.

1. Sem sombra de dúvidas desafios de code golf são ótimos para o aprendizado e muito já foi discutido a respeito do SOEN/SOPT servir para o aprendizado. É claro que o SO serve pra tal, mas seu objetivo primário é responder a perguntas que solucionam problemas de programação. Quando comecei a usar o SOEN a primeira coisa que aprendi é que não se trata de um fórum, e sim de um site de perguntas e respostas em que *uma resposta* deve ser aceita para servir de *principal referência* a pesquisas futuras. Por isso eu concordo com esse item, mas acho que code golf não faz sentido no SO porque o estilo de aprendizado é diferente, requerendo muito mais esforço de leitura e estudo do usuário do que o modelo perguntas-respostas.
2. Não concordo com esse item porque, partindo do princípio de que code golf seja aceito no SOPT, seria justíssimo que as perguntas e respostas mais bem escritas recebessem seus méritos (da mesma forma que ocorre hoje para as demais postagens). Além do mais, sendo diversão ou não, qualquer code golf gera conhecimento. Pode não ser interessante pra uma pessoa que já conhece do assunto, mas pode significar um grande aprendizado para um estudante, por exemplo. Aliás, se esse tipo de pergunta atrai muitos votos, isso deveria ser um sinal de que a maioria da comunidade aceita e deseja code golf por aqui (estranho é então não votarem a favor lá na outra postagem em que isso está sendo discutido).
3. Concordo com as colocações, e acho também que o OP causou uma certa confusão ao não responder propriamente aos comentários que o Guilherme e outros postaram e ao abrir uma segunda pergunta com praticamente o mesmo assunto (é verdade que nessa segunda pergunta o problema está mais claro e o caráter de code golf é praticamente inexistente, mas bastaria ter editado a pergunta original ou ao menos *referenciar* toda a discussão que já havia sido feita na nova pergunta).
4. Também acho que a separação é justa. Apesar de eu particularmente não achar que code golfs fazem sentido no SOPT, se a maioria na comunidade assim desejar isso deve ser permitido. De todas as formas, meu tempo é bastante escasso (assim como o de muitos de vocês), então saber logo de cara que uma questão é um code golf facilita na decisão de simplesmente ignorá-la e evita de afastar os especialistas do site.
5. Concordo que o SOPT tem um propósito um pouco especial, e acolher esse tipo de pergunta pode ser válido. Cabe à comunidade votar lá na outra postagem.
6. Bom, eu entendo o que você quer dizer. :)

Comment: É aquele estória de sempre, independente de ser *on* ou *off* quando a pergunta não tem qualidade ela deve ser fechada porque ela tem problema de qualidade.

Answer (score 3):

Acho que são totalmente off-topic e contra o propósito do site. (acho interessantes, mas não cabem aqui na minha opinião).

Os 2 primeiros tópicos do tour: (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

```
Faça perguntas, obtenha respostas, sem distrações
```

e

```
Obtenha respostas para perguntas práticas e detalhadas
```

Além disso são uma porta aberta para um monte de questões similares (que variam só em algum detalhe) que vão certamente ser usadas (para ganhar reputação por exemplo) e fazendo com que perguntas subjetivas se tornem uma atividade "permitida" no site.

Com isso usuários interessados em respostas objetivas e avaliadas pela comunidade (que são a força dos sites do SE em relação a outros sites e forums) vão abandonar o site.

Comment: Eliminou completamente a minha necessidade de formular uma resposta. +1

Comment: Em primeiro lugar Code Golf mais ou menos se encaixa nesta definição, ao menos é bem objetivo. Pode haver dúvidas no "prática". De uma certa forma CG é bem prático, em oposição a conceitual. De outra pode-se argumentar que o seu uso direto não é prático. Não sei se é o caso de todas perguntas de CG. E mesmo que seja há uso prático indireto através do aprendizado proporcionado. De qualquer forma duvido que esta definição sobreviva. Isso é legado do SO, nossa própria definição ainda não está pronta. E segundo:ainda bem que todos aqui tem bola de cristal e sabem o que vai acontecer se aceitar CG.

Answer (score 2):

Sou a favor de Code-Golfs desde que com regras bem definidas para distingui-las das demais perguntas. Por exemplo: Um Code-Golf deveria utilizar apenas a tag code-golf, e no titulo da pergunta ter [Code-Golf] logo no inicio e [Linguagem] no fim.

Acho que isso ajudaria a esconde-las um pouco de quem não curte, não quer ve-las e nem participar.

Acho que trechos de códigos otimizados seriam muito uteis para quem busca melhorar seus conhecimentos.

Quanto a reputação, eu acho justo que bons codigos recebam votos positivos. E nao vejo como problema pessoas criando esses jogos so para adquirir reputacao, desde que se possa tirar proveito do conteudo, o que no meu caso é a coisa mais importante desse site.

Acho que o debate aqui sobre o que bagunça ou não é constante e tenho certeza que se detectassem que isso esta acontecendo seria tranquilo voltar ao que era antes sem permitir esse tipo de "jogo".

É apenas a minha humilde opiniao e estou satisfeito com o site nos moldes atuais. Mas tambem sou a favor de tudo que possa gerar conhecimento e aprendizado.

Comment: Claro, podemos voltar atrás a hora que quisermos, o problema agora que é que nem estamos tendo a chance de analisar se é bom ou não aqui. Não em outros lugares. Aqui! Eu não acho que precise diferenciar porque as perguntas mal formuladas  tomam mais tempo de um usuário para perceber que não vale a pena do que para perceber que a pergunta é Code Golf. Mas até aceitaria uma diferenciação se isso ajudar a pergunta ser aceita. É bom todos notarem que fechar perguntas Code Golf não fará que elas nunca sejam postadas. Dá menos trabalho ver que é Code Golf e ir em embora do que ver e fechar.

Answer (score -1):

Eu **pessoalmente** acho legal para o site/comunidade. [Discutindo com o @Gabe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6119/3635) sobre a tag existente [code-golf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) creio que seria interessante definirmos as regras básicas, o Victor fez um excelentemente trabalho listando.

Como o Victor já deu uma ótima tradução sobre as regras do codegolf original que vai além da nossa tag [code-golf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf):

> #### O que é [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)?
>
> [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) é uma competição para resolver-se um problema particular no menor número de bytes (ou caracteres) de código-fonte.
>
> #### Quais são os requisitos de um [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)?
>
> Deve haver uma especificação completa e não ambígua do problema. Ela deve incluir ao menos:
>
> 1. Como a resposta deve ser apresentada – apenas uma função nua é aceitável, ou deve incluir o código que produz a entrada/saída completa?
> 2. O formato de entrada.
> 3. O formato de saída.
> 4. Uma descrição clara de como a entrada e a saída são relacionadas.
> 5. Uma menção explícita se qualquer verificação ou recuperação de erros deve ser feita (por causa que soluções frágeis também estão no páreo)
> 6. Exemplos de entradas correspondentes.
> 7. Se a pontuação é por caracteres ao invés de bytes, uma declaração acerca desse efeito.
>
> Todas as linguagens de programação populares devem normalmente ser permitidas exceto se houver circunstâncias excepcionais fora de opiniões pessoais.
>
> Se 1. e 7. não forem especificados, as seguintes definições padrões são usadas:
>
> - Respostas são pontuadas em bytes.
> - Respostas podem ser [tanto programas completos quanto funções (ou equivalentes)](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2419/8478).
> - Funções não precisam ter um nome, [a menos que você requira que elas sejam nomeadas](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1503/8478).
> - Tanto programas quanto funções podem receber a entrada via STDIN ou argumento de linha de comando ou prompt. Funções também podem usar seus argumentos como entrada. Tanto funções quando programas podem produzir saída ao escrever em STDOUT. Funções também podem usar seus argumentos ou valor(es) de retorno como saída. [Esses padrões são baseados em consenso da comunidade.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/8478)
>
> #### O que faz um bom [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)?
>
> 1. Rigorosamente especificado.
> 2. Simples o bastante para ser completamente entendido em sua maior parte por duas rápidas leituras da especificação.
> 3. Admitir implementações rápidas e ingênuas.
> 4. Complexo o suficiente para admitir mais de uma forma razoável de ser resolvido.
> 5. Ter soluções já-prontas-em-algumas-linguagens-de-programação excluídas. (ex. sem `eval` para análise de expressões aritméticas ou coisa parecida).
> 6. Não ser otimizada para uma linguagem de programação ou para uma classe de linguagens.
> 7. Não ser muito relacionado com o que os outros fizeram recentemente.
> 8. Solucionar uma classe de problemas ao invés de uma única instância.
>
> #### Como eu devo responder um [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)? Alguma dica?
>
> Escolha sua linguagem de programação favorita, resolva o problema, e reduza o seu tamanho o máximo que você puder! Na maioria das vezes você terá que usar práticas desencorajadas. As abordagens padrão são:
>
> - Remova espaços e linhas em branco desnecessárias.
> - Use nomes de variáveis com uma letra ao invés de nomes descritivos.
> - Sempre lembre que booleanos podem ser implicitamente convertidos para 0 ou 1 em muitas linguagens, e que você pode realizar aritmética em `char` no C e C++.
> - Estude as bibliotecas padrão da linguagem profundamente. Frequentemente existem [características “ocultas”](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22hidden+features%22) que podem resolver o problema em uma quantidade menor de bytes.
> - Muitas vezes, um algoritmo mais ineficiente pode reduzir o tamanho do código. ([Exemplo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960200/code-golf-lights-out/1977483#1977483))
> - Vá para a questão sobre as [dicas](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) apropriadas para a sua linguagem e veja se há truques que possam reduzir a sua contagem de caracteres.
>
> #### Coisas a notar
>
> - A menos que a questão especifique que ela é pontuada em caracteres, ela é pontuada em bytes. Se ela não especificar qual é a codificação usada para a pontuação, respostas que usam códigos Unicode fora da faixa de 0 a 255 devem mencionar qual é a codificação utilizada.
> - É [aceito na prática](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com) contar com flags não padronizadas de compiladores ou quaisquer outras marcações não-padrão requeridas para fazer o  interpretador/compilador fazer o que você precisa que ele faça como parte da pontuação.
> - Tente explicar sua solução.
> - Você deve mostrar como o programa ou função é executada, aceitando a entrada e escrevendo a saída.

Comment: A minha resposta original que você linkou foi excluída.

Comment: @VictorStafusa sim, espero que não leve a mal, foi [solicitação minha](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6118/3635), não é por nada, é que acho que aquele não era o lugar adequado ... de qualquer forma deixei linkado para quem tiver pontos ver que o trabalho foi seu ;)

Comment: Sim, entendo. É que eu estava me perguntando se um dos motivos dos votos negativos não teria sido o link que para a maioria dos usuários, só leva ao cabeçalho da pergunta, de forma que não daria para entender o que haveria acontecido.

Comment: Uma outra observação é acerca da performance. O objetivo do code-golf padrão (há várias variações no site) é única e exclusivamente reduzir o tamanho do código. Frequentemente isso é feito por meio de formas que degradam a performance, são extremamente ineficientes, não validam nenhuma entrada, não tratam nenhum erro, são extremamente inseguras, não têm portabilidade, crasham ou entram em loop infinito após concluírem seu propósito, geram milhares de warnings em compiladores, etc.

Comment: Há outras tags por lá para desafios que priorizam outras formas de avaliação (que eu considero muito mais útil que apenas o tamanho do código), mas o critério tamanho do código é o que domina de metade a dois terços dos desafios que normalmente são postados por lá.

Comment: @VictorStafusa nossa muito legal estes detalhes sobre o code-golf original, editei a resposta: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/6121/revisions