# Sobre a nossa própria tolerância aos limites do que é "on topic"

Tags: debate

Antes de começar com a pergunta, quero pedir desculpas por fazer esse papel de "advogado do diabo". Sei que não participo tão ativamente das discussões no meta e no chat como eu gostaria (e talvez por isso não esteja assim tão apto fazer esses julgamentos e corra o risco de mais atrapalhar do que ajudar), mas juro que é apenas porque quero ajudar e me importo com o andamento e a qualidade do SOpt. :)

Bom, [temos andado discutindo a pertinência e relevância de questões de code-golf](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1366/desafios-e-code-golf) por aqui, e esse particular assunto se mostrou um tanto polêmico. Ainda assim, parece que a comunidade está caminhando para permitir esse tipo de questão ou ao menos tolerá-las inicialmente como forma de teste para verificação da ocorrência ou não dos potenciais problemas elencados nos contra-argumentos.

Sendo esse o direcionamento (que, não vou discutir, realmente parece justo), não seria interessante sermos mais tolerantes também com outros tópicos, como o relacionado na pergunta "[Qual a forma de medir o nível de conhecimento de um programador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19229/qual-a-forma-de-medir-o-nivel-de-conhecimento-de-um-programador)"?

Ao meu ver, e sob o mesmo julgamento das discussões sobre code-golf, essa pergunta poderia ter sido discutida aqui ao invés de ter sido colocada em suspenso porque:

1. Ela me parece razoavelmente bem escrita e objetiva (se tais métodos existem e, se sim, quais são).
2. Ela tangencia o desenvolvimento de software de uma forma *similar* ao que o code-golf faz, no sentido de que as pessoas também podem aprender ao se preparar para testes e avaliações.
3. Muito embora seja verdade que as respostas podem ter algum grau de subjetividade, ainda assim pode haver o bom subjetivo como em perguntas como [aquela sobre as mensagens de erro se desculparem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2539/as-mensagens-de-erro-devem-se-desculpar), e eu creio que muitas respostas poderão sim ter informações úteis e concretas (eu mesmo considerei fornecer uma resposta indicando o [POSCOMP](http://www.sbc.org.br/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=237&Itemid=182) como forma de avaliação no meio acadêmico, mas quando vi a pergunta ela já estava fechada - tudo bem que o encerramento ocorreu 9 horas depois, mas mesmo assim...)

Eu mesmo [já argumentei contra certos assuntos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272/73) que hoje, considerando os argumentos que tenho lido a favor de code-golf em especial, acho que podem ser mais bem explorados.

Então eu pergunto: não deveria ser o caso de (1) darmos mais chances pra assuntos fora do "on topic" por um tempo maior, e (2) considerarmos fechar mais rapidamente perguntas que pecam em critérios da qualidade?

EDIT:

Alternativamente, [como bem colocado numa resposta abaixo por Andrey](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1490/73), o título dessa pergunta poderia ser
**Devemos aceitar perguntas que seriam do escopo do Programmers?** por não termos essa opção em português?

Comment: Eu não tenho certeza quanto a ela ser on-topic ou não (acho que vale tentar e ver que tipo de resposta surge). Mas eu achei a pergunta fraca e muito ampla. Respostas podem variar em um escopo muito amplo e uma boa resposta provavelmente será muito longa. Claro, algumas edições poderiam salvar, mas no estado atual não considero uma pergunta com tanto potencial de dar certo.

Comment: +1 porque abrir o debate. Mas concordo com o @GuilhermeBernal

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Você pode ter alguma razão sobre a amplitude, e eu até acho que a edição piorou um pouco porque misturou agora métricas de produtividade. :) De todas as formas, não era essa discussão que eu intencionava discutir, e sim sermos ou não mais tolerantes com assuntos julgados como off topic.

Comment: SO está cheio de velhas questões que ficam fechados quando encontrados, porque eles não estão on-topic. Os que eu ver e perto tendem a ser cheio de lixo opinativo. Conversa fiada, propício para o banco do bar em um café na praia. A idéia dos `programmers`  é interessante, mas essas questões tendem a ser citados como "por que meu próximo, olhar para este ..."

Comment: Aqui está outra a partir de hoje eu estive lutando com, após a minha bandeira para fechar foi rejeitado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19187/por-que-cobol-ainda-e-a-linguagem-preferida-no-mundo-dos-negocios mesmo autor:-)

Answer (score 7):

Eu sou o criador dessa pergunta que você citou, desde que comecei a frequentar o SOPT eu tento deixar minhas perguntas da forma mais clara e objetiva possível.

Um exemplo de uma pergunta que realizei e segue a linha dessa que você citou: [Como escrever um código legível e de fácil manutenção?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13890/como-escrever-um-codigo-legivel-e-de-facil-manutencao) (Poderia ter seguido a linha de "**principalmente baseadas em opiniões**") mas quem respondeu entendeu meu ponto de vista era meramente técnico.

Outro ponto que eu poderia ter exposto na minha pergunta: Se existe uma forma de medir sua produtividade, talvez exista uma forma de medir seu conhecimento e avaliar o profissional nesse quesito, são técnicas conhecidas não baseadas em **achismo**, programação é algo racional deve existir uma linha linear de conhecimento ou níveis onde um programador com experiência já conhece técnicas pra resolver problemas que para novatos seriam difíceis.

Talvez a forma que eu fiz a pergunta abriu um leque muito grande, mas isso eu posso resolver se for o caso.

**EDIT:** Reformulei a pergunta, se estiver faltando algo por favor me ajudem a editar.

Comment: NULL, sua pergunta foi reaberta

Comment: Não sei se a pergunta se encaixa no SO, seria uma boa para o Programmers, mas como não tem uma versão em português...

Comment: Null, eu tenho a impressão de que a sua pergunta ficou muito mais ampla depois da edição. Formas de medir conhecimento existem aos montes, mas ai as respostas podem realmente fugir do escopo do SOPT. Mas vamos aguardar o que os demais comentam a esse respeito. De todas as formas, eu dei uma resposta lá (com o que eu conheço), também como forma de testar se a pergunta funciona por aqui. :)

Comment: Como disse acima podem editar minha pergunta caso percebam que ela contínua sugestiva.

Answer (score 4):

Um título alternativo para a pergunta seria:

### Devemos aceitar perguntas que seriam do escopo do Programmers?

Não sei se isso já foi discutido aqui ou não. No SO-en a solução disso seria simples: mover a pergunta para o Programmers. Como aqui não temos um Programmers, temos que chegar a um concenso se devemos ou não aceitar essas perguntas.

Comment: Ótima colocação. Fiz uma edição na pergunta e adicionei esse título alternativo.

Comment: Meu voto é sim! Tudo que agrega conhecimento útil na area de programação eu aceitaria. Opinião minha.

Answer (score 4):

Discussões como essa são sempre bem-vindas aqui no meta, não importa se postadas por um frequentador habitual do site e do meta ou não. E o papel de advogado do diabo muitas vezes é o que falta alguém fazer. Então, não precisa pedir desculpas! Aqui é o lugar certo para esse tipo de discussão, e a experiência anterior do [code golf](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1366/desafios-e-code-golf) mostra que ainda existe bastante margem para mudanças no site e no modo da comunidade pensar e agir.

A sua pergunta envolve vários assuntos, e eu gostaria de comentar sobre cada um deles.

#### Especificamente sobre a pergunta citada

Eu acho que é uma pergunta limítrofe. Dá margem para opiniões indesejáveis, e também dá margem para opiniões desejáveis (conforme o que é dito em *[Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective)*). O simples fato de poder gerar boas respostas seria motivo para mantê-la aberta, mesmo com o risco de surgir também muito ruído (temos como lidar com isso e limpar o ruído). Eu inclusive acho que [resposta do Orion aqui no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1491/74) funcionaria como boa resposta lá na pergunta. Porém isso é só a minha opinião, e vale tanto quanto a opinião de qualquer outro aqui (por favor lembrem-se disso, o fato de agora eu ser moderador não muda o peso das minhas opiniões).

#### Sobre o tópico "Ambiente de trabalho e políticas de escritório"

De fato está com placar bem negativo neste momento. Eu sou um dos que votaram contra, e votei contra principalmente por ser um assunto que não me interessa muito. Mas a pergunta que está sendo debatida não pertence integralmente a esse tópico. Contratação não é o único motivo que leva as pessoas a precisarem ou quererem avaliar os conhecimentos de um programador. E mesmo que fosse, ainda assim me parece uma discussão interessante. Quem sabe eu ainda removo meu downvote lá, se alguém me convencer!

#### Sobre sua pergunta final #1

> Então eu pergunto: não deveria ser o caso de (1) darmos mais chances pra assuntos fora do "on topic" por um tempo maior[?]

Não tenho certeza. Eu acho que as pessoas fecharem e reabrirem as perguntas acaba trazendo mais intensidade à própria discussão – tanto esta quanto a do code golf e esta estão rendendo bastante. Se deixarmos tudo aberto para discutir depois, pode ser que a discussão "murche".

#### Sobre sua pergunta final #2

> [Então eu pergunto: não deveria ser o caso de] (2) considerarmos fechar mais rapidamente perguntas que pecam em critérios da qualidade?

Quais critérios de qualidade? Perguntas "ruins" em geral ganham votos contrários, não fechamento, contanto que atendam aos demais requisitos para serem respondíveis (claras, focadas, etc). Se estiver falando de perguntas confusas, pode dar mais resultado dar um tempo para o autor consertar do que fechar imediatamente, mas minha opinião pessoal nesse ponto ainda está dividida.

#### Sobre aceitar perguntas do escopo do Programmers

Aceitar todo o escopo do Programmers eu sou contra, porque de todos os sites da rede que eu conheço minimamente, o Programmers é o de escopo mais confuso. É bem capaz que essa pergunta acabasse fechada lá se fosse postada em inglês. Ou não. Aquilo pra mim é uma loteria! Então acho melhor discutir casos mais específicos aqui, à medida que forem surgindo, do que decretar que tudo o que é aceito no Programmers deva ser aceito aqui.

Comment: As suas colocações foram muito boas (principalmente sobre a questão final #2). Mas minha dúvida é que uma pergunta como a do exemplo, se fechada sem a oportunidade de errarmos em uma ou outra resposta, pode desestimular que eventualmente surjam respostas objetivas e úteis. Eu também não acho a pergunta interessante (e creio que nem a responderia se não fosse pelo exercício dessa thread no meta). De fato ela nem pareceu tão interessante pra comunidade, pois apesar de se argumentar que é opinativa não teve um número grande de respostas. continua...

Comment: Assim, apesar de você ter toda razão no fato de que o sistema de votação e sinalização funciona bem, será que não estamos perdendo oportunidades de conteúdo bom por isso? Dificilmente alguém se interessaria em responder uma pergunta suspensa, mesmo se isso fosse possível (honestamente não sei, nunca tentei), não é?

Comment: @LuizVieira Não é possível responder pergunta fechada/suspensa. O objetivo do fechamento é justamente impedir novas respostas. Então você tem razão, pergunta fechada é um risco de perda de bons conteúdos. Idealmente deve ser um risco calculado: fecha-se aquilo que tem bem pouca chance de produzir bons conteúdos. Mas aqui ainda estamos definindo o que seria isso. Eu acho que a pergunta deveria ser reaberta para ver o que acontece, mas cabe à comunidade fazer isso, com votos. Na verdade estou surpreso por ninguém ter votado para reabrir de novo.

Comment: Ela já foi reaberta uma vez (eu mesmo votei para isso). Pensei em votar para reabertura novamente, mas desisti. :)

Comment: Eu acho que não pode votar duas vezes para reabrir (não tenho certeza). Mesmo assim, aqui no meta tem muito mais argumento para reabrir do que pra manter fechado, e nenhum novo voto lá. Falta público para o assunto. @LuizVieira

Comment: Concordo com o @LuizVieira sobre as oportunidades que perdemos por excesso de cautela. Diversas vezes vi questões que, por sí só me deixariam bem perto de fechá-las mas que deixei aberta (e votei) por conta da resposta. Isso é parte da primeira instrução do site ("Relaxe"). Nem toda questão que não se encaixar objetivamente dentro do nosso on-topic merece expandir o nosso on-topic. Aceitar uma questão subjetiva não significa que todas serão aceitas. É importante sempre julgar os méritos da própria questão, e não as potenciais consequências de aceitá-la.

Answer (score 3):

A questão é principalmente baseada em opiniões pois ela mesmo é subjetiva

> "Qual a forma de medir o nível de conhecimento de um programador?"

- Programador de que?
- Qual linguagem?
- Que nível seria esse?
- O que seria nível intermediário?
- Qual a finalidade desse conhecimento no mundo real?
- Alguém com 80% de conhecimento é melhor que alguém com 60% de conhecimento?

Programador é naturalmente um desenvolvedor, existe lógica, criatividade, capacidade de resolver problemas. Foi citado como exemplo na questão um teste de conhecimento de inglês:

> Bom, o teste poderia ser utilizado por empresas para avaliar profissionais de uma forma similar ao que o TOEFL faz para o nível de inglês, se alguém assim desejasse.

Mas só conhecimento não basta para ser um bom programador, conheço muitos **CDF** de faculdade que conhecem vários recursos de determinada linguagem e tiram altas notas, mas na hora de resolver problemas reais não sabem nem por onde começar, não tem capacidade nem criatividade.

Foi citado ainda:

> um teste solicitando exemplos de código em um ambiente sem acesso a Internet

Nem os criadores de linguagem de programação deixam de consultar códigos na hora de desenvolver software.

**Concluindo**, a questão levantada não traz uma solução pontual, além de ir contra a ideia do que é um programador/desenvolvedor.

Comment: Tudo verdade. Ainda assim a minha colocação era sobre tolerarmos mais esse tipo de questão, justamente mais aberta. Afinal, olhando pra trás, temos [um](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2539/as-mensagens-de-erro-devem-se-desculpar), [outro](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2477/porque-devo-usar-apenas-um-return-em-cada-funcao), ou ainda [outro](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13890/como-escrever-um-codigo-legivel-e-de-facil-manutencao) exemplo que são potencialmente subjetivos nesses mesmos moldes e estão indo aparentemente bem e produzindo conhecimento útil e interessante.

Comment: O que eu quero dizer é por que ao invés de sinalizarmos a questão (no caso específico dessa questão, em que ao menos eu enxergo algumas coisas boas nela) não sinalizamos as respostas ruins que forem opinativas? Será que não é só mais cômodo fechar a pergunta pra evitar de ter trabalho em ler as respostas? Como no caso do code-golf, algumas pessoas têm interesse, outras não. Por que não deixar quem tem interesse julgar as respostas ruins?

Comment: @LuizVieira as questões também são de interesse da comunidade, assim como as respostas. Perguntas extensas e abertas diminuem a utilidade de nosso site e retiram outras perguntas da página inicial. (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Subjetividade é permitido? Sim, mas levantar uma questão que não irá contribuir de forma satisfatória deve ser evitado.

Comment: Entendo. Mas, enfim, a pergunta de exemplo, na formulação original (isto é, antes da edição do OP), realmente me parecia bem definida. O "aberto" que eu usei (provavelmente me expressei mal) era a respeito dela ser bastante subjetiva. Na minha modesta opinião qualquer pergunta pode ter respostas baseadas em opiniões. Claro que algumas perguntas estimulam usuários menos preocupados em simplesmente opiniar. Mas isso é motivo pra não dar oportunidade ao conteúdo? Eu simplesmente não sei.

Answer (score 0):

Como eu cheguei a comentar na referida pergunta. Acredito que ela seja uma excelente discussão. Isto envolve troca de ideias e argumentação, o que foge um pouco da resposta objetiva.

Como no [comentário do Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19229/qual-a-forma-de-medir-o-nivel-de-conhecimento-de-um-programador#comment35576_19229) iriam haver críticas porque, para ele, aquele método era melhor.

Existem estudos sobre o tema, mas estes estudos possuem resultados subjetivos o que acabo concordando que, se não podemos ter questões baseadas em opniões, ela acaba sendo off-topic.

Comment: Não acredito neste tipo de "técnica" ou tecnologia. Pelo simples fato de haver bons mentirosos e péssimos marketeiros no ambiente de informática. E lá vamos nós, há muito mais variáveis em uma verificação desta do que certezas. Quem disser para mim que programa sem utilizar o google como fonte de pesquisa, sinceramente, descarto e não o contrato. Não existe sênior que saiba tudo de tudo que ele tem experiência comprovada, quem dirá júnior e pleno...

Comment: @FlávioGranato Isso que você disse, com um pouco mais de recheio, daria uma resposta à pergunta em questão ;)