# Debater regras dependendo do caso é aceitável no site principal?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, respostas

Me deparei com esta pergunta [Como executar uma tarefa num momento preciso no tempo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211990/3635) e em seguida com esta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/215461/3635, entendo perfeitamente o argumento do Victor, já que a própria tag tem a seguinte "intro":

> Utilize esta tag quando somente quando a pergunta tem uma relação irrefutável à competição de código Code Golf. Tome muito cuidado ao utilizar esta tag, pois este é um tema fácil de ter perguntas de baixíssima qualidade. Code Golf é uma competição recreacional de programação com o intuito de resolver um problema específico no menor número de bytes, caracteres ou com algum tipo de restrição de código fonte.

No entanto o problema que eu quero discutir aqui **não** é se a pergunta é se a pergunta é correta ou não, mas sim o discutir **qual o lugar** apropriada para discutir e apontar problemas da pergunta.

Até aonde **eu entendo** o lugar correto é o *META*, ou seja a opinião do Victor é excelente para explicar como funciona o code-golf, mas o lugar aonde se foi discutir isto eu creio que não.

Eu sinalizei a resposta, como **não é uma resposta**, pois independente da pergunta ter problemas ou das demais respostas não terem seguido a regra básica do code-golf:

- Apresentar um "código funcional"
- Performance
- Minificação

Ainda sim ela não é uma resposta para a pergunta, a sinalização ficou como disputada, eu simplesmente não entendi aonde ela responde a pergunta.

Não é uma critica ao Victor, só que acredito que deveríamos organizar melhor.

Comment: Eu concordo contigo. Independente se a pergunta há problemas ou não, o Meta é o lugar ideal para esse tipo de discussão. Hoje até o chat Debate da Pilha é apropriado para isso.

Comment: Muito bem citado sobre o chat @AndersonCarlosWoss

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não. Independente do caso.

A intenção do @VictorStafusa é ótima, e o conteúdo que ele pôs na pergunta, é muito bem vindo. Mas entre o wiki da tag, o Meta, e até o chat... Definitivamente, uma resposta - que não serve como resposta - na pergunta não é o lugar apropriado.

Removi a resposta, mas espero que vocês continuem produzindo um bom guia sobre code golf no site - em parte porque eu gosto de code golf, e gostaria de ver mais por aqui.

Comment: Eu concordo plenamente, tanto que por isto disse que entendia os argumentos do Victor e agradeço pelo retorno rápido. Espero que possamos "evoluir" este estilo de pergunta e também espero ter mais por aqui.

Comment: Inclusive eu acho que o conteúdo postado lá vale como uma discussão aqui no meta de como postemos estruturar os code-golf de maneira adequada, até para evitar que apareçam perguntas completamente fora do objetivo desta tag.