# Vamos criar/incentivar perguntas no estilo code-golf?

Tags: debate, big-7

O [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com) para que não sabe é um site da rede SE. [Discutindo com o @Gabe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6119/3635) sobre a tag existente [code-golf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) creio que seria interessante definirmos as regras básicas, o [Victor fez um excelentemente trabalho listando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/215461/3635).

O que vocês acham? Se tem algum algorítimo/código pronto o que acha de colocar em uma competição?

O básico do objetivo é (bem resumido mesmo):

- Ter um código pronto funcional (com input e ouput)
- Performance
- Minificação

Claro que tem muito mais coisa, como o Victor já deu uma ótima introdução:

> #### O que é [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)?
>
> [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) é uma competição para resolver-se um problema particular no menor número de bytes (ou caracteres) de código-fonte.
>
> #### Quais são os requisitos de um [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)?
>
> Deve haver uma especificação completa e não ambígua do problema. Ela deve incluir ao menos:
>
> 1. Como a resposta deve ser apresentada – apenas uma função nua é aceitável, ou deve incluir o código que produz a entrada/saída completa?
> 2. O formato de entrada.
> 3. O formato de saída.
> 4. Uma descrição clara de como a entrada e a saída são relacionadas.
> 5. Uma menção explícita se qualquer verificação ou recuperação de erros deve ser feita (por causa que soluções frágeis também estão no páreo)
> 6. Exemplos de entradas correspondentes.
> 7. Se a pontuação é por caracteres ao invés de bytes, uma declaração acerca desse efeito.
>
> Todas as linguagens de programação populares devem normalmente ser permitidas exceto se houver circunstâncias excepcionais fora de opiniões pessoais.
>
> Se 1. e 7. não forem especificados, as seguintes definições padrões são usadas:
>
> - Respostas são pontuadas em bytes.
> - Respostas podem ser [tanto programas completos quanto funções (ou equivalentes)](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2419/8478).
> - Funções não precisam ter um nome, [a menos que você requira que elas sejam nomeadas](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1503/8478).
> - Tanto programas quanto funções podem receber a entrada via STDIN ou argumento de linha de comando ou prompt. Funções também podem usar seus argumentos como entrada. Tanto funções quando programas podem produzir saída ao escrever em STDOUT. Funções também podem usar seus argumentos ou valor(es) de retorno como saída. [Esses padrões são baseados em consenso da comunidade.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/8478)
>
> #### O que faz um bom [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)?
>
> 1. Rigorosamente especificado.
> 2. Simples o bastante para ser completamente entendido em sua maior parte por duas rápidas leituras da especificação.
> 3. Admitir implementações rápidas e ingênuas.
> 4. Complexo o suficiente para admitir mais de uma forma razoável de ser resolvido.
> 5. Ter soluções já-prontas-em-algumas-linguagens-de-programação excluídas. (ex. sem `eval` para análise de expressões aritméticas ou coisa parecida).
> 6. Não ser otimizada para uma linguagem de programação ou para uma classe de linguagens.
> 7. Não ser muito relacionado com o que os outros fizeram recentemente.
> 8. Solucionar uma classe de problemas ao invés de uma única instância.
>
> #### Como eu devo responder um [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)? Alguma dica?
>
> Escolha sua linguagem de programação favorita, resolva o problema, e reduza o seu tamanho o máximo que você puder! Na maioria das vezes você terá que usar práticas desencorajadas. As abordagens padrão são:
>
> - Remova espaços e linhas em branco desnecessárias.
> - Use nomes de variáveis com uma letra ao invés de nomes descritivos.
> - Sempre lembre que booleanos podem ser implicitamente convertidos para 0 ou 1 em muitas linguagens, e que você pode realizar aritmética em `char` no C e C++.
> - Estude as bibliotecas padrão da linguagem profundamente. Frequentemente existem [características “ocultas”](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22hidden+features%22) que podem resolver o problema em uma quantidade menor de bytes.
> - Muitas vezes, um algoritmo mais ineficiente pode reduzir o tamanho do código. ([Exemplo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960200/code-golf-lights-out/1977483#1977483))
> - Vá para a questão sobre as [dicas](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) apropriadas para a sua linguagem e veja se há truques que possam reduzir a sua contagem de caracteres.
>
> #### Coisas a notar
>
> - A menos que a questão especifique que ela é pontuada em caracteres, ela é pontuada em bytes. Se ela não especificar qual é a codificação usada para a pontuação, respostas que usam códigos Unicode fora da faixa de 0 a 255 devem mencionar qual é a codificação utilizada.
> - É [aceito na prática](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com) contar com flags não padronizadas de compiladores ou quaisquer outras marcações não-padrão requeridas para fazer o  interpretador/compilador fazer o que você precisa que ele faça como parte da pontuação.
> - Tente explicar sua solução.
> - Você deve mostrar como o programa ou função é executada, aceitando a entrada e escrevendo a saída.

Comment: Hehe, manero...

Comment: Dup? https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1366/101

Comment: UÉ downvote por que? Eu já não fechei a pergunta? Entendam, duplicata é coisa normal, não temos o direito de falhar? **Isso foi muito mimimi** sem necessidade -.-', eu mesmo fechei a pergunta, errar é normal... Agora se discorda da proposta negative a minha resposta no topico correto que esta sendo debatido (esta aberto). Faça um melhor uso da ferramenta.