# Perguntas envolvendo conteúdos matemáticos sem ser um caso específico de programação são válidas?

Tags: debate

Estava lendo a meta [Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic)
e me surgiu uma dúvida sobre perguntas de conteúdos matemáticos como:

1. Análise combinatória
2. Indução matemática
3. Máximo divisor comum
4. Congruências lineares
5. Aritmética modular

Todas os conteúdos acima são relacionados a teoria dos números e possuem ligação com programação, como vou descrever abaixo, porém não são problemas ligados a um erro de programação ou a uma duvida referente a uma linguagem. Todas essas matérias são fundamentais em diversas fases do desenvolvimento de um sistema complexo que por vezes os desenvolvedores podem ter alguma dúvida, nesse caso temos uma ligação direta com a programação e as perguntas sobre as matérias acima citadas entrariam dentro do escopo da comunidade.

Exemplos de uso das matérias:

`Análise combinatória` para calculo de probabilidades, desenvolvimento de algoritmos complexos

`Indução matemática` pode ser usada em condicionais de provação de algoritmos complexos ou com possibilidades de N resultados distintos verdadeiros. Aplicando indução podemos provar que todos os N resultados são verdadeiros e passar um teste condicional sem a necessidade de múltiplos cálculos de argumentos possivelmente válidos.

`Máximo divisor comum` serve de base para o calculo de `Congruências lineares` que por sua vez são utilizadas no desenvolvimento de métodos de criptografia.

`Aritmética modular` ainda dentro da criptografia temos essa matéria, que serve para aplicar as `Congruências lineares` a cálculos binários.

Essa são apenas algumas das matérias ligadas a programação que geram muitas duvidas, não são linguagens nem algoritmos ou métodos de criptografia, mas são a base de tudo isso, acredito que todo programador vai acabar tendo que utilizar muito esses conceitos durante sua vida e como não encontrei nada na meta referenciada no começo dessa pergunta falando se questões desse tipo são/serão aceitas pela comunidade resolvi questionar aqui...

Comment: É uma boa pergunta, mas eu creio que isso deve ser analisado caso a caso. Se alguém perguntar "Como acho o MDC?" a pergunta muito provavelmente será facilmente descontextualizada, mas como você mesmo aponta isso pode não ser sempre certo. Se você postou essa dúvida aqui também porque tem uma questão que parece desse tipo, eu sugiro que você vá em frente e poste-a. Com exemplos mais concretos a discussão fica mais fácil. :)

Comment: Na verdade postei por que estou estudando essas matérias novamente e achei que poderiam ser válidas perguntas do gênero dentro do escopo da comunidade... Porém como você disse cada caso tem que ser analisado, mas já abrimos as portas para que as perguntas sejam ao menos analisadas e não sinalizadas imediatamente...

Comment: Sim, também acho que podem ser válidas. Aliás, se alguma vez precisar postar algo mais matemático (eu já precisei, por isso fiz esse post), essas informações podem ser úteis: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/795/notacao-matematica-no-sopt

Comment: Muito útil esse post, não sabia que dava pra representar de forma tão simples notações matemáticas aqui