# Devemos aceitar perguntas sobre exercícios?

Tags: debate

De vez em quando eu vejo algumas perguntas, que, praticamente, pedem a resposta de um exercício de faculdade ou outro lugar, [exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25599/exercicio-de-programacao-c). O que quero debater é: devemos aceitar esse tipo de perguntas ou despachá-las o mais rápido possível para desincentivar esse tipo de pergunta e fazer o usuário resolver o problema sozinho?

Comment: Sem tempo pra detalhar, mas dever de casa *não tem problema* desde que haja **esforço** do autor em resolver a questão. Copy/paste descarado é lixo: downvote, fechamento e delete.

Comment: Relacionado: [O que fazer com usuários que estão na zona de conforto?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1137/3117)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Toda pergunta deve ser considerada como uma pergunta comum independente se é um exercício ou não e julgada da mesma forma.

Veja por exemplo essa pergunta: [Interpretação de um algoritmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17548/interpreta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-um-algoritmo/17562#17562)

É uma pergunta sobre dificuldade em exercício mas a pergunta é clara o suficiente e explica o que o OP deseja (que não é a resposta pronta).

E é basicamente o que foi indicado [nesta resposta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255499/2188186) do SOEN:

> A questão está dentro dos [tópicos permitidos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic)? 
>                 Se não, vote para fechar.
>
> A pergunta está clara e fornece todas as informações necessárias para resolvê-la? 
>                 Se não, vote para fechar.
>
> A pergunta está reduzida a um ponto mínimo e não precisa de um livro para respondê-la? 
>                 Se não, vote para fechar.
>
> A pergunta está perguntando por links/ferramentas ?
>                 Se sim, vote para fechar.
>
> A pergunta está pedindo opiniões? 
>                 Se sim, vote para fechar.
>
> A pergunta está pedindo para fazer a tarefa/lição sem demonstrar esforço? 
>                 Se sim, vote para fechar.

Answer (score 6):

Quando uma pergunta tem potencial para gerar conhecimento útil para a comunidade, não vejo razão pra desconsiderá-la independentemente da motivação do OP em postá-la.

Mas nesse caso da pergunta que você exemplifica, ela claramente não demonstra nenhum esforço de pesquisa, tem potencialmente um escopo muito amplo (porque demanda muita coisa - esse é o maior perigo com exercícios e trabalhos escolares, na minha opinião), e mesmo que alguém se dispusesse a respondê-la o conteúdo ali provavelmente seria de ajuda apenas para o OP, já que honestamente algumas das dúvidas são triviais (por exemplo, como fazer a soma de duas notas para obter a nota final).

Por isso eu acho que ela foi rapidamente fechada (e também amplamente votada negativamente).