# Discussão sobre pergunta suspensa: formato de exibição da hora

Tags: debate

Há 16 horas essa pergunta sobre o formato da exibição de horas foi suspensa como sendo principalmente baseada em opiniões:

[Formato de hora: 12 vs. 24 [em suspenso]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25594/formato-de-hora-12-vs-24)

A pergunta teve alguns votos para ser reaberta, mas a discussão local aparentemente parou sem ter se chegado a uma decisão consistente. Assim, eu gostaria de trazer essa discussão pra cá pra evitar que a pergunta seja simplesmente "esquecida" (até porque eu não tenho outra forma de aumentar o interesse nela sem forçar edições inúteis, uma vez que ela continua suspensa e eu já dei meu voto).

Eu sou **a favor** dessa pergunta pelos seguintes motivos:

1. Não acho que ela seja *principalmente* baseada em opiniões. Pelo contrário, há importantes razões para se escolher uma forma ou outra de exibição, que decorrem não apenas de questões culturais do usuário do sistema (como já bem colocado em alguns comentários na própria pergunta) mas também do propósito da interação na exibição/edição do valor.
2. Talvez a pergunta venha a receber respostas ruins, mas essa possibilidade não é exclusiva de perguntas que não envolvem um problema de programação. Por isso, me parece simplesmente injusto tratá-la de forma diferenciada com base nesse argumento (muito mais subjetivo do que a própria pergunta). O sistema de votação existe justamente pra penalizar/premiar conteúdo considerado ruim/bom pela comunidade, e é mais efetivo nesse sentido do que a suspensão ou exclusão de conteúdo.
3. Além disso, a questão trata especificamente de critérios de [usabilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/usabilidade) (talvez também de [ux](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ux)) na Interação Humano-Computador, que não somente é um assunto considerado [dentro do escopo do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic) como também já produziu questões bastante úteis para a comunidade ([1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/622/qual-a-melhor-maneira-de-se-representar-um-endere%C3%A7o), [2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6667/como-indicar-visualmente-quais-campos-s%C3%A3o-preench%C3%ADveis) e [3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2539/as-mensagens-de-erro-devem-se-desculpar), apenas para citar os exemplos mais populares).

Comment: Ok, fui convencido, dei o 5º voto... só acho que autor poderia ter se abstido de votar na reabertura da própria pergunta.