# Pergunta sobre configuração de IDE são off-topic?

Tags: debate

Me deparei com a seguinte pergunta e fiquei em dúvida:

[Modificar cursor do VIM rodando no Console2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27750/modificar-cursor-do-vim-rodando-no-console2)

Ela trata de uma configuração visual específica de um emulador de console para o `VIM`.

Esta é uma pergunta dentro do contexto do SOpt ?

Comment: [Relacionado](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1436/215), [relacionado](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1446/215)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vou responder já que a pergunta não teve muita atenção (talvez porque quase todo mundo já saiba a resposta e talvez porque ela seja praticamente uma duplicata).

No [link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1436/215) indicado pelo mgibsonbr no comentário da pergunta já indica que é aceito. A [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) também. Isso já vem do SO original em inglês. Normalmente a decisão do que é *on-topic* passa pelo que é importante para a audiência determinada pelo site e não pelo conteúdo em si.

Configurar IDEs é algo que **desenvolvedores** fazem? É algo inerente ao trabalho do desenvolvedor e não a outra função que por acaso o desenvolvedor está acumulando? É, portanto interessa à nossa audiência e é aceito.

Answer (score -3):

Sou novo aqui, mas eu não acho correto aceitar perguntas relativas a configurações, recomendações e uso de IDE's e outros aplicativos, por mais relacionados que sejam com programação, aqui no SOPT. Para isso existem fóruns e comunidades de suporte dos próprios aplicativos.

No máximo, o que consideraria muito útil, quando tais programas são citados como sugestões em respostas a dúvidas sobre a implementação de um determinado ambiente de desenvolvimento.

Vejo nisso dois pontos importantes:

- Muitas pessoas ingressam no mundo da programação confundindo a IDE com a linguagem, e sinto que uma das responsabilidades dessa comunidade bem poderia ser auxiliar a desfazer esse conceito.
- Até por conta do ponto anterior, existe um grande risco do SOPT transformar-se basicamente em mais um fórum de suporte, descaracterizando o que imagino ser a sua proposta.

Perdoem-me se compreendo mal os objetivos do SOPT. Como disse, sou novo, mas como um visitante bastante antigo e frequente via Google, especialmente do SOEN, eu sei como esse tipo de coisa polui as buscas.

Comment: A resposta do bigown explica o porquê. Lá no [on-topic do SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): `software tools commonly used by programmers`