# Queremos perguntas que tratem de "Dificuldades na instalação ou uso de ferramentas de desenvolvimento."?

Tags: debate, escopo-do-site

Hoje eu me deparei com essa pergunta e fiquei impressionado com o conteúdo das respostas fornecidas, no total foram 5 links distribuídos em 3 respostas que não possuíam nada que as caracterizassem como respostas. Apenas o link e uma breve frase do tipo "veja esse tutorial aqui".

[Instalando Python no eclipse Linux](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28120/3117)

Com respostas de tão baixo nível e nenhuma participação de especialistas no tópico acima, me surgiu a dúvida: Queremos pergunta que trate "Dificuldades na instalação ou uso de ferramentas de desenvolvimento." ?

De acordo com o tópico [Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/264/3117), tal assunto foi tão bem aceito pela comunidade que já foi até excluído:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Será que votamos a favor dele pois não imaginávamos bem como seriam as perguntas nesse tópico? Ou a pergunta linkada acima é uma exceção a regra? Devemos fechar tal pergunta? Se sim, qual seria o motivo de fechamento?

PS: enquanto eu escrevia a pergunta o bfavaretto converteu as respostas de somente link para comentários, agora restou [uma única resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28644/3117) que fiquei na dúvida se deveria sinalizar também ou não.

Comment: Parece que ninguém tentou responder de fato à pergunta: como achar o executável do Python no Linux. Se é só isso, é simples e inofensivo. Será que muitas outras perguntas sobre ferramentas têm o mesmo problema de qualidade? Se for para decidirmos que não queremos essas perguntas, precisamos de uma amostragem maior para debater.

Comment: @bfavaretto poisé, eu pensei em coletar outras perguntas do assunto mas não tive tempo, mas eu achei estranho o fato de três pessoas terem respondido com apenas link, duas terem afirmado nos comentários que o assunto é off-topic e nenhuma ter de fato tentado responder a questão.

Comment: Eu lembro também que esse assunto gerou um pouco de polemica graças a uma pergunta sobre como instalar algo em SOs da Apple, que inclusive você mesmo deu uma resposta @bfavaretto. Mas de fato você tem razão, a discussão perde um pouco o sentido se não tivermos várias fontes, espera um pouco que eu coleto alguns dados.

Comment: Relacionado: [Pergunta descontextualizada se o conteúdo for indirectamente sobre programação](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1234/3117)

Comment: Eu fiz uma [pergunta *mais ou menos* desse tipo](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/144789/19583) no unix.se (continuo desesperadamente precisando de uma resposta, aliás), até pensei em postar aqui também, mas fiquei na dúvida se era ou não on-topic. No meu caso, não é exatamente uma ferramenta de desenvolvimento, mas é próximo disso. De minha parte, não sei dizer se é ou não apropriada pro site, mas posso dizer com certeza que do ponto de vista de quem pergunta é desejável: pode ser um simples problema de instalação, mas vem me tirando do sério há bastante tempo...

Comment: @mgibsonbr não tenho familiaridade com o SuSE mas te dei uma força lá. (+1)

Comment: @mgibsonbr acredito que não há problemas em postar aqui não. Como o assunto é on-topic, na pior das hipóteses você apenas vai continuar sem resposta. Relendo minha pergunta acho que eu possa ter dado a entender que eu não quero tal assunto aqui, quando na verdade eu queria entender as origens de um tópico com publicações bem toscas e encontrar (caso haja) um real motivo para fechamento, já que no meu ver o motivo de fechamento "descontextualizado" está errado.

Comment: O que deve estar no tópico ou não independe da qualidade média dos seus posts. Post com qualidade baixa deve ser negativado ou fechado por outros motivos (muito amplo, não claro, baseado em opiniões). Não culpe o tópico, culpe o post :) E se 100% dos posts deste tópico forem ruins? 100% devem receber negativos (se for o caso) e ou devem ser fechados pelos outros motivos. Qualidade dos posts não torna algo *off-topic*. No casos específico todas as respostas eram ruins e a pergunta podia ser melhor formulada, mas era *on-topic*, IMHO.

Comment: @bigown obrigado pelo esclarecimento, concordo com seu ponto de vista. Seu comentário poderia ser uma resposta entretanto.

Comment: Respostas para perguntas simples deveriam estar nas wikis de tags, não?

Comment: @Patrick desculpa, não entendi seu comentário. Sobre qual pergunta e qual resposta está se referindo?

Comment: Sobre "Instalando Python no eclipse Linux".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não é o fim do mundo fechar uma pergunta pelo motivo errado. Mas o ideal é que o fechamento ocorra pelo motivo certo para instruir melhor a comunidade e não dar margem para aqueles que se sentem injustiçados (sempre aparece gente achando que está sendo perseguido). No caso específico citado todas as respostas eram ruins e a pergunta podia ser melhor formulada, mas era *on-topic*.

## Qualidade dos posts não torna algo *off-topic*.

O que deve estar no tópico ou não não pode ser definido pela qualidade média dos seus posts. Post com qualidade baixa deve ser negativado ou fechado por outros motivos (muito amplo, não claro, baseado em opiniões). Não culpe o tópico, culpe o post :)

E se 100% dos posts deste tópico forem ruins? 100% devem receber negativos (se for o caso) ou as perguntas devem ser fechadas pelo motivo apropriado.

O argumento que já vi aparecer algumas vezes que um tópico deve ser recusado porque ele costuma atrair posts de baixa qualidade é fraco porque você elimina a possibilidade de posts de alta qualidade do mesmo tópico, mesmo que eles sejam raros.

Não há como impedir os usuários postarem nada de baixa qualidade e limitando um tópico não vai ajudar nisto. Então qual a diferença entre fechar por um motivo ou outro? Para a comunidade a única diferença que eu consigo ver é que o motivo errado passa a mensagem errada e isto é uma desvantagem. Não vejo nenhuma vantagem tornar *off-topic* algo que pode atrair posts ruins. Não vai diminuir os posts ruins.

Comment: Concordo. Avaliar as perguntas no site como casos específicos é a melhor coisa a se fazer até que a comunidade esteja madura, e tenha evidências e argumentos suficientes para decidir o que não quer, ou o que não faz parte do seu tema.

Answer (score 4):

A pergunta que postou realmente é bem fraca tanto em termos da pergunta por si como a resposta.

Uma tag extremamente relacionada é [ide](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) e nela verá que algumas foram bem aceitas pela comunidade assim como há perguntas que não foram, como a citada na sua pergunta.

Para relacionar o porque acho que a comunidade votou a favor de tal tópico está na relação direta com o que ocorre no SOEN onde encontrará perguntas como:

[How to install pip on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)

- 418936 visualizações;
- > 800 votos a favor
- favoritada por mais de 400 pessoas.

[Windows 7 SDK installation failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901279/windows-7-sdk-installation-failure)

- 81739 visualizacões;
- > 250 votos;
- > 50 favoritaram.

Entre diversas outras onde algumas são bem aceitas e outras não, se ver a tag que relacionei verá que algo análogo ocorre por aqui, inclusive respondi uma pergunta hoje nesse tema:

[Como debugar na Code::Blocks utilizando o compilador VS 2010 Express](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28526/como-debugar-na-codeblocks-utilizando-o-compilador-vs-2010-express)

Mas geralmente esse é o tipo de pergunta que geralmente se consegue resolver só com comentários e até por isso nem tinha postado uma resposta antes que vi um comentário "pedindo-me"  para fazê-lo.

**TL::DR**

Se a pergunta pode realmente auxiliar programadores e possui uma resposta direta e concisa considero que a mesma deve ser vista como pertinente, **mas isso depende muito da pergunta em si.**

Comment: obrigado pelos exemplos

Comment: Só mais uma pergunta: A pergunta que eu linkei foi fechada como off-topic. Em sua opinião, seria o caso de mantê-la aberta então ou deveria estar fechada por algum outro motivo? Caso você tenha conhecimento no assunto e possa responder, é claro.

Comment: @Math eu pessoalmente a votaria para fechar como *Essa pergunta não parece ser sobre programação, dentro do escopo definido na central de ajuda.*. No entanto acredito que é possível salvá-la com edições e até acredito que conseguiria respondê-la. Vou tentar editar e ver se a mesma é reaberta.

Comment: Mas é justamente esse o ponto, ao meu ver a pergunta é sobre "Dificuldades na instalação ou uso de ferramentas de desenvolvimento." (ou estou enganado?), logo, de acordo com sua própria resposta e o outro tópico da votação, o assunto é aceito, consequentemente ele torna a pergunta contextualizada e o motivo de fechamento errôneo. Não que eu queria ser preciosista e reabrir a pergunta apenas para fechá-la corretamente, podemos deixá-la encerrada por esse motivo mesmo desde que ela realmente mereça estar fechada por algum motivo.

Comment: Sim podemos deixá-la encerrada por um motivo equivocado. Mas acho que é possível fazer da mesma uma questão válida, do contrário nem tentaria editá-la.

Answer (score -4):

Não, pode fechar como:

- Essa pergunta não é sobre programação e blá blá blá...