# É permitido fazer perguntas de caráter estético, relacionado ao layout do projeto?

Tags: debate

Sei que o Stack Overflow tem por objetivo foco na programação, seja ela qual for. Porém recentemente fiquei em dúvida sobre o desenvolvimento de um projeto, mas minha dúvida não era sobre como fazer, e sim o que fazer pra deixar melhor no quesito *layout*. Porém em cima dessa minha duvida surgiu outra maior ainda, ou seja, aqui no Stack Overflow em Português é permitido fazer perguntas sobre WebDesign?

Comment: Sempre pode ficar em uma zona cinzenta. Se vai mais para um lado ou para o outro depende muito do que e como for postado. Querer saber o que fazer pode cair no "muito amplo".

Comment: O Stack Overflow é muito voltado para a resolução de problemas de código. O Stack Overflow em português, especificamente, é mais aberto a outras questões relacionadas a TI. Não sei o qual bem recebidas perguntas sobre design seriam recebidas aqui. Mas se quiser um bom lugar para perguntar em inglês, existe o [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/), que é outro site do Stack Exchange. Fica a dica ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Acho que a única maneira de descobrir é... perguntando, e vendo como a comunidade reage!

[É permitido fazer perguntas sobre](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic):

- "Experiência e interface com usuário (utilizador)." (+33/-0)
- "Code Review (Pedido de análise de código específico)." (+34/-2)

E atualmente **não é** permitido:

- ["SEO, Mecanismos de busca, Design de websites"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284/215) (+12/-17)

Minha interpretação disso é que pode sim fazer perguntas que envolvam a análise de uma IU com foco da Experiência do Usuário (UX) e Usabilidade, mas que *talvez* essas perguntas sejam rejeitadas pela comunidade (dada a divisão no tópico que inclui "Design de websites").

Sempre lembrando que - ainda que determinado tópico seja permitido - é necessário que a pergunta seja objetiva (i.e. não seja baseada em opiniões) e de escopo restrito (i.e. não seja muito ampla). Uma coisa é perguntar:

> Esse é o leiaute do meu programa, como melhorá-lo?

E outra seria perguntar:

> Nessa minha tela eu uso um menu drop-down, mas percebi que os usuários estão com dificuldade pra achar a informação contida nela. Como posso melhorar o acesso a ela, sendo que aqui não há espaço pra substituir o menu por uma lista?

Etc. Até onde se pode ir, isso eu não sei, mas "caráter estético" provavelmente já foge um pouco da proposta do site (Design Gráfico é uma área à parte, com profissionais próprios, não é uma tarefa que deveria ser exercida por um desenvolvedor).