# O que fazer com perguntas com problemas de natureza ética?

Tags: debate, comportamento

Na nossa lista de assuntos *on-topic*, temos um item que está com votação empatada:

- [Técnicas de Hacking, Pentest e técnicas de invasão.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/960/215) (+11/-11)

[Hoje surgiu uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32155/215) onde o usuário pede por "maneiras de um site dentro de um `iframe` manipular o site hospedeiro". A pergunta foi negativada e recebeu alguns votos pra fechar, mas fiquei indeciso quanto à melhor maneira de se lidar com ela.

A princípio, não me pareceu que o uso pretendido seria ético (se trata de um site de anúncios, em que o AP quer abrir popups e mexer no background do site que contém esse anúncio), de modo que eu preferi não responder. Entretanto, dois comentários me chamaram a atenção, um na própria pergunta:

> Não é possível manipular elementos de um site externo utilizando iframe.

E outro no item do meta:

> Concordo, não há motivo de esconder conhecimento, não importa o tipo.

Ora, se alguém não sabe que um problema existe essa pessoa não toma providências para se precaver contra ele. No caso, é sim possível fazer o que o usuário quer, a menos que o site tome medidas ativas pra se proteger disso. Deixar de informar o autor do comentário sobre o fato o manteria na ignorância em relação a esse problema. Mas ao mesmo tempo, se eu entrasse em mais detalhes, estaria dando a "dica" que o AP precisa pra ir em frente com a proposta dele...

O que fazer nesse tipo de situação? Devo disseminar o conhecimento e deixar com a consciência de cada um a forma como o mesmo será usado, ou devo omitir informações com potencial de serem mal utilizadas?

P.S. Pergunta relacionada no MSE (apontado por brasofilo num comentário): [Dealing with questions of nefarious intent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3528/177950)

Comment: Eu votei como "Não está claro o que pergunta". Duas linhas de explicação (!) pra obter um código que faz popup (!) num iframe. Um pouco too much.

Comment: Melhor aprender aqui onde todos podem comentar sobre a natureza ética da questão do que em lugares duvidosos.

Comment: Sugiro que só deva ser disseminado tal conhecimento juntamente com uma medida preventiva, caso contrário seria melhor não responder. Desse jeito, da mesma forma que alguém pode para no post para ter conhecimento de como atacar, o atacado possa igualmente ter o mesmo privilegio.

Answer (score 15):

Acho que a pergunta não geraria esta discussão no Meta se fosse feita dessa forma:

> Como são feitos os ataques que permitem manipular o background de um site a partir de um iframe, e como evitá-los?

Quando se recomenda, por exemplo, que se deve usar *prepared stataments* para evitar ataques de [SQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/7261) [Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9734/7261), também se diz para o leitor que o ataque é possível, e até como fazê-lo. Nem por isso fechamos perguntas/respostas que tenham esta recomendação, simplesmente por conterem referência ao ataque.

Eu voto por manter a pergunta fechada, porque entendo que ela foi **formulada da maneira errada**, podendo atrair o tipo de usuário que não queremos aqui. Mas não acho que devemos sair fechando perguntas que perguntam como um ataque acontece, porque ali também se pode explicar como evitá-lo, ajudando os usuários que desconhecem do assunto.

Comment: Relacionado: [*Dealing with questions of nefarious intent*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3534/185667)

Comment: Entendendo melhor as intenções do autor, é possível editar e reabrir a pergunta. A forma é importante, mas menos que o conteúdo.

Answer (score 6):

Esta resposta vem alguns anos atrasada, porém acho que esse é um assunto atemporal.

Não vejo problema nenhum em responder perguntas sobre técnicas de ataque no Stack Overflow. Não vejo problemas nisso mesmo que as respostas ensinem sobre como realizar ataques de forma mais efetiva.

**Uma pessoa só é capaz de se defender efetivamente de uma forma de ataque cibernético se souber como - e mais especialmente porque - o ataque funciona.**

---

Vou dar um exemplo comum de porque *entender como funciona* um ataque é importante.

Uma das técnicas mais comuns de ataque é injeção de SQL. É tão simples que eu já vi aplicada por pré-adolescentes. E ao mesmo tempo o campo de programação é tão leniente com pessoas leigas que até hoje encontro diversos sites vulneráveis a isso.

A reação mais comum que temos ao ver um código vulnerável a injeção de SQL é ensinar a "usar parâmetros, pois assim o atacante não consegue poluir a nossa query com comandos maliciosos". Pois bem, graças a essa atitude, eu já vi mais vezes do que eu gostaria esse padrão de codificação (em pseudocódigo):

```
String comando = "UPDATE tabela SET coluna = 'foo' WHERE x = " + textoVindoDaTela;
algumObjeto.executaStoredProcedure("procedimento", comando);
```

E no banco:

```
DECLARE PROCEDURE procedimento
    @comando
AS
    EXEC(@comando)
```

Bom, a pessoa seguiu a sugestão de usar parâmetros à risca, certo?

---

Com relação a segurança, eu penso da seguinte forma: quando você está na rua, na praia, no cinema etc., onde você é apenas um agente passivo (a menos que você seja policial, segurança ou algo do tipo, haha), é suficiente seguir apenas o bom-senso e as práticas mais comuns. Leve apenas o essencial, esteja sempre ao alcance de um telefone, não resista a um assalto, saiba os números de emergência...

Mas como programadores, nós somos agentes ativos. Quando você escreve um software, a responsabilidade pela segurança é nossa e é intransferível. Se alguém perde privacidade, dinheiro ou mesmo sofre um dano pessoal por conta de algo que você escreveu, você responde por isso.

O maior exemplo e modelo que eu sigo com relação a essa filosofia é ninguém menos que o criador do Stack Overflow. O Jeff Atwood costumava postar no blog pessoal dele várias formas de vulnerabilidades **e como elas funcionam**. [Vejam o texto dele sobre tabelas arco-íris](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rainbow-hash-cracking/) - ele deu até o [link para você baixar uma ferramenta utilizada para esse tipo de ataque](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/). Recentemente ele [se deu ao trabalho de hackear o sistema que é o atual ganha-pão dele, o Discourse, para ver onde e como poderia melhorar a segurança](https://blog.codinghorror.com/hacker-hack-thyself/). Não satisfeito ele **contratou** um especialista para tentar hackear o sistema de forma independente.

Um programador que não faz esse tipo de análise crítica sobre a segurança do que desenvolve é na melhor das hipóteses relaxado e preguiçoso; e se esse programador criou ou alterou sistemas que são utilizados em escala, esses sistemas são perigosos de usar. E se nós não quisermos discutir ataques em detalhe por aqui, somente esse tipo de programador formará o público principal do site.