# Perguntas que pedem indicação de software são on-topic?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Não encontrei isso no [post oficial](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic), por isso a pergunta.

No SOen perguntas que apenas pedem indicações de frameworks/bibliotecas/software são off-topic. Eu ia sinalizar [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34826/verificando-filial-mais-pr%C3%B3xima-de-um-cep) hoje dizendo que ela era off-topic, mas como alguns assuntos daqui são diferentes dos de lá (como code review, por exemplo) e esse assunto não estava como um dos motivos de sinalização dentro de "fora de escopo", preferi perguntar aqui antes.

Esse assunto é on-topic?

Comment: Há controvérsias :)

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/devemos-aceitar-quest%c3%b5es-de-recomenda%c3%a7%c3%a3o On-topic certamente são, agora se elas possuem qualidade, se elas são úteis, depende do caso. Tem que saber escrever, porque senão vira problema de muito amplo ou baseado em opiniões. Esta que você indicou está fazendo coceira no meu dedo. Às vezes espero alguma resposta para ver se dá para sair alguma coisa útil. Veja http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/488/gorilla-vs-shark e http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective é uma arte fazê-las direito.

Comment: Esta pergunta citada tem uma resposta que não cita API alguma, e isto é bom. Meu medo é aparecer alguma coisa assim: "Usa a API xyz porque ela é a maior, eu amo ela e todo mundo deveria usar isto". Claro que fiz uma caricatura do texto, ninguém escreve desta forma tão óbvia, mas a intenção costuma ser essa. Quando se recomenda algo, tem que fundamentar bem, tem que ser adequado para o que o usuário precisa. Mas as pessoas costumam preferir o caminho fácil de postar um link e afirmar que é bom. Mesmo que não seja. Mesmo que um dia deixe de ser.

Comment: @bigown Obrigado por esclarecer, agora sei que é on-topic :). Ainda assim, achei a pergunta vaga demais. Ele marcou só como "api" e não deu muita informação. Não creio que saia algo legal de lá do jeito que está

Comment: @WilliamBarbosa Concordo com você. Vaga demais cai no "não claro" em casos mais raros, ou no "muito amplo" porque não oferece muitos detalhes do que precisa e portanto muitas respostas **podem** servir, mas vai saber qual. Vai ser uma loteria acertar o que ele precisa.