# Opiniões da comunidade sobre uma pergunta fechada

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Eu gostaria da opinião da comunidade sobre esta pergunta e suas respostas: ***[Alternativas para pagamentos de bens ou serviços com cartão de crédito no iOS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14444/alternativas-para-pagamentos-de-bens-ou-servi%C3%A7os-com-cart%C3%A3o-de-cr%C3%A9dito-no-ios)***.

A pergunta pede recomendação de serviços online (APIs), com requisitos bem definidos:

> Gostaria de saber que outras empresas fazem esse tipo de serviço no Brasil, de preferência que tenham um SDK para o iOS e que não precise acessar uma página web para realizar a transação.

Ela foi postada no fim de abril/2014, e alguns dias depois recebeu duas respostas. Cada resposta é uma recomendação, e não contém muita informação além dos links para os serviços que recomendam. Uma dessas respostas foi editada no final de maio, e então esse conjunto de postagens parece ter ficado inativo até ontem (22/02/2015), quando a pergunta foi fechada.

Bom, eu tenho meus motivos para trazer esta pergunta para discussão, mas prefiro não mencioná-los para não influenciar a opinião de ninguém. Queria saber de vocês:

- Trata-se de uma boa pergunta? Tem como melhorá-la?
- Ela deve mesmo ficar fechada? É mesmo baseada em opiniões? Por quê?
- E as respostas, são boas? Tem como melhorá-las?

Se também quiserem responder algo que eu não perguntei, fiquem à vontade :) Só peço o favor de tentar manter o foco nesta pergunta específica.

Comment: Excelente tópico! Parece que há uma falta de consenso muito grande sobre a pergunta em questão.

Comment: Será que eu fugi do foco com os meus bônus? Acha melhor eu manter ou apagar?

Comment: @Math Acho melhor manter, parte do foco da discussão é justamente a estrutura de lista da pergunta.

Comment: A resposta do Math me convenceu de que a pergunta é válida sim. Então votei para reabrir.

Answer (score 7):

> Trata-se de uma boa pergunta? Tem como melhorá-la?

Acredito que a pergunta está boa assim, ela está bem clara e com objetivo bem específico.

> Ela deve mesmo ficar fechada? É mesmo baseada em opiniões? Por quê?

Com certeza não é baseada em opiniões.

Na minha opinião, tampouco é fora de escopo. Por mais que possa haver mais que uma resposta correta, ou seja, que atendam aos requisitos definidos pelo AP, cabe a ele escolher a que melhor lhe atende, não é por que tem mais de uma resposta correta que se caracteriza uma lista.

Eu diria que esse assunto faz parte do escopo pois ela se enquadra nos [**tópicos escolhidos**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/264/3117) pela própria comunidade:

- Problemas práticos específicos sobre programação que podem ser respondidos;
- Ferramentas normalmente usadas por desenvolvedores exercendo sua função programando, depurando, preparando ou implantando softwares e controlando o processo; e
- Técnicas de domínio específico para um sistema (Ex.: checagem de CPF, cartões, consumo de web services específicos, padronizações, legislações que afetem sistemas).

Me corrijam se eu estiver errado, mas eu acredito que a pergunta se refere a esses assuntos que eu listei acima.

> E as respostas, são boas? Tem como melhorá-las?

As respostas não são as melhores possíveis. Uma delas fala: `Dá uma olhada lá`, deixando claro que o AR não tem firmeza do que ele está respondendo. A outra diz: `Recomendo o site X. Blá blá blá`.

Para melhorar eles poderiam dizer os pontos positivos, os negativos, as limitações e se possível um ou outro detalhe técnico relevante do serviço, evitando que o AP e qualquer outro usuário interessado no assunto tenham que *dar uma olhada lá* para descobrir se o serviço vai resolver ou não o problema. Além do mais, as respostas do jeito que estão, é quase impossível que alguém que não tenha vivência com as ferramentas em questão possam dar um voto a favor ou contra, dificultando o controle de qualidade do conteúdo do SOPT.

## Bônus

O que diferencia a pergunta em questão de uma lista?

Vejamos um exemplo:

> Existem bons sites ou livros de introdução à programação em português? O que você indicaria como primeira leitura para um leigo absoluto em programação?

*Eu* considero que a pergunta acima é um claro exemplo de uma pergunta que gera uma lista de respostas.

O AP do exemplo acima está completamente perdido! Ele não faz ideia do que ele precisa nem onde ele quer chegar. Praticamente qualquer resposta que contenha um título de um livro ou um link para um blog servirá para ele. Essa pergunta gerará zilhões de respostas e qualquer um que acessar o tópico se sentirá no meio de um turbilhão de palavras que fazem o site mais se parecer com um fórum.

## Bônus 2

Vejam um exemplo de uma pergunta de sucesso que possui uma estrutura semelhante à que levou a criação desse tópico aqui (bom, eu achei semelhante):

[**Java e Bancos de Dados Off-line**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29577/3117)

Reparem que a qualidade das respostas permitiu que o controle de qualidade (também conhecido como votação) pudesse ser aplicado de forma mais apropriada. E apesar da resposta aceita recomendar o SQLite, as outras respostas que recomendam HSQLDB e  H2 Database também atendem ao requisito do AP, sem tornar a pergunta como "baseada em opiniões", "ampla demais" ou "fora de escopo".

Analogamente, se um dia o SQLite for extinto, a resposta aceita da pergunta que eu linkei também deixará de ser válida. Infelizmente respostas não duram para sempre, muitas vezes elas simplesmente caem no esquecimento e a ação do tempo corrói sua utilidade.

PS: A resposta inteira reflete uma opinião pessoal minha. Sintam-se a vontade para discordar, argumentar e etc.

Comment: Eu particularmente não vejo problemas com esse tipo de questão, no próprio stackoverflow gringo tem inúmeras questões pedindo recomendação de API, frameworks e etc. Acho a questão relevante para a comunidade, ela está totalmente ligada ao setor de programação.

Comment: Acho que as perguntas não são comparáveis, pelos simples facto de que uma API para pagamento é muito mais volátil e muito menos genérica do que um sistema de BD. Naquele caso o AR conseguiu facilmente colocar um exemplo de código de SQLite, que se manterá por muito tempo, mesmo que o SQLite seja extinto serve de referência.

Comment: Acho que este caso é muito especifico, e eu até poderia aceitar uma pergunta destas, se e só se as respostas fossem boas. É tipo caso em que a resposta salva a pergunta, a meu ver, claro.

Comment: De acordo com tudo. Principalmente com o primeiro bônus, sobre a diferença de uma pergunta que requer diversas respostas para ser válida/útil e uma que requer uma lista como resposta.

Comment: Eu não percebi bem se és a "favor ou contra" a pergunta.

Comment: @JorgeB. Quem, eu?

Comment: Sim @Math tu...

Comment: @JorgeB. sou a favor. Estava pensando em editar a resposta para deixar claro esse ponto por isso te respondi no chat a princípio, mas como até agora não a editei fica aqui minha resposta nos comentários.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que está ai uma discussão bem pertinente.

> Trata-se de uma boa pergunta? Tem como melhorá-la?

Acho que a pergunta está bem formulada e bem contextualizada, por isso acho que sim, que é uma boa pergunta.

> Ela deve mesmo ficar fechada? É mesmo baseada em opiniões? Por quê?

Acho que ela deve estar fechada como fora do escopo e não como baseada em opiniões, não concordo com o motivo mas acho que deveria estar fechada.

> E as respostas, são boas? Tem como melhorá-las?

As respostas são respostas de link ou de indicação e tal como as listas, já anteriormente faladas, acho que não se encaixa no escopo do site. Seria difícil manter as respostas atualizadas e que pudessem ajudar alguém num futuro mais longínquo.

<strike>Além disso, acho que a resposta é demasiado centralizada, só poderia ajudar Brasileiros e não seria uma ajuda ao público em geral.</strike>

Comment: Concordo com quase tudo, só discordo do seu último ponto. Afinal, o autor tem um problema especificamente com pagamentos no Brasil e não há problema em se ter perguntas que tenham um escopo delimitado geograficamente por qualquer motivo. É verdade que nesta pergunta uma solução universal ou quase universal seria melhor, mas sabemos que nas circunstâncias dadas na pergunta isso é difícil, e portanto não vejo problema em ser geograficamente restrita.

Comment: Sim eu entendo, é só mais um comentário.

Comment: Acho que uma pergunta que não possui respostas validas (ex: respostas que tenham somente link) é uma pergunta que deva permanecer fechada.

Comment: @RodrigoBorth E se as respostas contivessem uma breve descrição de cada serviço recomendado? Se existe essa possibilidade, a pergunta deve ser mantida aberta?

Comment: Mesmo assim @bfavaretto continuava a depender dos links

Comment: @bfavaretto aí acho que chegamos em um outro ponto, pois é dificil indicar uma API sem um link e corremos o risco dele se tornar invalido, mas por outro lado, contendo as informaçoes que a pergunta pede dentro da resposta acredito que sim, que a pergunta deveria ficar aberta.

Comment: Poderia dissertar um pouco mais sobre sua resposta na parte que diz achar que a pergunta deveria estar fechada como fora de escopo? Não ficou claro para mim.

Comment: @Math fora do escopo porque eu considero que uma pergunta que pede links não deveria fazer parte do escopo do SOpt.

Comment: A verdade é que cada vez acho mais ténue a linha que separa uma boa pergunta deste tipo duma má pergunta...