# Dúvida sobre licenças para software livre é off-topic no SO em Português?

Tags: suporte, escopo-do-site

Tenho uma dúvida sobre licenças para softwares livre, coisas como alteração de licenças e tal.

Se fosse em inglês o local mais recomendado seria no [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), mas como gostaria de ver por aqui mesmo, a dúvida é: uma questão abordando os aspectos acima, sobre licenciamento, é off-topic no StackOverflow em Português?

Comment: Show @VictorStafusa, não tinha percebido na pesquisa.

Comment: Na verdade, vou reabrir. Aquela disussão funcionou bem como sondagem inicial sobre os tópicos aceitos, mas acho bom que tenhamos discussões mais aprofundadas caso a caso.

Comment: Bem, o meu comentário automático de duplicata foi removido automaticamente, então fica aqui o link daquela pergunta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic

Comment: Discussão mais recente https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6041/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eu considero esse assunto *on-topic* no site. Na nossa [sondagem inicial](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/264/74) sobre o que seria on-topic, encontrei dois itens relacionados, ambos pendendo para a aceitação:

> Dificuldades técnicas e administrativas (legais) com publicação de aplicativos, incluindo licenças e documentação. (+21/-2)

e

> Problemas administrativos ou legais relacionadas a software, como casos de uso e aplicação de licenças ou documentação requerida para publicação de aplicativos. (+11/-8)

Além disso, temos já algumas perguntas sobre esse assunto, na tag [licença](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/licen%c3%a7a).

Claro que nada disso é garantia de que as pessoas não votem para fechar como off-topic (ou por outros motivos, caso a pergunta tenha outros problemas), mas são precedentes importantes.

Comment: Se as perguntas de licença são *on-topic*, não devíamos abrir [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15157/licen%C3%A7a-do-dreamspark-posso-usar-em-mais-de-uma-m%C3%A1quina/15160#15160)? ([A pergunta foi debatida no Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1306/perguntas-fora-do-%C3%A2mbito-t%C3%A9cnico-pr%C3%A1tico))

Answer (score 8):

As pessoas confiariam em um programador, ou jardineiro, ou advogado fazendo uma cirurgia no coração delas? Creio que não, imagino que elas prefeririam um cirurgião mesmo.

Da mesma forma, eu entendo que uma pergunta sobre um problema jurídico num site onde a grande massa frequentadora é técnica não tem condição de ser respondida corretamente.

Na rara "sorte" de alguém com formação jurídica responder a uma dessas perguntas (já aconteceu aqui no SOpt), este esforço vai ser minado, pois os votos avaliando a resposta dada não vão vir de uma comunidade com condição de analisar se aquilo é bom ou não, ou diferenciando suficientemente uma resposta dada pelo entendedor do Direito da de outro que é mero "curioso" mas escreve convincentemente.

Entendo que os posts que fogem do escopo "verdadeiro" do site (que corresponde ao público alvo, de programadores) tem um potencial de dano muito maior do que de resolver qualquer coisa que seja.

E no fim vira conversa de bar, pois um post aqui não vai servir como referência jurídica também, pois se precisar realmente usar na prática uma informação jurídica, vai precisar de alguém técnico... porém na área correta (Direito) para poder dar um parecer com valor legal.