# Tradução de community wiki: Wiki da comunidade ou wiki comunitário?

Tags: debate, tradução

Descobri agora no [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/$/40268547?q=Community%20Wiki) que o termo *Community wiki* está traduzido tanto como **Wiki comunitário** quanto **Wiki da comunidade**. Será que deveríamos escolher apenas um deles?

Algumas informações que podem ser úteis para discussão.

- O termo **Wiki da comunidade** foi adotado 6 vezes, incluindo a tradução do termo isolado que aparece no *checkbox* para transformar a resposta e também [quando a pergunta/resposta é um Wiki](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic).
- O termo **Wiki comunitário** aparece traduzido em 5 strings.
- Em 4 strings, o termo **Wiki** foi separado de **Comunidade** para que a tradução ficasse melhor.
- Há duas strings não traduzidas (resolvi esperar uma definição aqui ao invés de traduzi-las).
- A palavra **Wiki** aparece sozinha em 4 strings, sem comunidade ou comunitário na tradução.
- No total, *Community Wiki* aparece em 21 strings.

Particularmente, eu prefiro **Wiki da comunidade**. Soa melhor como algo que pertence a todos nós, enquanto **comunitário** para mim dá a impressão de ser apenas algo que podemos usufruir.

Comment: Também prefiro Wiki da comunidade.

Comment: Concordo do o Jorge B. `Wiki da comunidade`

Comment: de certa forma se é um Wiki já é comunitário, mesmo que de uma comunidade fechada como uma empresa.

voto no Wiki da Comunidade, fica menos redundante.

Comment: Em todos as perguntas e resposta que vou vejo o uso do termo Wiki da Comunidade, me parece que está consolidado desta forma, porém a tag usada é [tag: wiki-comunitário] vejam esta pergunta e resposta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/762/8039