# Fórmula excel - Fora de escopo?

Tags: debate, perguntas, escopo-do-site

A pergunta [Como comparar sequências de números no excel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88111/26643) está realmente fora de escopo?

Eu trabalho muito com VBA, e uma das minhas razões para estar aqui foi ajudar com essa plataforma.

Realmente, essa pergunta caiu numa solução que não precisava de VBA para resolver (embora poderia usar - só que sempre tento resolver com fórmulas quando possível por ser mais acessível).

De acordo com isso, acho que estaria no escopo: [Discussão sobre escopo - resposta sobre fórmulas do excel](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1436/26643).

Nós temos uma tag excel (sem contar as com VBA). Uma boa parte delas (mas não a maioria) trata claramente sobre fórmulas - sem VBA.

Acho discutível se fórmulas no excel são um tipo de programação. Mas como existe o VBA, eliminar este tipo de pergunta (como a citada) pode restringir o aparecimento de perguntas sobre VBA. Muitas vezes, o AP acha que precisa de uma macro VBA. O fato de não precisar, no final das contas, invalida a pergunta?

Comment: É preciso dizer que a pergunta apontada tem uma resposta minha aceita?

Comment: Não, isso não é relevante para a discussão.

Comment: Certo, quis confirmar porque recebi votos lá depois de postar aqui e não era a intenção.

Comment: Fui eu que votei, achei boa a resposta e votei, mas uma coisa não tem nada a ver com a outra. A não ser que fosse hábito teu fazer isso para ganhar votos.

Comment: Esta é uma daquelas perguntas que me parece no limite entre dentro e fora do escopo do site. Eu não me lembro do motivo que coloquei para fechar por isso nem sei bem o que te responder.

Comment: É, eu também acho que é limite mas há outras no mesmo caso.

Comment: Minha posição nesses casos é, como recomenda a FIFA, na dúvida segue o jogo. Se o caso tá no *limite*, mas a pergunta é razoável e a resposta é boa, Não vejo porque punir o bom conteúdo e seus autores. Claro que, por outro lado, ter a FIFA como parâmetro pra alguma coisa não é o melhor dos sinais.....

Comment: Perfeito, só um detalhe: o fechamento não é uma punição.

Comment: RSinohara, eu votei pra reabrir lá, se você respondeu é porque achou que era on-topic, eu também acho, mais de uma vez o [so] me salvou a pele tentando fazer cálculos. A pergunta está bem explicada (pro padrão médio de novatos no site) e depois da edição do @JorgeB. ficou com excelente qualidade editorial.

Comment: Curiosamente _à propos_, ontem tivemos essa pergunta [Confrontos no Excel](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83348/26643) que acho fora do escopo.

Answer (score 8):

Eis a minha opinião: perguntas sobre *fórmulas* no Excel devem fazer parte do escopo.

Primeiramente porque podem se tratar sobre a resolução de um problema usando funções providas pela ferramenta (e nesse sentido são tão válidas como perguntar qual é a função/método que se usa em C# para comparar strings, por exemplo).

Em segundo lugar, porque em usos específicos também podem envolver conceitos lógicos de programação (como, por exemplo, fórmulas que envolvem o uso de decisões, tal como a função `SE`, ou a recorrência/recursão nas chamadas entre as células).

Enfim, a construção de fórmulas em Excel serve ao propósito de resolver problemas computacionais (ainda que no formato de planilha) e requer conhecimento técnico específico (muitas vezes bem próximo ao da programação "tradicional"). Por isso, esse assunto pode usufruir das vantagens do SOpt tal como qualquer outra ferramenta/linguagem. Quem discorda é sempre bem-vindo a argumentar com o porquê, mas deveria também refletir se não se trata de preconceito com o fato de ser uma utilização muito específica.

Reitero o que você já disse a respeito do [fechamento não significar punição](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4373/f%C3%B3rmula-excel-fora-de-escopo#comment13641_4373), e adiciono que perguntas ruins devem ser fechadas independentemente da pertinência ao escopo (não sei se foi o caso, mas acho importante a distinção).

Comment: Um dos pontos que me motivam é esse, que fórmulas são uma forma rudimentar de programação.