# A dificuldade singular de julgar uma questão dentro de contexto ou fora de contexto no SOPT

Tags: debate, perguntas-fechadas, escopo-do-site, superuser

Diferente do SOEN, o SOPT não pode simplesmente migrar uma questão *fora de contexto* do SOPT para uma outra comunidade Stack Exchange.

[Uma pergunta sobre comandos executados direto no terminal Linux](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107682/como-saber-se-uma-porta-est%C3%A1-aberta-ou-n%C3%A3o-no-linux) poderia ser considerada fora de contexto no Stack Overflow facilmente, mas tal pergunta está disponível em [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/309052/check-if-port-is-open-or-closed-on-a-linux-server), [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/621870/test-if-a-port-on-a-remote-system-is-reachable-without-telnet), [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/95888/how-to-check-whether-certain-port-is-opened-or-block-on-any-other-servers-from-a), etc. Isso porque fiz apenas uma pesquisa de 30 segundos na primeira página do Google.

Em contrapartida, [uma pergunta sobre máscara de subrede](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100982/c%C3%A1lculo-de-sub-redes-e-hosts#comment221888_100982) que possui [perguntas semelhantes no próprio SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199512/subnet-mask-how-to-segment-three-separate-networks) já foi fechada por estar fora de escopo.

Enfim, o debate gira em torno de recebermos de braços abertos perguntas que giram em torno do que um desenvolvedor de software pode precisar entender ou nos limitarmos apenas a perguntas sobre desenvolvimento de software.

Comment: Sim entendo, o problema é que as vezes a pergunta não parece apresentar o contexto voltado ao desenvolvedor e cada pessoa tem uma opinião própria ou até entende melhor, sendo assim não é uma opinião geral, mas sim depende de quem estava online e viu a tal pergunta e jugou ela fora ou não do escopo. Não tem como todos terem um pensamento linear...

Comment: ...Mas apoio totalmente discutir o assunto se for uma pergunta especifica que você quiser citar com o intuito de reabrir, caso seja uma pergunta que ache que deveria estar fechada, você pode clicar em [fechar] e se não tiver pontos suficientes pra isto então clique em `flag`.

Comment: Esse tipo de pergunta tem uma tendência a ficar num loop infinito de avaliação...depende do humor da galera que vota

Comment: Gostei particularmente do título dessa postagem. :)

Answer (score 7):

Concordo contigo que essa é uma discussão realmente importante. De fato, ela vai e volta com certa frequência. Nós [já chegamos a elencar e votar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic) sobre o que achávamos que deveria ou não fazer parte do escopo, e frequentemente aparecem perguntas sobre o escopo de um assunto em específico (é só [pesquisar por "escopo" aqui no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=escopo)).

Eu constantemente defendo como dentro do escopo dois assuntos: [latex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex) e [excel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel). Ok, eles não são *exatamente* programação, mas eu entendo que eles contêm linguagens próprias, requerem certo nível de lógica e são usados em automatismos em seus respectivos focos. Pessoalmente acho mais difícil defender de uma forma similar perguntas que solicitam informações sobre comandos, muito embora questões sobre seus usos podem estar mais relacionadas com programação (de scripts, por exemplo).

Assim, não acho que seja uma questão de "receber de braços abertos" toda e qualquer pergunta, mas de ser um pouco mais tolerante (do que o SO se dá ao luxo de ser) e analisar cuidadosamente cada caso. Isso pode permitir que a comunidade se torne mais adaptável às necessidades dos falantes da língua portuguesa sem implicar necessariamente na perda de qualidade.