# Queremos começar a fazer triagem dos posts?

Tags: debate, filas-de-análise

> **tl;dr:** Propondo uma nova fila, que ajude a separar os posts que podem ser melhorados dos que estão muito ruins, ajudando a guiar os
>   novos usuários do SOpt. Mas isso só pode acontecer se tivermos
>   conteúdo suficiente e gente suficiente disposta a ajudar. O que você acha?

Tivemos alguns debates recentes sobre a qualidade do site, recepção de novos usuários e o futuro do SOpt. Isso é ótimo. Sinal de que o site está crescendo como deveria, e de que a comunidade entende que precisa constantemente melhorar se quiser ter sucesso.

As muitas conversas sobre o conteúdo, e principalmente sobre o que fazer com o conteúdo ruim, me lembraram que o [SOen tem uma ferramenta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278380) que nós não temos: **a fila de triagem**.

A triagem é uma maneira de organizar e separar as coisas de acordo com sua necessidade, para aproveitar melhor os recursos disponíveis quando chegar a hora de botar a mão na massa. No Stack Overflow ela funciona separando *perguntas* em 3 categorias:

1. As que provavelmente vão ser bem aceitas pela comunidade, e receber respostas, sem precisar de mais nenhuma ajuda ou melhoria.
2. As que provavelmente vão ser mal recebidas pela comunidade, fechadas ou removidas independente do quanto a comunidade tente ajudar
3. As que podem acabar sendo bem aceitas, e respondidas, desde que recebam um pouco de ajuda

[image: Como ela funciona]

Essa fila é alimentada por uma análise automática do conteúdo. As perguntas que forem bem avaliados vão direto para o site, e as outras vão parar na fila de triagem. E a partir daí essas perguntas têm 3 destinos possíveis:

- Página inicial do site, para poderem ser respondidas
- Fila de fechamento ou sinalizadas para moderação, onde elas serão revisadas e eventualmente removidas
- A nova fila de "Ajuda e Melhoria", para serem editadas

É algo que deu certo no SOen, e talvez seja a hora de implementar por aqui, mas antes é preciso considerar 3 coisas:

1. A análise automática do conteúdo precisa ser treinada em Português e pra isso nós provavelmente vamos precisar da colaboração de vocês, dando um feedback sobre a qualidade inicial da fila
2. O número de análises por dia vai dar um pequeno salto. Nossa expectativa é de que essa fila vá ter em torno de 15 novos itens por dia. Vocês acham que a comunidade pode dar conta do trabalho extra?
3. Essa fila só é útil se ela for realmente necessária. Ou seja, se realmente tivermos uma boa quantidade de conteúdo que pode ser melhorado com um esforço razoável por parte dos revisores. Caso contrário, ela se torna burocrática e ineficiente. Vocês acham que chegou o momento? Temos condição de dar esse passo?

Basicamente, a fila de triagem é uma ferramenta de "gente grande" e agora precisamos decidir se somos grandes o suficiente pra isso. A ideia é dar uma boa chance ao conteúdo que tem potencial para melhorar, sem gastar muito tempo com o que é **obviamente** ruim, e melhor aproveitar o empenho dos revisores e editores do site.

O que vocês acham?

Comment: Ótima ideia Gabe, mas quem estaria apto a fazer essas analises? Como funcionaria essas analises? Fui no soen ver mas não tenho reputação pra fila, apesar de lá não ser muito alto.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe A fila precisa dos mesmos 500 pontos que todas as outras filas. Vou adicionar uma foto, pra mostrar como funciona

Comment: Bom, se funcionar semelhante as edições sugeridas, com 2 votos em 3 pra decidir onde se enquadra a pergunta, acho que vai funcionar bem.

Comment: Me parece um recurso promissor, mas tenho duas dúvidas. Todas as perguntas estarão sujeitas a essa "análise automática"? Será apenas 15 perguntas por dia? e as demais?

Comment: Já que temos sempre 15 analises para fechar poderíamos ter essa ferramente. Mas é difícil dizer se chegou o momento. Se for simples de colocar ativo podemos experimentar, senão é melhor avaliar bem o cenário...

Comment: Não acho que chegou o momento, mas não tenho nada contra.

Comment: @bigown Você poderia explicar o motivo de achar que ainda não é o momento? Obrigado.

Comment: @bfavaretto o site é pequeno ainda, o que existe nas filas já é uma triagem. Acho que está funcionando bem. Claro que é só uma questão de percepção. É o que eu entendo pelo que li na descrição do que é esta fila. O Shog9 respondeu melhor que eu faria: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251744/140010

Comment: Quanto de reputação é necessario para poder avaliar? Eu possuo somente acesso à dois níveis (Primeiras publicações e Respostas Tardias), esses dois geralmente estão vazios, acredito que somente uma vez consegui analisar algum item. Mas, os que ficam mais lotados são "Votos para Fechar" e "Votos para reabrir", que somente com 3000 pontos podem ter acesso. As proximas areas que terei acesso será "Publicações de baixa qualidade" e "Edições sugeridas", acredito que nessa irá se enquadrar esse novo recurso, mas por enquanto também costuma ser poucos itens.

Comment: @Inkeliz se aqui for seguir os passos do SOen, a análise de Triagem está disponível para usuários com 500+ de reputação.

Answer (score 4):

### Sim. Por favor, traga trabalho moderativo aos usuários 500+

Sinceramente, a lista de análises é MUITO vazia para usuários entre 500 e 2000 rep (cerca de ~150 usuários). Eu, por exemplo, tenho uma ou duas análises realizadas por falta de conteúdo a ser analisado. Atualmente as listas são de primeira postagem (novato) e resposta tardia (novamente, novato).

Se 10% dos usuários nessa faixa acessarem o site diariamente e realizar 3 avaliações na lista de triagem, temos 45 avaliações em 15 perguntas. Se considerarmos todos os usuários com reputação `>` 500, acredito que podemos alcançar a taxa de 5 avaliações por postagem na triagem com uma certa facilidade.

Como consequência, pode-se afetar os usuários com reputação superior a 3000. Apenas cerca de `~75` usuários podem analisar a lista de perguntas a serem fechadas. Com a triagem, essa lista poderá crescer e é importante levar isso em consideração.

---

### Mas, a ferramenta está funcionando corretamente?

Já vi usuários com reputação 1 realizando suas primeiras perguntas e, naquele momento, corri para a lista de análise para ver se a pergunta estava lá e não estava. Não sei se já tinha sido avaliada no prazo de 1 minuto ou se a lista está demorando muito para ser atualizada. As vezes vejo várias perguntas precisando de análise para ser fechada e o número fica estagnado por um longo período de tempo. Com o tamanho consideravelmente menor do que o SOen, não podemos nos dar o luxo de receber perguntas para análise uma vez a cada 4 horas e elas chegarem em lotes de 20~30 de uma vez só. Acredito que precisa ser contínuo.

---

### Opiniões da comunidade

Essa é a questão mais plástica: divergência de opiniões. Já comentei sobre [a dificuldade de julgar uma questão dentro do escopo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4749/a-dificuldade-singular-de-julgar-uma-quest%C3%A3o-dentro-de-contexto-ou-fora-de-conte) e até recentemente fiz uma pergunta no [Stack Overflow English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240935/migrating-htaccess-from-apache-to-nginx) que foi negativada, mas bem aceita em [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/754493/migrating-htaccess-from-apache-to-nginx).

Entendo por desenvolvedor uma profissão que não funciona *standalone* (sozinha). Desenvolvemos softwares voltados à Vendas, Comércio, Saúde, Segurança, Contabilidade, entre diversas outras áreas interessantes. Digo isso para justificar uma pergunta relacionada um pouco à contabilidade como dentro do escopo se realizada por um desenvolvedor trabalhando com emissão de Nota Fiscal Eletrônica.

### Conclusão

Ative a ferramenta e mantenha-se analisando o percurso que a lista de triagem percorre. Quando tiver dados os suficiente para debatermos, traga uma nova postagem aqui no Meta.

Comment: Acho que muitos usuários com até 1k (já vi com 3k) não entendem o modelo do site muito bem, não estou falando de você. Concordo e boa parte, mas acho que haverá muitos problemas com isto, devido a muitos quererem inventar as proprias regras de certo e errado :/

Comment: Será que a no SOEn a proporção de usuarios ativos com reputação pra analisar fechamentos não seria muito superior aqui? Isso já justificaria aqui ficar estagnado e lá não, já que o soen tem muito mais usuários(total e ativos também) do que nós. Talvez o @Gabe possa responder isso. E com o tempo, o números de usuários daqui tendem a aumentar, e consequentemente, os usuários com +3000 também.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Desculpe, não entendi exatamente que números você quer buscar...

Comment: @Gabe numero de usuários mais ativos na fila de fechamento com mais de 3000 de reputação nos últimos meses.

Comment: Se bem que se ele tem acesso a fila, ter 3000 é redundante.