# Perguntas que envolvem programação indiretamente são permitidas?

Tags: debate

Há algumas perguntas que não envolvem programação diretamente como perguntas sobre Hardware, Software e etc. Devem ser permitidas? As vezes fico em dúvida se devo sinalizar ou não.

Comment: Depende muito. Se você citar pelo menos uma pergunta que gerou essa dúvida, talvez fique mais fácil afirmar qualquer coisa, pois acho que depende muito de qual é o objetivo. Recentemente discutimos se VHDL seria parte do escopo e a comunidade pareceu aceitar bem, mesmo sendo uma linguagem voltada ao *hardware*. Há perguntas que discutem sobre as arquiteturas de *hardwares*, como Harvard e Von Neumann e também foram muito bem aceitas aqui. Tem muita coisa que não envolve programação diretamente que faz parte do escopo. Perguntas sobre protocolos são exemplo disso.

Comment: O problema e que não me recordo muito da pergunta e não sei o link

Comment: @LeoneCerqueira acho que a maior questão é a forma como perguntar, recentemente houve uma pergunta válida, relacionado a shell script, que por ter sido feita de maneira incoerente com o que ele queria realmente, quase gerou o fechamento da mesma, e um usuario com muitos pontos. temos diversos tópicos sobre ferramentas que utilizamos, mas dentro do escopo se não for algo NECESSÁRIO, entra ou no fora de escopo, ou no não está claro e possivelmente no problema xy... o que resultaria em votos negativos e fechamento consequentemente...

Comment: Temos uma pergunta do tipo *poll question* sobre os tópicos que fazem parte do nosso [escopo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/264/66203).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vou dar uma dica, faça essa pergunta a si mesmo:

> O problema é no código que esta tentando acessar um hardware e/ou software a parte?

1. Se sim, então provavelmente é on-topic
2. Se não, provavelmente é off-topic.

**Mas é claro** que tudo vai depender de alguma pratica para compreender as vezes. É claro que algo pode ser on-topic, mas por engano pode ter sido fechada, ou off-topic e ser erroneamente deixada em aberto, somos humanos e não máquinas, equívocos e acidentes podem ocorrer, ninguém fecha as perguntas para prejudicar ninguém, pois "fechar" é totalmente diferente de "deletar".

Então se algo foi fechado como off-topic é bem provável que seja, mas nada lhe impede de perguntar aqui no Meta apontando especificamente a sua pergunta fechada e apontando os pontos pelo qual acredita ser on-topic.