# Perguntas fora de escopo?

Tags: debate

[Essa pergunta que eu fiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247292/op%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-deploy-de-app-em-python) foi marcada fora de escopo. [Já essa outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128417/aws-acesso-remoto-%C3%A0-inst%C3%A2ncia), (ainda) não. Qual a diferença de uma pra outra ou [qualquer outra pergunta que se refere a, por exemplo, AWS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws)? Sobre a minha pergunta, as plataformas pra deploy não seriam consideradas [ferramentas comuns entre programadores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)? E que, por mais que não seja exatamente isso, não traria benefício a discussão pra comunidade de programadores em geral?

Comment: A primeira parece um pedido de sugestão e/ou indicação de serviço, se algumas perguntas off-topic ficam abertas não quer dizer que é a intenção, não tem como olharmos tudo, por isso todos colaborarem com Sinalizar ou o Botão fechar é necessário para comunidade. Não são moderadores só que fecham, qualquer um pode votar. Outra coisa nem todas tags são corretas ou úteis, temos vários problemas com certas tags, afinal qualquer usuário pode criar uma tag

Answer (score 4):

Você tem dois perfis de usuário?

---

O principal ponto é que "a discussão" não é adequada ao formato das comunidades da Stack Exchange. Procuramos por perguntas e respostas. Não debates. Na pergunta [Opções para deploy de app em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/247292/66203) você está pedindo por recomendação de software em grande parte da pergunta:

> Quais são algumas das opções disponíveis e mais usadas hoje em dia utilizando CloudFoundry ou que operem de forma semelhante?

---

> **gosto muito** do `cf push meu_app` e ele puxar meus pacotes todos do `requirements.txt`, das opções do `manifest.yml` e etc. Porém, **só conheço serviços que são** *overkill* pra aplicações web em geral (site/blog) como Predix da GE ou o próprio Pivotal Web Services que não me dá tanta flexibilidade em termos de região do datacenter.

Já na outra pergunta [AWS - Acesso remoto à instância](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128417/66203), a qual não vejo nenhuma relação com a primeira (não sou *expert* no assunto, mas superficialmente sem relação no **meu** ponto de vista), você traz um problema concreto:

> Boas! Eu criei uma instancia Linux Amazon e uma Windows, segui todos os passos para fazer X,Y,Z [...], porém **em nenhuma das instancia eu consigo logar. Dá time out. Via SSH (PuTTY) no LInux ou via RD no Windows**. Inclui inicialmente regras restritas, agora permiti qualquer acesso full nas duas, e nada! Alguém pode ajudar? Agradeço a ajuda.

Pelo que entendi você quer saber o motivo de estar dando *timeout*. Isso é um problema concreto.

Veja também que as tags são muito diferentes, então existem sim diferenças nas perguntas. Se você quer recomendações de software, tem a comunidade [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)<sup>en</sup>.

Foi por esses motivos que votei para o fechamento da pergunta. Veja aqui o nosso tópico de perguntas [Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/264/66203).