# Esta pergunta merece mesmo ser fechada como fora do escopo?

Tags: debate, fechamento

A pergunta abaixo está, no momento da publicação deste post, com 4 votos como fora do escopo:

[Como pegar valores em função de um outro valor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/283625/28595)

A questáo de perguntas relativas a dúvidas de fórmulas de planilhas sempre vão e voltam por aqui, basta [pesquisar no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=excel), e quase sempre voltada de polêmica quanto ao fato de ser ou não parte do escopo.

Inclusive há um [post interessante](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1436/28595) onde cita esse tipo de dúvida como parte do escopo, e [**há essa pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99642/o-excel-%c3%a9-uma-linguagem-de-programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o) muito bem votada no próprio site que debate o fato de excel ser ou não linguagem de programação.

Sem contar que uma rápida olhada na tag [excel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) a gente encontra várias perguntas semelhantes que continuam no site e não foram rejeitas.

Então eu trago mais uma vez esse questionamento para o meta: Essa pergunta realmente deve ser fechada como fora do escopo?

Comment: Bom, na [tag excel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/excel/info) não diz de forma clara que as perguntas devem ser feitas só quando houver alguma linguagem de programação. Antigamente eu fechava  este tipo de pergunta só sobre Excel, hoje não vejo muitos problemas em fazer perguntas de Excel, desde que a pergunta seja clara e respondível, é logico. Caso a comunidade decida que essas perguntas deveriam ser fechadas, eu poderia mudar de opinião. Mas no momento eu não vejo problemas em perguntas sobre Excel.

Comment: Já comentei em outras ocasioes: se for um problema de programação usando excel, é dentro do escopo. Se for um problema de configuração do excel pra começar com 7 abas numa planilha nova, como fazer caber a saida num A5, e como instalar templates para listas de festas de aniversário, entendo como fora de escopo, definitivamente (salvo ter problema em um trecho de código que faça exatamente isso, mas ai cai no primeiro "IF" do meu comentário).

Comment: Eu pessoalmente não tenho nada contra questões de Excel em geral, mas com que o vejo na comunidade e com o foco que lhe foi dado estou de acordo com o @Bacco e acho que está fora a menos que seja com VBA. Infelizmente acho que deviam haver mais redes SE em PT para outros temas mas é provável que não existam usuários suficientes para as manter. Situação difícil de facto.

Comment: Curiosamente eu proprio já respondi a uma ou 2 questões de excel no site já há algum tempo atrás. E na verdade até respondi a esta questão que foi fechada, ainda que de uma forma vaga, era mais uma dica na verdade

Comment: @Bacco Não sei se entendi bem seu comentário, mas no caso desta questão é uma pergunta sobre uma função a ser usada numa fórmula. Fórmulas do Excel não é uma linguagem completa, mas pode ser considerada uma meta linguagem, não menos do que HTML ou expressões regulares. Em outras palavras, não consigo ver muita diferença (conceitual) entre perguntar sobre uma função do Excel ou uma função do PHP para somar valores de um array. Eu votaria para reabrir, mas não quero passar por cima da comunidade. O que acham?

Comment: @utluiz eu vou votar para reabrir, pois vejo esta pergunta como dentro do escopo. Meu professor da faculdade usa o Excel para ensinar a respeito de aprendizagem de maquina, tudo usando funções do Excel e formulas.

Comment: Também acho que deviríamos propor uma wiki de Excel mais descritiva. Se quiserem propor? Eu posso ajudar.

Comment: @utluiz só de curiosidade, quando comentei ela ainda estava aberta. Sobre o comentário, não fiz pensando só no caso isolado, e sim no site como um todo: se é de programação, seja excel ou PHP, como você disse (fórmula, macro, automação), entendo ser no escopo. Se for pergunta de "suporte" (formatação, configuração de página, aplicação manual de cores, etc), já entendo que não. Na pergunta específica, entendo que está no escopo sim.

Answer (score 8):

Depois da discussão acredito que chegamos ao consenso que a pergunta poderia ser reaberta.

Vou citar o comentário do Bacco que resume perfeitamente a questão:

> (...) se for um problema de programação usando excel, é dentro do escopo. Se for um problema de configuração do excel pra começar com 7 abas numa planilha nova, como fazer caber a saida num A5, e como instalar templates para listas de festas de aniversário, entendo como fora de escopo, definitivamente (salvo ter problema em um trecho de código que faça exatamente isso, mas ai cai no primeiro "IF" do meu comentário).

Como já havia alguns votos para reabrir, bati o martelo e a reabri.

Também editar a [excel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) para esclarecer que somente perguntas que tenham a ver com programação estão no escopo do site, não aquelas sobre uso da ferramenta em geral. Se tiverem sugestões de como melhorar, ficarei grato em ajudar a editar ou revisar.

Comment: Pode ser uma [boa descrição](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1436/27190) para a tag do Excel.

Comment: Mais se for pensar, deveria ser uma tag mais genérica, uma que abrange todos os editores de planilhas ao invés de só excel.

Comment: Neste caso é o Excel, mas existem mais aplicações onde pode ser usada um qualquer tipo de linguagem. Esses casos seriam também aceites? Por exemplo o [iLogic](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/inventor-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Inventor-Help/files/GUID-B98DF82D-E489-4C19-8351-11C0ED63C349-htm.html) Autodesk Inventor. Não estaremos, nestes casos, a resolver problemas de como automatizar uma determinada acção do programa e não um problema de programação? Perguntas sobre o uso de um framework/api são aceites, mas estes serão framework/api no nosso contexto?

Comment: @ramaral Boa pergunta. Eu acredito que qualquer coisa que funcione segundo um algoritmo, através de uma API que expõe certas funções, tal como macros em linguagens VBA, Apple Script, etc. são oportunas para o site. Mas o principal é o bom senso e não fechar só por causa da tag. Algo que poderíamos aplicar para esses programas (Excel, Autodesk Inventor, etc.) é pensar neles como IDEs tal como Eclipse, Atom ou Sublime. Muita gente pergunta como fazer algo usando essas ferramentas, daí cabe refletir se é um problema de programação ou apenas de uso da ferramenta.

Comment: Eu não tenho uma opinião formada, daí as questões que levantei. Assim concordo consigo em deixar para o bom senso e analisar caso a caso.

Comment: @Articuno "_O problema é que sempre tem usuário que encrenca com qualquer coisa e acha que o fato de poucos participarem do debate_"... Vc confunde _"encrencar com qualquer coisa"_ com **expressão de opinião**... talvez vc não esteja acostumado a ser contradito e por isso se doeu quando fiz questionamentos, o que é normal quando se não concorda com algo (estando certo ou errado).... em relação à segunda parte do seu comentário que citei aqui "_e acha que o fato de poucos participarem do debate_"[sic]... não foram poucos, foi apenas 1 e vc disse que era o "consenso da comunidade"...

Comment: Boa colocação @dvd. Algo que aprendi nos primeiros meses do site foi justamente como compreender a expressão de opiniões diferentes ou mesmo quando os outros apontam meus erros. Não podemos tomar pelo lado pessoal, sempre assumindo que o outro quer o melhor para a comunidade. Nada mais saudável do que discussão com respeito e argumentos racionais, sem ataques a quem discorda.

Comment: @Articuno Eu apaguei os últimos comentários porque haviam colocações ofensivas sem mérito objetivo e outros argumentos acabaram indo junto. Atitudes de tal natureza não serão toleradas neste site. Quero reforçar que o objetivo das discussões aqui no meta não é sinplesmente vencer os demais nem parece melhor que os outros. Ninguém aqui está numa guerra pessoal querendo vilanizar os demais (e se há alguém assim sera advertido).

Comment: @utluiz meu último comentário nao tinha nada demais, os demais posso ate concordar. Apenas expliquei que o consenso que eu falava também era de conversas no chat, não sei como isso pode ser ofensivo.