# Uma pergunta sobre IPs e endereços MAC está dentro do escopo?

Tags: debate

Vi a pergunta [Qual a diferença entre IP e o MAC Address e como eles se comportam?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408224/75104) sendo realizada hoje e fiquei em dúvida se está dentro do [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) do SOpt.

**Uma pergunta sobre IPs e endereços MAC está dentro do escopo?**

E se for aceita, quais tags utilizar? Pois encontrei a tag [[redes]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redes)

E a tag possui esta descrição:

> Uso de redes não é assunto permito neste site. O uso desta tag
>   provavelmente significa que a pergunta não é adequada. NÃO USE para
>   redes sociais. Uma rede de computadores, muitas vezes referida apenas
>   como rede, é uma coleção de computadores e dispositivos interligados
>   por canais de comunicação que facilitem a comunicação entre os
>   usuários e permite que os usuários compartilhem recursos.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não está no escopo. Isto é mostrado na página oficial da [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) e também [onde fizemos uma análise mais aprofundada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/264/101).

Eu fiquei um pouco na dúvida e se ela fosse escrita de outra forma talvez fosse o caso de aceitar porque é um conceito que pode servir para entender algo na programação. Afinal quando programamos usamos esses conceitos. Se concluírem que está no escopo podemos reabrir. Note que qualquer conclusão seria porque faz parte de programação e não porque redes passaria estar no escopo, aqui estamos julgando a questão e não o escopo.

Answer (score 0):

"*Uma pergunta sobre IPs e endereços MAC está dentro do escopo?*"

Totalmente fora de escopo (sem medo de ser taxativo). O motivo que torna a pergunta fora de escopo é porque não envolve programação. O fato de abordar IPs e/ou endereço MAC em si não a torna fora de escopo, pois a pergunta poderia abordar algum tipo de programação baseado nessas informações. Mas se o teor da pergunta se limita apenas a questões de rede, que é o caso, não tem nada a ver com programação, portanto fora de escopo.