# Docker está no nosso escopo?

Tags: debate, escopo-do-site

Até que ponto assuntos relacionados a Docker ou outras formas de *container* estão no nosso escopo e podem ser aceitos como perguntas do nosso interesse? Nada? Tudo? Quais critérios?

Comment: Penso o mesmo de dúvidas sobre IDEs, mexer no terminal, etc... Meu conflito é sempre: "Esta é a única comunidade em português, mas isso justifica aumentar o escopo do site?". Enfim, vou ficar no aguardo por novos pontos de vista.

Comment: @fernandosavio basicamente quanto mais coisa "aleatória" no escopo, mais respostas  de não-especialistas, mais votos de não-especialistas, consequentemente menor qualidade e confiabilidade do site. No caso do Docker, assim como de IDEs, acho que não tem resposta "genérica" sim ou não. Depende da pergunta. "Como instalo o VSCode" é problema de suporte. Diferente de resolver um problema  numa extensão que vc está  desenvolvendo, que é problema de programação, ou mesmo de como ver as assinaturas de função da linguagem X. Mesma  coisa o Docker. Tem coisa que vai estar no escopo e coisa que não.

Comment: Perguntas sobre "resolução do monitor" aparentemente seriam fora, mas de repente surge alguém querendo ler o EDID do monitor para sabera resolução nativa, e  ai temos um problma de programação. O importante pra quem for responder esta pergunta (assim como outras coisas do meta), é entender a cultura e filosofia do site (que é dinâmica), e as razões que fizeram o site chega onde chegou (pelo bem e pelo mal)  antes de tirar conclusões precipitadas.

Comment: O Docker não é uma tecnologia isolada junto dela vem um ecossistema completo **swam**, **kubernets**, **marathon**, **mesos**, **etcd**, **consul**, **crypt**, **zonekeeper**, **pipework**, **flannel**, **wave**, **...** precisaria de um stack overflow dedicado a atender com qualidade o ambiente Docker.

Comment: Nenhum problema **que relaciona programação** deveria estar dentro ou fora do escopo só por sua tag.
É muito fácil identificar quando um assunto relacionado ao Docker é ou não programação. 
Não existem indícios reais que perguntas sobre docker irá aumentar o número de tópicos offs. Alegações semelhantes são chamadas na literatura de declívio escorregadio. Além do fato de que, geralmente, a ideia que DevOps é algo restrito a profissionais de infra é totalmente incorreta, e o inverso do que propõe a cultura DevOps.

Comment: Se um desenvolvedor inserido na cultura DevOps postar um tópico de Docker que não é de programação, é alta a probabilidade de ele fazer a coisa errada sabendo que está errado, dado ao perfil desse tipo de usuário. E não vai ser uma restrição de tópico que vai "educar" o indivíduo.
Como consequência, teremos uma considerável parcela de problemas de **de programação** excluídos do SOPT, porque alguém acha que docker e Kubernetes são a mesma coisa (portanto assunto amplo ou fora do escopo), ou outra afirmação incorreta dessa natureza.

Comment: @SérgioLima Ninguém falou em *tag* aqui. As duas respostas dadas até agora indicam que é assunto de infra, até a que diz que poderia estar aqui. Seus comentários só fazem afirmações sobre o seu desejo e tem zero argumentação e justificativa que sustente. Ninguém está querendo educar ninguém aqui, estamos querendo decidir se o assunto é on ou off topic.

Comment: O que, talvez, poderia ser interessante é termos uma "área 51" sobre cada assunto *controvérso* aqui no Meta. Uma pergunta no Meta em que as respostas seriam exemplos de perguntas que surgem ou poderiam surgir relacionadas ao assunto. Assim poderíamos julgar cada exemplo separadamente e avaliar como e porquê cada parte seria ou não dentro do escopo.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss tem gente que vai achar que é sério :)

Comment: @Maniero A ponto de invalidar a ideia?

Answer (score 7):

Vou aproveitar para colocar um outro ponto importante na discussão aqui e de outras coisas sobre o site.

Até eu sei que o Docker pode ser usado para auxiliar algo de programação. Dá pra questionar se deveria, mas existe esse uso. E parece que ninguém sabe disto aqui. Mas o grosso do uso é como infra. Isso quer dizer que não teremos especialistas, de verdade para responder essas questões.

Eu tomei o cuidado de perguntar até que ponto o Docker e outras ferramentas relacionadas estaria no escopo porque em algum ponto pode estar. Nem as pessoas que defendem a inclusão conseguiram argumentar nesse sentido. Se eu sou a pessoa com mais condições de falar de Docker aqui então ficou difícil de ser aceito.

Por outro lado pode ser até outra coisa. As pessoas parecem de saco cheio do SOpt, já não gastam mais tanto tempo dedicado ao site. Não os culpo. Só que isto indica que temos problemas maiores do que por algo novo no escopo.

Estamos vivendo um momento complicado do SOpt. Como o previsto os especialistas sumiram. Eventualmente aparece um ou outro, tem uma ou outra pessoa que ainda participa ativamente que domina certos assuntos, mas não todos. Está complicado manter qualidade e dar respostas que podem realmente ser úteis. Em um cenário assim aumentar o escopo não parece prudente. Não estou dizendo que não podemos fazê-lo, mas tem que ter muito mais cuidado. Deveria até se discutir se não deveria diminuir, mas nem vou começar isto. Tem "jurisprudência" na rede sobre isto.

Estive analisando perguntas já feitas aqui, quase todas parecem ser de infra e não de programação. Curioso não ter tido essa análise antes. Em outros tempos o debate era muito mais profundo e cuidadoso, agora parece ser só desejo. Aí vem outra pergunta, se as pessoas parecem tão desinteressadas e tão sem condições de argumentar a favor, deveria fazer parte do escopo?

Ainda tem a dúvida de quais pontos poderiam ser considerados programação, porque está claro que a maioria não é. Eu realmente não posso responder isso com propriedade e parece que ninguém sabe.

## Conclusão

Não temos especialistas sobre o assunto aqui.

Comment: Acho que esse post sintetizou todo o debate. Concordo que infelizmente não podemos colocar o Docker no escopo do site. Do meu ponto de vista por problemas que estão além da natureza do Docker. Pelo ponto de vista de outros, por se tratar muito mais questão de infra (o que eu discordo, mas não é o ponto). O ponto é que a maioria concorda que no momento não dá para inserir no escopo. Peço desculpas se pareci um "ditador de regras" (para não dizer uma expressão de baixo calão envolvendo excremento), mas é que gastar energia com uma redação para discordar de apenas duas ou três linhas...saca né?

Answer (score 5):

Eu não sou nem de longe um entendido de "virtualização", "núcleos" e "processadores", mas do pouco que entendo de "containers" (e docker) o maior numero de perguntas prováveis aqui seriam problemas (para rodar ou outras falhas) com:

- Hardware
- Drivers do "hospedeiro"
- Configurações especificas limitadas ao equipamento exclusivo da pessoa
- "Imagem" do "container/docker" única que possui problema nos "softwares" inclusos dentro dela (e até dependências)
- Problema com o script ou programa em si que não esta relacionado ao "container", mas sim ao projeto

Creio que seriam poucos os casos que a pergunta iria conter problemas como:

- Configurar/criar/editar arquivos de configuração de um "container"
- Explicação sobre o funcionamento e/ou requisitos para rodar o tal "container" (algo que talvez gerasse umas 3 perguntas no máximo até aparecer novas melhorias neste tipo de ambiente, caso contrário provavelmente cairíamos no item 3 a primeira lista "Configurações especificas limitadas...")

Eu não estou dizendo que não seria um tipo de pergunta útil, estou apenas dizendo que a maioria seriam problemas complicados de resolver que provavelmente seriam mais voltados ao HelpDesk por serem problemas com o "hospedeiro" e sinceramente eu duvido muito que a maioria das pessoas que venham a perguntar irão se preocupar em entender a diferença entre perguntar sobre configurar um "container" e sobre não entender o porque não esta funcionando em sua estação, o que acho que neste caso seria a diferença entre o que seria on-topic e off.

### Resumindo

Com a falta de entendimento da maioria das pessoas na hora de pergunta sobre o problema ser na configuração do "container" ou no hospedeiro o número de perguntas off-topic, que seriam relacionados a problemas únicos e raramente aproveitável a outros usuários, iria crescer, aumentar o numero de fechamentos (se não por off-topic seria por baixa qualidade) e com o resultado disto tudo teríamos uma série de pessoas que não entenderiam os motivos de fechamento e começariam a reclamar, no final causando mais dores cabeça do que gerar bom conteúdo sobre "containers".

### O que fazer?

Duas sugestões:

1. Não aceitar perguntas sobre "containers" (ou Docker, não sei se o foco é exclusivamente Docker)
2. Criar algumas perguntas com foco exclusivo na parte técnica de forma planejada voltada a criar um bom conteúdo sobre o assunto, escolhendo alguns usuários de confiança, mas ainda sim mantendo a situação sobre o assunto um pouco "restrita" ou até permitindo que qualquer um pergunte mas com colaboração da comunidade nos atentarmos a fechar o que é indevido (que já citei o que creio ser indevido neste tipo de assunto)

Eu não entendo muito disto e me perdoem se falei alguma besteira, me corrijam e/ou critiquem. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Meu entendimento é que sim, entra no escopo por entrar no contexto de ["ferramentas comuns entre programadores"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) e ["Ferramentas normalmente usadas por desenvolvedores exercendo sua função programando, depurando, preparando ou implantando softwares e controlando o processo"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic).

Sinto falta de um Server Fault em português, ali seria o local para esse tipo de conteúdo, mas como não temos isso e atualmente o SO-PT já acumula alguns contextos que teriam uma linha mais ligada a um Database Administrator, acredito que podemos ser mais tolerantes com perguntas relacionada com Docker também.

Referências:

[A respeito de quais tópicos posso fazer perguntas aqui?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

[Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic)

Comment: Uma coisa que percebi que todo mundo que deve ser a favor deve ter esse discurso, "é uma coisa do Server Fault, mas como não temos em pt então cabe aqui".

Comment: Tambem sinto falta de sites especializados em  PT, e o melhor jeito de viabilizar isso um dia é não misturando no SOpt. Um dos segredos da rede é concentrar o escopo de cada site ao máximo para aumentar a chance de atrair especialistas de cada área no mesmo lugar.

Answer (score -4):

Opa gente.
Faz muitos anos que não frequento aqui.
Parei de postar em 2016 +-.

Bom, eu gostaria de rever isso e hoje com muita experiência em DevOps, eu acredito que é um erro muito grande não abordar sobre Docker.

O Docker não é IDE nem nada do tipo.
É virtualização? Sim.. É infra? Sim..  tudo bem mas, tem muito sobre programação nele.

Eu acho válido liberar questões sobre o Docker, como desenhar e montar o ambiente de forma adequada, como entender a usar a linguagem dele na construção de instruções do DockerFile, docker-compose.yml, etc

A parte que eu acho que pode manter fora do escopo é quando adentra-se muito na infra, por exemplo, abordar k8 (kubernets), jenkins, jira, etc..

Alguém aqui concorda em permitir temas sobre o Docker?
Eu posso contribuir e moderar os temas e instruir outros para que tenha uma continuidade quando eu sair.

Outro motivo de abordar Docker é que eu vejo uma imensa quantidade de programadores que não sabem montar um ambiente Docker localmente.

Nesses últimos anos, eu trabalho com DevOps desde 2017 até hoje e obtive bom know how. Gostaria de compartilhar e desmistificar esse tema que assombra a maioria dos programadores.

Eu garanto suporte e acredito que outras pessoas podem ajudar.

Comment: Poderia orientar como encarar o DockerFile e docker-compose.yml como linguagens de programação? Eu os encaro como linguagens de marcação. Em minha opinião, talvez o mais próximo de uma linguagem de programação seria a instrução `RUN` do DockerFile usando estruturas de laços de repetição e declarações condicionais na linguagem de script da imagem o que talvez leve a construção de perguntas ambientadas como Docker que não sejam relacionadas ao DockerFile mas sejam dúvidas específicas de shell script infladas com conteúdo Docker.

Comment: Tem que lembrar a discussão surgiu após um surto de posts sobre docker, em geral problemáticos e helpdesk. Não só é infra, mas é nicho (até muito usado em cenários sem sentido, seja por desconhecimento ou dogma). Vale lembrar que a rede já tem o [devops.se], para infra tem o [sf] e para suporte tem o [su]. O fato de não podermos ter em português é uma restrição da empresa, e como já discutido quando propusemos o Super User em Português (passou na fase de convite mas a SE cortou a iniciativa), creio que não justifica tirar o foco do SOpt (o SU é muito mais relevante e nem ele foi aceito).

Comment: E só pra ser bem chato e pedante (que eu sou mesmo, fazer o que), _containers_ e virtualização são coisas diferentes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=85k8se4Zo70

Comment: Entendi @Bacco
Então não tem muito o que fazer. 
Mas eu discordo muito disso pois se for pensar, cutucando o comentário do AugustoVasques, CSS não é linguagem também e, é um tanto ignorante dizer que DockerFile não usa linguagem alguma. Aquilo é GoLang. O docker-compose.yml é yaml. 
Bom, enfim, eu só acho que a atitude em banir tudo é, em boa parte, baseado em ignorância. Pode sim banir conteúdo que vá muito adentro da infra, mas acredito que coisas como levantar um container, escrever um dockerfile, pode perfeitamente entrar aqui.

Comment: conforme escrevi no post, estive totalmente OFF do stackoverflow desde 2016. Foram 7 anos. Não vi nada do que ocorreu aqui nesse período. 
O Docker em si, até 3 anos atrás era bicho de 7 cabeças. Poucos profissionais realmente entendiam como usar. Por isso também não teve praticamente ninguém aqui para argumentar os pontos a favor de permitir o tema aqui. Olhando os comentários, teve um ou outro que já tinha uma boa visão porém foram muito mal compreendidos.  Bom já vi que esse tema virou um tabu.

Comment: Quando o pedi orientação achei que poderia ser algo interessante, fiz questão de colocar minha visão sobre o assunto na esperança de ser convencido do contrário

Comment: @DanielOmine é assim que pretende orientar aos usuários que vierem em busca do seu conhecimento, os chamando de ignorantes? Sinto o informar que você não está capacitado para lidar com as pessoas, seu temperamento precisa ser trabalhado e seus conhecimentos sobre o assunto que pensa dominar estão equivocados. O Docker foi escrito em Golang porém o Dockerfile é apenas um arquivo de texto. É um script que contém coleções de comandos e instruções que serão executadas automaticamente em sequência no ambiente docker para a construção de uma nova imagem docker.

Comment: Eu gostaria muito de ter tais tipos de pergunta (e ate outros assuntos correlacionados ao on-topic), mas é importante entender que tentamos sim por um tempo aceitar Docker, mas a experiencia provou que não funcionou, quase todas a perguntas que tivemos eram sobre *suporte técnico pessoal* e *infra*, algo que só atenderia ao AP, só 2 perguntas atenderam bem para servir a comunidade como conhecimento...

Comment: ... As decisões não partem só por um debate no Meta, muitas coisas são experiencia, Docker não foi a unica situação que foi experimentado e que provou que raramente teria conteúdo bom para a comunidade. Tudo que a comunidade participativa decide e feito com a maior calma, visando o tópico, a empresa e a comunidade. Agradeço a compreensão.

Comment: Tem muitas perguntas de HTML e CSS que são suporte técnico pessoal, essa geralmente são fechadas (o que é o correto), mas a maioria das perguntas sobre HTML CSS boas são sobre o funcionamento das linguagens (marcação e estilo) e não sobre ajuda pessoal, então a experiência com elas nunca foi problemática no nível que Docker foi. De qualquer forma não podemos comparar o que e aceito ou não entre duas coisas distintas (CSS e Docker), temos que analisar uma a uma de forma isolada, sem comparar. 

Comment: @DanielOmine curiosamente tenho um post que preferi deletar depois de receber -4 com os mesmos argumentos que o seu em 2021. Não permitir docker é restringir e dificultar o desenvolvedor novato que facilmente poderia testar sua aplicacao subindo ela juntamente de um db/cache/queue com meia duzia de linha num dockerfile/compose sem precisar instalar nada em sua máquina, e basicamente garantindo que ela funcionaria em outros ambientes dockerizados. Enfim, eles preferem assim. Eu só lamento pelo iniciante que não sabe inglês e vem buscar ajuda aqui. Vai levar patada e ser negativado somente.