# O hack está relacionado a programação?

Tags: debate

O hack refere-se à reconfiguração ou reprogramação de um sistema de forma não autorizada pelo proprietário, administrador ou designer. O hack também está localizado na área de Segurança da Informação dentro de TI.

Mesmo assim eu nunca vi uma pergunta relacionada a hack no SO, mesmo (no meu ponto de vista) parecendo um assunto que está ligado a programação e pode afetar em como uma aplicação é feita. Mas no fim das contas, ele está relacionado a programação? Consequentemente, ele está dentro do escopo do site?

Comment: Isso já foi sugerido em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/960/5878

Answer (score 7):

Hacking não faz parte de programação, mas o vice-versa sim, logo, o processo de construção de alguma ferramenta que será brevemente usada por um hacker está diretamente associada com programação. Logo, não vejo o porquê de não perguntar algo relacionado a programação no site.

Não vejo problema algum em fazer uma pergunta relacionada a construção de qualquer ferramenta. A responsabilidade do uso de qualquer criação é diretamente associada à quem irá utilizar a ferramenta, independente do porquê será usada. Hoje, muitas ferramentas já utilizadas por hackers são *open-source*, associadas a uma licença que contém em cláusula "Não me responsabilizo por usos inadequados do software". Isso deve ocorrer aqui também.

Tenho certeza que existem perguntas voltadas a construção de softwares que seriam brevemente utilizados com mal intenção no funcionamento de algo, mas o autor da pergunta nunca deixará claro para que estará utilizando essa ferramenta, pois não será necessário e iria fugir do escopo da pergunta.

Exemplos disso seria:

- [App sendo reconhecido como potencialmente perigoso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/242724/app-sendo-reconhecido-como-potencialmente-perigoso/243819#243819)
- [Como implemento vento numa equação de trajetória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129282/como-implemento-vento-numa-equa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-trajet%C3%B3ria) - *um hack que estava desenvolvendo para um jogo de tiro 2D.*

Listei apenas as que tenho conhecimento sobre, mas pode existir muitas outras por aí.

Vale lembrar que nem sempre *hacking* tem uma intenção maliciosa em sua invasão. Algumas empresas tem Pentesters encarregados em invadir seus próprios sistemas para testar sua segurança. De qualquer forma, é uma forma de compartilhar conhecimento.

Hacking não é diretamente associado a programação porque você pode hackear um sistema sem ter que tocar em qualquer código. Não existe a tag `hacking` (se existir, não deveria) porque não vejo que seria útil e com certeza iria remover o escopo da pergunta, limitando a uma filosofia ou um problema amplo demais.