# O que fazer quando encontrar uma pergunta de algo que possa ser "ilegal"?

Tags: debate

Recentemente enquanto visitava o SOpt, eu me deparei com a seguinte pergunta: [Largura Indefinida Html 5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/418940/largura-indefinida-html-5)

E nós comentários, o questionador passou o link do site que ele estava fazendo, e aparentemente é um site para filmes e séries piratas.

Eu não assumi que seja isso (mas talvez seja), então me veio está dúvida. O que fazer quando for encontrado algo que possa ser ilegal ou antiético? Levamos em consideração somente o código e a dúvida?

Exemplos:

Alguém está com dúvidas em um código para o seu site de downloads gratuitos de livros pagos (pirataria), ou para um site de vendas, propagandas ou apologias a coisas ilegais.

Comment: Relacionada: [O que fazer com perguntas com problemas de natureza ética?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1966/5878)

Comment: Comentei sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8000/o-hack-est%c3%a1-relacionado-a-programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o/8002#8002).

Comment: Achei muito bom os dois links, gostaria também de saber o que poderia ser feito se não for caso de hacking em si, mas sim um desenvolvimento real para algo "ilegal", como é o exemplo do site para filmes e séries piratas, ou como sites que contenham cópias de livros pagos para download.

Comment: Acho que é um pouco complicado decidir o que fazer oficialmente, pois um dos preceitos fundamentais da comunidade é sempre presumir a melhor intenção de todos. Se um usuário faz algo ruim, presuma que ele fez de tal maneira porque não sabia fazer diferente e se acha que aquilo poderia ser melhor ajude-o a melhorar. Em casos que fica muito claro que a intenção do usuário não é boa você pode se omitir de ajudar, negativar e sinalizar para a moderação, mas sempre é bom comentar orientando que aquilo é ilegal e vai contras os princípios da comunidade.

Comment: Um caso semelhante que vale citação é o [Como integrar a aplicação com Whatsapp?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/221557/5878) em que esse tipo de integração fere os termos de uso da aplicação e é considerada ilegal. Talvez o autor da pergunta não saiba disso e possui boas intenções, então foi orientado através da resposta.

Answer (score 4):

Vou ser sincero, eu geralmente **não faço nada** quando me deparo com algo assim, primeiro porque ele no minimo deveria saber como trazer o código independente do site de onde ocorreu o problema, já que o problema é com CSS e HTML, e deveria criar um [*exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Ok, ele é inexperiente e provavelmente **nem é um desenvolvedor** de verdade, é apenas um curioso que resolveu fazer algo por conta, assim como muitos, ainda sim o foco tem que ser no código, o problema é que muitas vezes perguntas deste tipo tem mais de um problema, o principal é **o helpdesk barato**, porque simplesmente ele não quer aprender (assim como muitas perguntas) ele só quer um suporte para corrigir o erro e pronto

O pior das perguntas do **tipo "helpdesk"** é que ainda por cima tem um povo que adora responde-las porque esbravejam *"o importante é ajudar"*, mas essa ajuda é um argumento **sem** contexto ou qualidade definida para um aprendizado futuro sobre as tecnologias e sobre agregar conteúdo de valor ao site, simplesmente parece que tem gente que gosta de apoiar o "resolva o meu problema de graça", e não, não estou falando que não devemos "trabalhar de graça", e se entendeu isso até este ponto que escrevi comece a leitura do começo deste paragrafo, o ponto é que simplesmente uma série de erros de digitações se **"tornaram escopo"** e cada vez mais é tolerado, não por todos, mas por uma maioria que não entende o propósito do ensinamento e aprendizado sobre tecnologias.

Então sobre o caso de natureza ética em um link, eu diria que pedir o link já **é o problema**, se ele postou por conta o link direto no corpo da pergunta então ai sim teria uma ação, o **sinalizar** (se o link estiver no corpo da pergunta):

> [image: como sinalizar uma pergunta com problemas]

Você pode até por opção editar por conta e remover você mesmo, mas lembre-se de sinalizar, e o mais importante não entre em debate/discussão com o autor da pergunta acaso ele se aborreça, deixe um moderador resolver isto após sinalizar.

Então torno a dizer **minha opinião**, perguntas assim, que levam a obrigar ver coisas como:

- Sites externos
- Projetos inteiros em GIT (como Github, Gitlab, etc)
- Baixar projeto para testar

Por si só já deveriam ser perguntas fechadas, afinal o nosso foco é resolver problemas de códigos e ensinar porque aquilo falhou e como fazer o certo e **não** dar suporte técnico gratuito.

A pergunta especifica eu comentei, se reparou, ele nem explicou em que momento os espaços deveriam sumir, ele simplesmente entende ZERO disto e provavelmente se eu for explicar para ele o passo a passo ele vai achar ruim (muitos acham) porque ele veio aqui procurando simplesmente helpdesk.

Comment: Sim, nesse caso eu concordo com você. Mas o que deveria ser feito no geral, quando não for caso de hacking e sim de um "desenvolvimento real", quando o sistema desenvolvido for para ser usado em algo "ilegal".

Comment: @Sumback **Resumindo a resposta toda:** se a pergunta depende de links externos já está errada e deve ser fechada, "ponto"; Se a pergunta esta vaga e você como quem foi ajudar pedir o link, você está errado, então evite e oriente o usuário a formular a pergunta seguindo o https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example e vote para fechar também, lembre-se fechamento não é o mesmo que deletar, é apenas um meio de barrar temporariamente (na maioria dos casos) perguntas que precisam ser melhoradas, o autor deve apresentar o minimo esforço.

Comment: Se o link for conteudo ilegal de fato e estiver no corpo da pergunta você pode tomar a liberdade de editar e remove-lo e em seguida sinalizar a pergunta para um moderador.... Basicamente o que disse na resposta, resumido, não tem "solução" padrão para todos casos, infelizmente é analisar pergunta a pergunta e tentar fazer o que é possivel a nosso alcance