# Devemos corrigir palavras abreviadas ou deixar como está?

Tags: debate, edição

Eu vejo que há muitas perguntas aqui no SOPT que são feitas com várias abreviações, como:

`pq -> "porque" ou "por que" - depende da interpretação da frase`

`pqq -> "por que é que"`

`qnd -> "quando"`

`dps -> "depois"`

`tá -> quando tem sentido de "está"'`

... entre outros.

Veja alguns exemplo não reais, mas bem semelhantes ao que vi:

> **Qnd** (quando) eu clico em prev, ele volta e **dps** (depois) avança na mesma ação?
>
> Esse erro **tá** (está) acontecendo **cmg** (comigo)

É válido efetuar a correção do texto em tais perguntas ou isso pode ser ignorado?

Comment: Eu acho que sim, estamos num site de Q&A e não num chat ;)

Comment: Relevante: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1297 (porém nao trata de abreviaturas, talvez seja o caso de incluir).

Comment: Talvez isso pudesse virar uma funcionalidade claro mais detalhes são necessários, por exemplo ao digitar 'vc' ele completasse 'você' caso fosse um nome de variável e vc apagasse ele não sugeriria mais, isso pode ser usado também por trocar palavrões por asteriscos(quando acontece meio raro), alguns sistemas de fórum fazem isso.

Comment: axo q vc tá certu. Tá xeio d prigunta i reponta aki on s0pt xeio d pobrema d abviacaum d otrogafia gamaltica i cocodança!!!!11onze! Pq cerá q iço acunteçe???? oq cerá q tá eradu nas pesoa q faiz iso?????

Comment: Pqq, dps, qnd? Isso existe? Primeira vez que vejo :(

Comment: Nunca tinha visto "pqq", sempre pensei que fosse erro da digitação de "por que"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sim, por favor faça isto. Embora a [pergunta que trata da formatação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/101) não fale explicitamente disto ela fala de corrigir ortografia e gramática. Talvez alguns nem percebam mais que estão escrevendo errado. Eu, de fato, conheço pessoas que acham que é errado escrever dentro das normas mas isto é um absurdo. A pessoa se recusar escrever certo é uma coisa, achar que os outros devam tolerar isto é um problema.

Ninguém é obrigado consertar nada. Mas se o fizer estará prestando um grande serviço à comunidade.

Claro que o ideal mesmo é mostrar para os usuários que é importante para todos, até para a vida dele que escrever corretamente só tem vantagens. Que ele deveria colaborar. Como a maioria destes problemas ocorrem em perguntas ele que recebe tanta ajuda deveria pelo menos se preocupar com isto. Mas normalmente não ocorre, muitas vezes ele se irrita se alguém pede para se ele se ajudar. E pior, há uma noção geral aqui que deixar o usuário à vontade como se ele estivesse na casa dele e pudesse fazer até que o ele não faz na casa dele é melhor. Vou sempre colocar minha opinião quanto a isto mas se é assim que deve ser, que seja.

No mais só posso agradecer aos que se preocupam e fazem alguma coisa para o *site* estar em melhor forma.

Comment: Cliquei [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/2467/revisions) só pra ver o que o @Wallace Maxters encontrou errado :)

Comment: Mas ele não consertou tudo, tinha dois espaços antes da palavra e ele não viu, ele não é um bom corretor :P Infelizmente como todos devem ter percebido eu tenho deficiências para escrever. Não é fácil pra mim, eu até me esforço mas tenho dificuldade. Mas adoro quando me corrigem direta ou indiretamente. Só gostaria de dar menos tralhado :) Eu costumo revisar meus *posts* depois, quando eu já me desvinculei dele. Na hora eu não consigo enxergar os problemas :P

Comment: Você é muito meticuloso :)

Comment: Por isso existem outras pessoas aqui também para poder corrigir, né?