# Perguntas sobre modelos de negócios são considerados on-topic?

Tags: debate

Estão surgindo perguntas recorrentes sobre administração, vendas, etc.
Enfim, são perguntas mais voltadas a consultoria de negócios.

Aqui tem um exemplo onde ninguém votou para fechar até o momento, talvez devido as tags: [Software com custo. Ajuda?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66511/software-com-custo-ajuda)

**Acho** que o AP foi esperto e colocou nomes de linguagens nas tags para parecer ser algo relacionado a programação, pois, o contexto não tem relação alguma com programação, banco de dados nem nada disso, é puramente uma dúvida sobre qual plano de business desenvolver.

Ontem mesmo vi outra pergunta semelhante, a qual foi suspensa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66496/conhecimento-em-varias-linguagens#comment135858_66496

Então, afinal, é permitido ou não esse tipo de pergunta sobre consultoria, administração, vendas, etc ?

Answer (score 3):

Vamos reescrever essa pergunta num contexto totalmente alheio ao desenvolvimento de software, e ver se ela ainda faz sentido:

> Olá, pessoal!
>
> Bom, minha situação é a seguinte: Tenho um <del>programa</del> **parque de diversões** e quero cobrar <del>pelo uso</del> **ingresso**, porém percebi que se eu deixasse **a entrada** gratuit<del>o</del>**a** existiriam mais clientes. Então pensei em limitar o <del>sistema</del> **acesso** e cobrar uma mensalidade pelo que o <del>usuário</del> **visitante** quiser a mais. Só que existem diversas opções de <del>ferramentas</del> **brinquedos** que eu ofereço com um custo. Por exemplo:
>
> ```
> Valor inicial: R$ 0,00
>
> Brinquedo1: +R$ x,00 mensal
> Brinquedo2: +R$ x,00 mensal
> ...
> ```
>
> Aqui é onde está o problema, como eu posso fazer <del>um software</del> **uma precificação** desse tipo? Gostaria de gerar um boleto só no final do mês e não vários para cada <del>função</del> **brinquedo** que o cliente quiser... Preciso de ajuda para bolar uma lógica
>
> Eu gostaria de dar ao <del>usuário</del> **visitante** a oportunidade de <del>adicionar e remover funções</del> **se inscrever ou desinscrever nas diversas atrações**... Assim ele poderia escolher o valor que deseja pagar de acordo com <del>as necessidades</del> **os interesses** dele...
>
> Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer algo do tipo? Já trabalharam desse jeito? Tem chance de dar certo ou existem opções melhores?

É... parece uma pergunta aplicável a "empresários em geral", e não algo específico a um desenvolvedor [*enquanto este exerce seu trabalho de desenvolvedor*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/101/215). Eu diria que é *off-topic*. Se essa mesma pergunta estivesse focada em algum ponto bem específico - como DRM (garantir via solução técnica - e não jurídica - que o usuário pague pelo que usou) ou questões legais de interesse específico dos desenvolvedores (ex.: fazer o contrato com o cliente como SaaS, "aluguel de software", *royalties* segundo os direitos autorais sobre o programa, alguma outra alternativa?) então *talvez* ela pudesse permanecer aberta. Mas ainda assim seria uma "área cinza", e a pergunta teria de ser formulada com muito cuidado para não se tornar ampla demais ou principalmente baseada em opiniões.

Sem desmerecer a pergunta (espero que ninguém se ofenda com essa minha pequena "paródia" rsrs), sou da opinião que é necessário restringir sim os tipos de pergunta aceitos no site. Não basta que algo afete *tangencialmente* um desenvolvedor, precisa ser bem específico dessa área para que tenha lugar no site (ainda que dúvidas semelhantes já tenham cruzado a cabeça de vários desenvolvedores). Seria interessante abrir comunidades em português englobando mais tópicos, mas não é pela ausência das mesmas que deveríamos relaxar demais os requisitos para perguntar aqui.

(Mesmo porque, se o escopo é amplo demais, o que diferenciaria um "especialista" e de um "não-especialista"? Queremos um site com essencialmente "leigos ajudando leigos"? Como já [comentei em uma outra resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1950/215), nada contra a existência desse tipo de espaço, mas creio que a proposta *deste site em particular* seja outra - se é que ainda estamos fiéis à proposta...).

Comment: P.S. Vou me abster de votar pra fechar por enquanto, vai que alguém tem um contraponto interessante... Gostaria de ter mais tempo para me envolver mais nos assuntos do site, mas ando bastante ocupado, e quando encontro tempo prefiro usá-lo perguntando/respondendo coisas interessantes do que "fazendo faxina" - por mais que esta seja muito necessária na manutenção da qualidade do SOpt.

Comment: Concordo plenamente @mgibsonbr.... Mas já que não temos uma comunidade para falar sobre esse tipo de assunto, o meta poderia ser uma saida não ? Aqui no meta tem várias discussões, este tipo de assunto poderia se encaixar aqui também ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Alguns assuntos são bem-vindos no meta, outros no chat, não sei dizer quando usar qual. Mas um pedido de ajuda, opiniões, etc, que claramente não está no escopo do site nem é *sobre o site*, creio que é o chat mesmo a melhor opção. Só é uma pena que não dá pra "chamar a atenção" para um assunto no chat, mesmo que muitos na comunidade achem aquilo importante. Eu não costumo frequentar o chat, mas sei que às vezes tem algum assunto bombando por lá (e não somente a conversa usual), e o único jeito de ficar sabendo é se por acaso você entrar no chat naquele dia. :(

Comment: Poxa.. O ruim do chat é por ter bastante gente os assuntos são extremamente variados e por vezes não tem um foco específico.... E outra, @mgibsonbr, pra acompanhar os assuntos, teria que ler desde o inicio do dia... ;/

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Sim, de fato ele é inconveniente por esses motivos. Usuários com 100 pontos de reputação ou mais podem [criar salas de bate-papo separadas da principal](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms), de modo a evitar essa dispersão de assunto. Mas o problema de como divulgar que essa discussão está ocorrendo permanece. De todo modo, essa foi só minha opinião, não me parece haver regras formais (nem mesmo informais) para o que pode e o que não pode ser discutido no meta (acho que funciona na base do [olhômetro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it) mesmo).

Comment: Eu também acho @mgibsonbr... Pelo que entendi, questões como a que foi colocada na pergunta podem ser discutidas no meta e não no SOpt... Mas que uma coisa é verdade, tem que ir na base do olhômetro...